# Can we place all future code snippets under a software-specific license?

Tags: feature-request, legal, copyright, licensing

Creative Commons specifically recommends that its licenses not be used for software, and I am aware that discussions occur frequently on this topic. Users often come to the site seeking a solution, and when that solution is posted they will then copy it to their own code, but that requires them to license their software under CC-BY-SA.

The solution? All program code posted to Stack Overflow should be licensed by default under a license that permits its free use in software. I would recommend the [Mozilla Public License, version 2.0](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0), which still provides some copyleft protection but is fairly easy to understand. Also note that the MPL explicitly grants you the right to display the code, something that could be useful for posting on other websites. Of course, the poster would have the right to choose another license if they wished.

Of course, we can't change any of the code that's already been posted to SO. It's under CC-BY-SA, and the copyleft can't be broken. So some code-marking system would have to be developed to mark pre-change and post-change code.

Comment: Why not just Beer License the whole damn site?

Comment: Because Stack Overflow contains a significant amount of other important programming information for which a software license would be unsuitable.

Comment: @Manishearth because encouraging users who may be under the drinking age in their country to drink a beer could be seen as enabling a minor.

Comment: @LeeSleek: It was a joke :/

Comment: Never assume jokes will be taken as such in nonverbal environments. I recommend using pseudo-HTML such as </sarcasm>.

Comment: I find pseudo-HTML super lame. Meta is a very humorous environment, you'll get used to it. :)

Comment: "Please give me a beer. By the way, I don't like beer."

Comment: "I here for do not permit to relicense any content, including source code in any form, I contributed to any Stack Exchange site still attributed to me to be relicensed under any lesser terms then provided by CC-BY-SA." I don't want anything more "relaxed" then that for what I contribute(d), I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Manishearth: I actually like that idea, imagine what would happen on a big SE meet-up.

Comment: "...and when that solution is posted they will then copy it to their own code..." Actually, I think that's the core problem that needs to be tackled. But I fear that's outside of the scope of SE ("don't C&P code from the interwebs!").

Comment: Related proposal: [The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code Across the Stack Exchange Network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/148099)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see with this suggestion is that there are already almost 5 million questions on the site, with tons of code.

AFAIK, you can't just "relicense" a load of code that's already been released under a different license.

Of course, a small info note could be added to pre-existing code to say it's licensed under CC BY-SA, and the footer changed to say user contributions are licensed under *XYZ*, unless otherwise mentioned.

IMO though, this would look a bit silly.

Based on [Jeff's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), it would seem that the reason for choosing CC BY-SA is due to the 'attribution required' element of it. From what I can see from skimming the [MPL](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/), it doesn't seem to be requirement.

Comment: The attribution part isn't the problem. The share-alike part is.

Comment: Some other licenses I'd recommend from skimming [this page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html): the Apache License 2.0 ("You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that you changed the files"), the [Vim License](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Vim7.2) with some SO-specific modifications (see section II[3]), or perhaps the Lesser GPL, which requires modifications be marked as such. Or, the code could be downgraded to CC-BY, which would also be alright.

Comment: "AFAIK, you can't just "relicense" a load of code that's already been released under a different license." I'm not a lawyer, but I confirm this. Only the copyright holder/author can relicense that stuff. Since this is "BY" *we* clearly retained our copyright, and did not pass it on to SE. Relicensing content on this site would require the consent of *every single user* who ever posted something.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby By "all code snippets" I meant "all future code snippets" because of this. I'll edit the post to reflect this.