# The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, licensing, creative-commons

> **Update (Dec. 22, 2015):** Thanks, everyone, for your feedback to this proposal. We're going to digest this one over the holidays and should have a follow-up announcement answering your questions and addressing your concerns after the new year. We won't be making any hurried decisions on this topic, and certainly not without ample opportunity to integrate your ideas into the final decision. So continue letting us know what you think. You'll hear again from us soon.
>
> **Update (Jan. 14, 2016):** [The promised follow-up is here, requiring attribution and postponing the change to March 1, 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1).

CC-BY-SA is an ideal license for a crowdsourced knowledge base. We’ve benefited immensely from it, our community has gained protection through it, and we look forward to CC-BY-SA continuing to cover prose contributions to Stack Overflow and across the network for all of eternity.

But code is a bit different (pun intended), and it’s always been a little ambiguous how CC-BY-SA covers code. This has led to uncertainty among conscientious developers as they've struggled to understand what (if anything) the license requires of them when grabbing a few lines of code from a post on Stack Exchange. Uncertainty is a drag on productivity, for you and for us, and we feel obligated to make code use more clear.

**Starting Feb 1, 2016, all new code contributions to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange will be covered by the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).**

We’ve been working on this problem for a little while now. We’ve consulted with the OSI, enlisted the help of a real-life lawyer, and discussed it exhaustively internally. We’ve come up with a solution that we think is a major improvement upon the status quo.

The new license terms, in brief:

Starting **February 1, 2016**, contributions across the network will be licensed to the public under the following terms:

- Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the terms of CC-BY-SA
- Code contributions will be available for use under the terms of the MIT License
- You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution *upon request* of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

That last bullet makes using Stack Exchange easy, and provides added protection to code contributors and users.

For the vast majority of developers, the above is Too Much Information. The new licensing terms don’t change anything. You can do everything you did before and maybe more when you visit Stack Overflow: copy code, tinker, fiddle, put it in your project, and keep building.

But to future-proof your work, we recommend you do one of these 2 things, or both:

- A) Add a comment to your code that links back to the post where you found it, or
- B) Comply with the MIT as it’s typically used, by including the full license text in your source

You’re doing option A already, right? This is just standard operating procedure when it comes to finding code on the internet – a hyperlink comment ensures you’ll be able to debug down the line. But under the new terms a hyperlink comment is more than just pragmatic, it’s a hat-tip, and it’s a tit-for-tat that ensures you’ve complied with a contributor’s terms.

**We want to know what you think about the terms described above.** Before you let us know, a few anticipated questions answered in brief:

**Is it really that simple?**

It’s pretty simple. We’re optimizing for ease of compliance and clarity. This scheme lets you be compliant even if you don’t do a thing. You just have to do a thing – provide credit – when and if the original poster asks for it.

**My project is Open Source, can't I just include the MIT License?**

Yes. Taking advantage of the notice preservation exception is completely optional. When the new terms launch, we'll have easy to follow guidelines in the help center on how to be compliant for a variety of use cases.

**What about code contributed before February 1, 2016?**

This is just a first step in alleviating licensing ambiguity for users of Stack Overflow and other [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). Code that was contributed prior to February 1, 2016 will be available for use as it has always been, under the terms of CC-BY-SA. We are looking into ways we might allow users to opt-in old code contributions to the new scheme.

**What about other sites in the Stack Exchange network?**

These terms will go into effect for all code posted after Feb. 1 on all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

**Who came up with this scheme?**

You can blame or optionally thank [Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post), [Britton Payne](http://copyrighton.com) and [Sam Brand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/896802/) for this. They also had an enormous amount of help from the [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/).

**What’s next?**

We hope to roll this out February 1, 2016. We know it’s short notice, but we think the proposed terms are a decisive improvement over status quo, and so a change probably can’t come early enough. Please let us know what you think.

Comment: Thank you so much. <3

Comment: For bullet 3, as a contributor we automatically opt out of (attribution?). So to automatically opt-in, we include the license in our code snippets? Or anywhere within the post?

Comment: How does this work for edits of existing code post 1st Jan? Does there exist a halfway state where part of a code block is under one license and the other part another?

Comment: How are we defining code? If I write "code" but dont put it int a `code block`, is it counted as code? Also, what about things like math blocks on the Math.SE site? Im guessing that would go under CC-By-SA? ([related meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271117/what-is-code))

Comment: How are you defining the difference between prose and code? What if I argue that my Python code is perfect English, and that therefore it's prose and is covered under CC-BY-SA?

Comment: Crap, *crap*, **crap**.  This is not even "what do you think of changing the license", this is a "we **will** change the license".  This is not your work, you have no right to decide this.  Shame on you.

Comment: @HansPassant Code contributed before this is exempt: "Code that was contributed prior to January 1, 2016 will be available for use as it has always been, under the terms of CC-BY-SA"

Comment: You say you want to know what we think, but it will go into effect Jan 1 regardless. I support this change but am offended at your pretense of caring what we think.

Comment: So if I want to make sure people attribute code they used from me in their source do I have to put that on every answer or can it be on the user profile?

Comment: Can we make the link back to SO in the code a hard requirement? I don't care about the full MIT license notice but I think the link is useful.

Comment: @NathanOliver Do people actually look at user profiles?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom If we were going to "just do it" we would have, and then announced it. The whole point of this post is to get feedback _before_ we do it. Coulda probably been worded to make that clearer, good point there.

Comment: Will this license have the same provisions as far as who *owns* the content, and who has the rights to remove it, as the current CC license does? I certainly wouldn't want to lose the ability to keep content whether the contributor wants it there or not.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I could have worded that more carefully. We want to send a strong message that a license shift is happening Jan 1. This is our best foot forward after years of investigation. Let us know how you think we can improve the terms and we will give them serious consideration.

Comment: I don't like how attribution isn't required for code. I tend to choose CC-BY for content I post elsewhere on the Internet (where I have a choice) and Apache 2.0 is my go-to software license. Both require attribution. True MIT requires attribution by way of the license (it requires the license, including the copyright line, to be included in a project that uses it). Effectively, text that I write on SO requires attribution, but anyone can use my code...dislike that.

Comment: Did you consider using something even more permissive like Public Domain or CC0? I still don't entirely understand the attribution requirements in your current proposal, with the exception to the license that isn't actually in the license

Comment: It would be nice if there was a checkbox somewhere that would enable or disable an inclusion of the notice on every answer I post. Otherwise, I'll have to include the notice on every single answer I post manually. Or make attribution a requirement if you don't want to complicate the UI.

Comment: If you take the MIT License and waive the copyright notice requirement, what's left?  Isn't that essentially public domain with a disclaimer of liability?

Comment: I think it's ludicrous that this is something people spend time on, what happened with common sense or public domain?  If I ask you a question in the street and a passer by hears the answer I don't care.  Posting stuff on stackoverflow, it being text, code or whatever is basically the same as shouting it from the rooftops - _how_ can it be anything other than public domain/licence-free?

Comment: @MadScientist we did consider that, but decided it was user-unfriendly to require contributors to relinquish their copyright over their work.

Comment: @samthebrand What was the rationale for getting rid of requiring attribution?

Comment: @ChristofferBubach: Ah yes, the old "it's on the web, therefore it's public domain" nonsense. Please, no. That's not supported by any legal theory I'm aware of, and for rather good reason.

Comment: Is there any chance that in the future there might be a canonical way to specify that you'd like to do things like waive the attribution requirement for your own contributions or that you'd like to retroactively apply this change to all contributions?

Comment: @NathanOliver These terms acknowledge the reality that very many users never complied with previous attribution guidance.

Comment: @samthebrand So we just reward them by getting rod of the requirement?  That does not seem right to me.

Comment: @samthebrand "We want to send a strong message that a license shift is happening Jan 1." -- that's my point.  It's a _[fait accompli](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fait_accompli)_.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom we have every opportunity to modify the proposed terms up until that point. Do you have any suggested modifications?

Comment: @Flexo Most edits will produce a derivative work, which will continue to be licensed under whatever license applied to the original code. However, a substantial edit might be said to create an entirely new work, for which the current license would apply. To be on the safe side, always include a comment with a link back to the post so that revisions and authors can be tracked - whether the license is CC or MIT, giving credit where credit is due is always a good choice.

Comment: What happens when someone posts code they don't own the copyright to (for example, to explain a bug in third-party code their answer works around)?  If the user attributes to the SO post, there's a chance of figuring out what happened (IANAL but "good faith" may now apply, for whatever that's worth); with no attribution it looks like the code was just copied.  (Also, while you're working on the license, it might help to clarify the poster's obligations when quoting third-party code.)

Comment: @samthebrand If attribution is "always a good choice", why isn't it a hard requirement?

Comment: `Add a comment to your code that links back to the post where you found it` - This is good advice, even ignoring legal requirements, and even if the code didn't come from Stackoverflow.

Comment: CC-BY-SA is fine for the text and explanations, but we all know that the code will be copied. In most cases this will be fair use, but...

So I can see what you are getting at. BUT MIT without attribution is not MIT. Just say "code fragments are public domain" and have done with it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, A nightclub is not a party, it is a business which provides a party-like experience. StackOverflow is not a community, it is a business which provides a community-like experience. Of course they don't care what we think. They never did, nor ever will, because they don't know us personally and people are biologically unable to care about people they don't know. They might make a good pretense of it - As McCloskey said commerce generates civility - but they aren't really our friends.

Comment: @Ben I care. I do.

Comment: `as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder` Since there's no active notification when someone grabs my code from SO, **isn't this *for all practical purposes* saying all code submissions should be understood to be in the public domain?** Then why not say that + give a USE AT YOUR OWN RISK warning? (Or you need to actually enforce a copyleft.) (And, natch, keep in mind that it's still no protection when Shameless Joe pastes copyrighted code from his company's repo, though we'll never fix that...) Still, big step in a better direction; thanks.

Comment: @Ben, I think you're making too much of a dichotomy between businesses and people. To say a business can't care _by definition_ is to ignore what it's made of.

Comment: So, public domain as a *thing* doesn't actually exist everywhere, @ruffin - this is one of the problems that licenses like CC-0 have tried to attack. But beyond that, it's *really* not cool to tell people that merely by posting here they're giving up **authorship** of what they wrote. Presumably if you're posting on Stack Exchange you *want* others to benefit from what you've written... But that doesn't mean you want them passing it off as their own work! No one should have to make that trade-off.

Comment: What happens with Code Golf and Code Review where we're not talking about snippits but often more substantial works.  I seem to recall a now SE employee having a bit in the profile that said something to the effect "I license all code I contribute on sites other than code golf and code review under..."

Comment: @Shog9 Public domain's limited applicability is an excellent point. `give reasonable attribute upon request` kills your second, I'm afraid. Attribution-less MIT is not MIT. You really need a new license, I think, and *you need to decide if we care that I'm using Skeet's `DictionaryBackedSet` in my code.* ^ (Note in my profile that I already do exactly what SO's proposed. Consider my code dual-licensed: Whatever SO says + MIT. And I won't get upset if you don't attribute. Just use at your own risk. **So I do like this,** but as is, it's just not clean.) ^ Ok, ok, I attribute Jon, fwiw. ;^)

Comment: Like you said, @ruffin, nothing's stopping Joe from using whatever he wants without attribution *today* - unless his co-workers are keeping him honest, of course. We can't, you can't, no ToS or license is gonna make a difference there either. This really only matters in two scenarios: someone who *wants* to do the right thing and can't figure out how, and someone who *wants* to do the wrong thing **in public** and needs a stick to be hit with. So primary intent here is to make #1 as simple as possible without losing #2.

Comment: I have an interesting question: is "Code" explicitly defined here, and if we want to release our code under a different license (such as GPL, or similar), are there going to be conflict issues here?

Comment: While I realize this was posted on MSO first, there's that whole "We were Stack Exchange before, we are Stack Overflow now" thing and the statement "we will be licensing all new code contributions to Stack Overflow under the MIT License."  Is CodeReview.SE and CodeGolf.SE (and Programmers, Wordpress, GIS, GameDev, TeX, RaspberryPi, ...) part of this "Stack Overflow" umbrella? or is this only for the code posted to the site StackOverflow.com?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg It is a good question. We have some thoughts about this (hint: pseudo code probably isn't code), but we figured this is probably of secondary concern to the broad proposal. If you'd like to ask a separate Meta question I'll try hard to give you an answer in the next day or two.

Comment: @MichaelT Good question. This is something that's confusing to even us in the company and we're trying to standardize how we address Stack Overflow vs. other code communities in the network vs. SE as a whole. Consider this a proposal for a network-wide change. I should have done a better job of communicating that.

Comment: @samthebrand If this is entire network wide, it will have a ***very*** large impact on sites that don't post snippits of code, but rather entire working programs (Code Review), and [large unique solutions to difficult problems](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/30292/12166) (Code Golf). If this is the type of material going under MIT in the future it can significantly stifle future use of the sites.

Comment: @Shog9 "it's really not cool to tell people that merely by posting here they're giving up authorship of what they wrote" You're talking about people giving an example bit of code to help a user solve a problem, in their spare time with no expectation a reward outside of the reputation system. Just like every other forum on the internet. This site could (should, really) have done this right at the start and we'd not even be having this conversation. I doubt anyone's posted stuff here with any other expectation. What's next? Slashdot copyright battles? "The monster stole my comment!"

Comment: How does this impact on: 1) people who explicitly mention a license in their profile (for example, to avoid any issues at all I have this down as CC0) and 2) sites where an alternative license is more appropriate (as a moderator on the TeX site, I'd say the most applicable 'fall back' license for us would be the LPPL).

Comment: Ok, that does happen and has caused drama on /., but we're not talking about /. here, @Alex. Meanwhile, folks don't like to see people ripping off their work here anymore than they do anywhere else; in particular, folks object to seeing the entire site mirrored with attribution given to fake names created to lure in unsuspecting readers and stuffed with ads and malware. So yeah, the trick is finding a way to balance the intent of the author (to help) with their desire not to contribute to the greater Internet Miasma.

Comment: @MichaelT Noted. We will have specific discussions with members of those communities to discuss how they feel about the proposed change. The community team will give close attention to any related meta discussions happening at those sites.

Comment: @samthebrand posted followup here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271117/what-is-code

Comment: @JosephWright Good question. I wrestled with this for a bit myself, and then realized it's actually pretty simple: You are free to dual license your contributions however you like, but users will always be free to also use your code under the license in the terms of service. We will make this even more clear in an upcoming help center article.

Comment: @samthebrand re edits: whose substantial changes would count for changing the license? What if I go back and make substantial changes to someone else's posts? Are those posts now "derivative works" and thus using the new license and attribution is no longer required? What if I only updated the explanation on the post and not the code?

Comment: @Shog9 Protecting the site is something entirely different; most of this site is discussion about code, not the code itself.  I don't claim to speak for anyone else, but when I post here it's not "work". I don't think of it as work; it's a bit of optional typing in my spare time.  If someone else uses it, for free, in their code, well...good. That's the whole point. I don't want anything in return. It's not "ripping me off", it's just "using this site" and ideally people would feel moved to help out this site in the same way in return (hence the reputation system).

Comment: @samthebrand No, don't have specific discussions with each community. Having separate licensing discussions for each community would result in license fragmentation beyond the license fragmentation that you are already proposing. If we don't have a uniform license policy for all of Stack Exchange, then how would migrations of posts even be possible?

Comment: You feel that way, and bless you for it @Alex. Others feel differently, and very strongly so. Believe me, there's no way we'd open this can of worms if they didn't...

Comment: Eh hem hem... Any questions about this can be asked at [Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com

Comment: @samthebrand, really? I'll bet you didn't know I existed until just now, but you'll claim to care about me nonetheless. I'll bet that what you care about is maintaining that community-like experience: Nothing to do with me specifically.

Comment: This is a genuine effort from SE.. Thank you so much. And of course, I believe those who commit work will feel the same way. I love how SE are always looking out for us.

Comment: @Ben I consider myself very lucky to work for a company where community and business goals are pretty much always aligned. By "community" I mean anyone who bothers to pay attention to Meta - high bar - or maybe even anyone who gets even a little bit of help building things thanks to Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange. I genuinely want to know what you think. Nothing here is set in stone.

Comment: I take it that this means I can copy the code in one answer and post it as my own answer and not credit the post I copied it from? You are expliitly giving me the right, permission, and expectation, not to.

Comment: I fully support the changes.  For exactly the reasons @Alex enumerates.  I don't post code on SE because I want to own it, control it, control what others do with it, or receive attribution for posting it.  I post code to _help people solve problems_.  I want them to be able to use the code that I post freely and easily and in whatever manner they choose, without having to jump through any legal hoops or worry about whether or not they're following my "license terms" correctly.  If I wasn't okay with that, I wouldn't post the code _in the first place_.

Comment: Smile, everybody: [you're on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3x407x/stack_overflow_changing_code_submissions_to_use/)!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this change is being made, and honestly (since I'm not too license-savvy), don't have a good sense of what it means at all. Could you guys possibly edit to add an explanation?

Comment: What happens if I do not copy paste code but use a code based answer to solver my problem, writing my own code from scratch?
Seriously, I really was hoping SO would not be dealing with this stuff, always thought code on SO is public domain, code I read, code I wrote, anything here is public domain. I can reproduce the code, but make look different than the original, (e.g. use switch case instead of if else if) . Would that mean I copied or not?

Comment: There should be no distinction between code and non-code. [Debian](http://debian.org)'s [DFSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Free_Software_Guidelines) don't make such difference for good reasons. See [this](https://people.debian.org/~bap/dfsg-faq#docs) and [this](https://people.debian.org/~bap/dfsg-faq#not_just_code) answers from the [DFSG FAQ](https://people.debian.org/~bap/dfsg-faq).

Comment: If they cared about license ambiguity, there is a non-profit whos been working hard on clearing that up, yet no mention of them, and no where on this list http://creativecommons.org/supporters. Ambiguity is mostly gone, since cc-by-sa is now compatible with gpl: http://creativecommons.org/weblog/2015/10/08/46186

Comment: Huh, I bet you didn't expect such an outburst of objections, @sam. Or did you?

Comment: @aroth Can you explain how you support the changes for reasons I stated, as i'm against the changes (specifically the license chosen) given that it does not allow people to use your posted code in any manner they choose as they are left with certain obligations.

Comment: This ought to be advertised prominently on the front page of all sites that could possibly include computer code. It is too big and too fundamental a change to be mentioned only here in Meta where hardly anyone will come to see it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It's featured network-wide in the sidebar

Comment: @JosephWright I know. That is not prominent enough. At the very least the title of this thread needs to be "ATTENTION: MAJOR CHANGE TO TERMS AND CONDITIONS", not some vague "clarity" message.

Comment: @Shog9 `You feel that way, and bless you for it @Alex. Others feel differently [about SO being 'work product'], and very strongly so.` Wait, what? It's always been CC licensed. Broken licesnse or not, those "Others" really missed the boat. In other news, **will we have two CSS classes, one for "code authored or edited before MIT" and one to clearly show what came after?** And will the terms say that editing pre-MIT code makes it MIT?

Comment: When (if) this change rolls out, please provide a "before" and "after" example of what properly attributed snippets should look like.  To me, it sounds like you're changing the minimum attribution from `//found on SO` to `//found on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questionid/answerid`, or including the MIT license file in the source

Comment: @Alex - I was specifically referring to "If someone else uses it, for free, in their code, well...good. That's the whole point. I don't want anything in return. It's not 'ripping me off'".  I agree with that sentiment, 100%, and that's why I wholly support the change.  Any obligations that the MIT license imposes are _insignificant_ compared to the ones imposed under CC-BY-SA.  The former is a permissive license, the latter is copyleft.

Comment: @Gus: You're substantially understating your obligations under the status quo.  "`//found on SO`" is way insufficient, right now you need to attribute the particular author, link back to the original answer and the author's profile page, and release your derived or composite work under CC BY-SA or compatible.  But IANAL, so maybe you should do even more than that.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah, that uncertainty is what I'm worrying about, TBH.  Having a sample that is a "known good" template would be pretty helpful, even if there's no new license.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I expected worse.

Comment: @Shog9  I agree with you 100% .

Comment: So, what about the code in the questions? That code is not necessarily being provided as a giveaway, especially not on Code Review. I understand that if code is being presented in an answer, there's an understanding that you're releasing the code to others and you're okay with it (as long as you're the author), but that's certainly not the case for the questions themselves -- especially, as I've mentioned, on Code Review. I understand this is a good way for SO to cover their butts; however, is this the right approach?  We're certainly not being given enough time to decide that, as a community.

Comment: `When the new terms launch, we'll have easy to follow guidelines in the help center on how to be compliant for a variety of use cases.` Maybe it would ease some of our confusion if you posted those guidelines now.

Comment: This is awesome, I once had to find an SO contributor and ask him to relicense some lines of code under a software friendly license. MIT is a great choice given the range of users.

Comment: I definitely don't understand everything about this, but is it at all possible for comment snippets to be auto-inserted at the start of all code blocks, i.e `/* Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234567890/some_title\n Author John Doe (http://stackoverflow.com....)*/`

Comment: I have >10K rep across other SE sites, and I cant downvote this because of where the question has moved to.  Thanks.

Comment: You've been a member for six years and haven't earned any rep? Aptly named...

Comment: Is pseudo code code or non code?

Comment: Would you say this is a license based on **a)** MIT without attribution unless requested? or **b)** MIT with attribution upon request? The difference would be that if someone lost means of being notified or changing their copy of unattributed code, one interpretation relieves them of any blame (or potentially legal issues) while the other does not. (Or if that's not what those two phrases mean, then what happens if someone is unable to add back in attribution?)

Comment: Can users only post code which they have the right to distribute under the MIT without attribution licence? If so, work which is derivative under the LPPL or which is derived from GPL code or... cannot be posted. If not, I assume code should carry a licence notice where it differs. But then can't I do the same thing if my code is not derived? [Mind you, I still don't understand whether TeX code is 'code' or not as no definition has been provided and this is not a clear case, even if other cases are clear.]

Comment: I sort of thought that the *whole point* of stack overflow was volunteering to help other people solve their problems.  Prior to this thread, it literally never even occurred to me that someone would want anything more than attribution as I copied code from their answer into my work.  And I actually assumed that somewhere in the EULA I'd already given away rights to any code I post, because why wouldn't I?  That's the whole point!  I certainly never looked in anyone's profile to see if they have license notes.  Big thumbs up from me; this site needs a permissive license to run smoothly, IMO.

Comment: Assuming we don't take advantage of the notice preservation statement, **what do we put in the copyright line**? I don't foresee every poster putting "Copyright &copy; Their Real Name 2016" at the start of every snippet.

Comment: @Shog9 - I just mean that its a meta site for stackexchange. Rep across them should count here, for at least something as simple as downvoting. But this is totally off topic, so I will stop.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't even aware that there was previously any sort of licensing. I have to agree with some of the others here, if a user asks a question, and you choose to post code to answer that question, you just made it public domain. You aren't required to answer questions here, or to post any code. If you do so, you've deemed that the potential rep is all the reward you need, or that you care about helping the user more than any sort of ROI the code you provide might have.

Comment: What's the problem that this is intended to solve? I don't see what's ambiguous (but just for code and not for prose) about CC-BY-SA.

Comment: I hereby put all my contributions on any stackexchange also under public domain, cc-0, WTF license. Actually I just give up copyright to all my contributions here. They shall be completely free. Well and why? Because I don't do any of it here for me and so I don't need anything in return.

Comment: @ruffin "And will the terms say that editing pre-MIT code makes it MIT?" I think that this should not be possible in general. After all you cannot change the license without asking the copyright holder, and the copyright holder are the original authors, not Stackexchange (CC is copyleft). So what was once not modified MIT cannot become modified MIT just like this. But I'm not a lawyer, so maybe it's possible.

Comment: Does this mean that Mojang doesn't have to give us all attribution anymore for copy-and-paste programming minecraft from SO? ;)

Comment: @Trilarion Sorry, good clarification. Meant if you edited your own answer/code. As the SO code starts to gain some extra legacy cruft... ;^)

Comment: @samthebrand, 2 points: (1) you say, "*we* will be licensing all new code contributions to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange under the MIT License" (emphasis mine). That's rather distastefully worded: it suggests you think those contributions are yours to license, which they aren't. It would be less disingenuous to say, "*we* will be changing *our* T&C to require *you* (i.e. Stack Exchange users) to license *your* code contributions to *us* under the MIT License, if you wish to publish them on Stack Exchange." (2) Will you enable users to opt-out (besides simply ceasing to contribute)?

Comment: @200_success has my same point. It seems SE wants a non-copyleft license which doesn't require attribution other than by linking: the most suitable tool for this is [CC-0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). MIT is all about mentioning the copyright holder and the license; if you remove that, it's no longer MIT, call it something else.

Comment: Sorry if this was asked already but is there clarification as to how this affects code snippets that are referenced from open source libraries that may have an existing license that isn't MIT?

Comment: I'd like to know, if this "do[es]n’t change anything", how did StackExchange decide on CC-BY-SA before? It's obvious that it isn't intended for computer code, as well as being morally as different from "MIT without attribution" as it's possible to be. So, are we to understand that SE had no idea what they were doing and mistakenly chose a licence with terms they did not understand, which were somehow completely opposite to their intention? Can we believe it's different now--how thorough was the legal advice you received, really? Or is this actually a more major change than you want to admit?

Comment: @Nemo The legal text of CC-0 uses the phrase "in all territories worldwide".  Maybe stack exchange is worried about complications if people on a prospective Martian settlement try to make use of the site.

Comment: @OleksandrR. That decision happened waaaaaay before my time, so take this with a grain of salt, but my suspicion is that not that much thought went into figuring out all possible legal implications of CC-BY-SA as it applied to code at the time while the focus was more on "let's get this startup off the ground and see if anyone even uses the site".

Comment: @OleksandrR. At the time, the envisioned use case was lots of text accompanied by short snippets of code - snippets so short that their ability to be copyrighted at all was questionable, or certainly (if third party) 'fair use' as examples in an educational type of setting. It was 2008 and the ship had to sail. A very, very different world. It's nearly 2016 now, and we need to update. Our counsel _teaches copyright law_ at Fordham - specifically around software and user contributed content. I'm quite certain he knows what he's doing.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for your reply. I would encourage you to engage your counsel on the points raised in the answers--particularly whether the non-attribution option may open the code consumer to liability given that the provenance of the code and terms of the licence will not be apparent later on, the interpretation of this non-attribution scheme in jurisdictions where moral rights cannot be waived, and reuse problems caused by mixing incompatibly licensed content within the same threads and even the same posts. If you will convincingly address these three issues, I could support the proposal.

Comment: @TimPost please remember that you are in a very privileged position as the (sub)licensor, being able to choose any terms you find convenient and located in the USA, where concepts of "fair use" and "public domain" have legal standing. Many users and visitors to the site are not so fortunate, and for them, your intent when choosing licensing terms or interpretation of those terms unfortunately does not matter one bit. All they have is the licence itself and its interpretation in their own jurisdiction. I fear you are making things difficult for people by ignoring issues that don't affect you.

Comment: @aug IIRC some of the answers cover this point; I only find http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271296#comment880555_271296 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271106#comment880551_271106 right now.

Comment: Under CC, would it violate the license for closed-source software to not give attribution for any snippets used?

Comment: **No. Noo. Nooooooo**. This post makes me sick.

Comment: Look at the first part of the MIT license.  Will answers have to add `Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>` to each answer?  Will SO add it to each?  Whom would it acknowledge?  Removing the copyright and.or permission notice means it is not MIT at all as others have pointed out.  The whole thing of this part is implied in our TOS but users can opt back in (somehow) is Rube Goldberg at best, confusing for certain.  If a scamp gets some code from SO they can cite the TOS and non-License verbiage to negate everything else.

Comment: @sampablokuper Good catch. I modified the sentence in question to reflect your suggested edit (that we the company are sublicensing from contributors).

Comment: @TimPost - Don't you think it would be wise to seek the council of someone who practices law instead of who researches it? Considering the size of Stack Exchange it makes sense to seek someone of equal caliber, and one who is a trial lawyer and not an observer.

Comment: @samthebrand Any progress on my [question on what is code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271117/what-is-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-proposed-mit-license-switchover)?

Comment: I don't think I can justify to myself to keep posting answers containing code if this goes live.

Comment: @samthebrand, good. Now, what about the other point in my comment? I don't currently feel comfortable licensing code to you/SO/SE under the terms you've proposed in your post. It's also evident from the answers and comments here that you've made quite a few other people similarly uncomfortable.

Comment: Is your little code stub of 5 lines really soooo amazingly engenius that you need to protect it with a kafka-esque license ? A license that nobody will ever read (including whoever reads this) (as Plutonix has pointed out). And if somebody copies your code anyway, will you hunt them down to court? International copyright infringement cases are extremely complicated and expensive? Things like this just don't happen.

Comment: @bvdb, (1) SO's proposed crayon/nonsense license is, IMO, much more kafka-esque than CC-BY-SA 3.0. (2) I have read CC-BY-SA 3.0, as have many others who wish to respect (a) the law & (b) others' wishes. (3) While some code posted to SO/SE is not original/creative enough to be entitled to copyright, the rest *is* entitled to it. (4) I doubt anyone here *wants* to have their rights infringed & to have to consider suing. That does not mean they should simply *give up their rights*. CC-BY-SA 3.0 is hardly onerous to comply with. It requires pretty minimal courtesy; a fair trade, surely!

Comment: I'm always taken by surprise at how bitter and twisted developers can get over open source licensing. This really isn't worth spending any energy on. The standard that I hold myself to is that if I give code away at all, then I do it wholeheartedly with no strings attached whatsoever. If there HAS to be a license, then I'd use the MIT because it is as close as you can get to "anyone can do anything at all without limitation", which is what I really mean.

Comment: @Christoffer Bubach you have it exactly right. I suppose SO has to protect themselves legally somehow, but beyond that it doesn't matter a jot. If people don't want others to benefit from their code, then not posting it on a public web site would be an excellent way to avoid that. It is utterly ridiculous to think these tiny code snippets should be covered by any kind of license other than "fair use". I believe that is probably the intent of using MIT, but honestly it would have been better to just not poke the hornet's nest.

Comment: @TimLong, you say, "if I give code away at all, then I do it wholeheartedly with no strings attached whatsoever. If there HAS to be a license, then I'd use the MIT". That being so, I don't see why you're commenting here, since your desires are satisfied regardless whether the proposed change goes ahead or not. I.e. if you want to use MIT or CC0 on SO/SE right now, there's nothing stopping you: your code contributions are automatically licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0 as per the TOS, & you can dual-license them under MIT/CC0/etc wherever you see fit. The change will neither benefit nor disrupt you.

Comment: @TimLong, In short, since you are not affected by the proposed change, please don't presume to speak on behalf of those on SO/SE who will feel negatively affected by the proposed change.

Comment: @TimLong, you also say, "If people don't want others to benefit from their code, then not posting it on a public web site would be an excellent way to avoid that." That is absolutist thinking: all or nothing; black and white. It ignores the fact that there is a wide (and welcome!) spectrum of middle ground, for which the FSF and Creative Commons licenses are excellent fits. It's to the credit of the founders of SO that they chose such a good license: it helped create a flourishing ecosystem where respect for contributors was important. I hope they keep it that way.

Comment: MIT license might be good enough for most users but that doesn't give right to SE team to force them. Let the users themselves choose the license. Forcing it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @khajvah SE is not proposing the MIT license but a new ad hoc license which is not really free software.

Comment: @A E: The problem with CC-BY-SA is it ALSO requires you to publish derived works under CC-BY-SA as well. What's ambiguous is whether a million line project plus a 3-line snippet of code from SO constitutes a derived work, requiring all million lines of source to be republished as CC-BY-SA? The answer: probably yes, on close examination, it does, although that's ambiguous. The overwhelming majority of professionally-written code written in this world cannot use any code licensed under GPL (and most of it cannot use LGPL either), CC-BY-SA, on close examination, seems to be just as bad.

Comment: @khajvh: Forcing everyone who uses an answer I provide on SO to spend half an hour working out what license my 3 line code snippet that I posted with the full intent that anyone can do anything with it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @RobinDavies Which is why SE can create an easy way of displaying the license within ever answer.

Comment: See also the highly upvoted discussion at Meta.Stackoverflow: [Can we get some explicit clarification on the *intended* legal usage of code from SO answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro)

Comment: Two things that I still haven't seen addressed: 1. Don't call it MIT. MIT has three sections: A. Do whatever you want except B. virality (must also be licensed under MIT) and C. warranty disclaimer. You've stripped out the virality part and monkey-patched in your own vague definition. You should really call it "The Stack Exchange License" or something. 2. I having trouble empathizing. What exactly are the troubles people run into when trying to use code under the current license? How does this fix it?

Comment: Also to me the attribution requirement feels like it might as well not be there at all. I believe you mentioned at one point that this is becuase this is what happens anyway, but you're simply opening the gates wider. Now an honest user of code thinks it's just fine to go about without any attribution unless someone complains. This is much worse. As it is right now, this is an absolutely horrible idea and should not be carried out if you want to continue as a business.

Comment: I would like a license rather that allows anyone to do literally anything with my code but relicense it under a stricter license.

Comment: Don't the terms of service make answers qualify as works of hire? (I'm no lawyer, I'm trying to figure how anyone thinks they "own" code they were asked to create.)

Comment: I really feel that this move is best however it is not clear what is and isn't code within a question. Why not just change the license for all content to [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)? [Another related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254757/1730559).

Comment: That Feb 1 date is getting pretty close now without any further update...... you guys still on holidays?

Comment: @kjbartel We're back! We've been back! Keep an eye for an announcement tomorrow or the next day. And rest easy on that Feb 1 date. The transition will happen weeks after that.

Comment: @samthebrand Thanks for the reply. Look forward to the announcement. And glad to hear (the implication) that you haven't given up on the transition despite the top voted answers here being rather negative.

Comment: If you remove the question now, you will get a badge :P

Comment: Another downvote comment.   Not enough rep, so... SO is just getting to be a pain in the ass.  Code Golf and Code Review should be split off into independent sites and stop screwing everything else up.

Comment: @samthebrand Should the post be edited -- it still says Feb 01 in the body

Comment: Stackoverflow is code snippets. I wasn't aware people were supposed to attribute to me my for loop that outputs the numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: On CodeWars sometimes 100 people or more will all come up with the exact same solution. Should it be licensed? Licensed to whom? CodeWars uses the [BSD-2 Clause License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause).

Comment: So... 3 years later, the [Public Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) still lists CC-BY-SA, not MIT. As much as this post clearly states the licence is MIT, without the TOS updating, it's not yet the case. Any updates there?

Comment: @glasnt, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370418/632951

Answer (score 773):

In essence, this proposal is to move from a copyleft license (CC-BY-SA 3.0) to a permissive license for code.  (By default, it's basically the most permissive license possible, nearly equivalent to public domain with a liability disclaimer.)

Having thought about it for a couple of hours, I've shifted my opinion from ["I'm not sure"](/a/271082/148099) to "Please reconsider — this is truly awful."  (Sorry to sound dramatic, but [@Laura suggests](/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code#comment878760_271082) that that's what it will take.)

I suppose that the rationale for the change is to protect users of Stack Overflow answers from (hopefully hypothetical) copyright trolls whose modus operandi is:

1. Post code in a Stack Overflow answer
2. Wait for the code to be incorporated into some software project
3. Sue or extort
4. Win or settle
5. Profit!

To preempt that low-probability, high-stakes terroristic threat, we're being faced with a proposal that imposes huge costs on all Stack Exchange communities.

### Wrong attitude

When I contribute an answer on Stack Exchange, I like to think that I am sharing knowledge, not giving away code, even if my answer happens to contain code.  Also, we as a community expect questions to be more like "How should I …?" rather than "Can anyone gimme teh codez to do …?"  The Creative Commons license expresses the knowledge-sharing attitude.  The MIT License most certainly does not.

### MIT License: inappropriate for questions

When someone posts a question, whether to Stack Overflow, Code Review, WordPress, Raspberry Pi, or any other Stack Exchange site, I don't believe that there is any intention to donate that code to the public domain (technically not PD, but in practice indistinguishable).

For Code Review, in particular, the code being shared is usually substantial, often a complete runnable program.  The intention is to share code **for discussion, not to give code away**.  A permissive license that allows commercial exploitation without attribution could discourage a lot of questions.  It could also encourage users to withhold parts of their code, hindering open discussion.

Sometimes questions are actually homework solutions.  It would be helpful to have the attribution requirement as an additional legal tool to combat plagiarism, in addition to the usual moral/academic standards.

### MIT License: inappropriate for answers

We want the Internet to take the knowledge and advice that they learn from answers to improve their code and their skills.  We do not expect them to just take the code as a product.

If the answer is trivial (e.g. "Just use this library function that does exactly what you need"), then [common sense says that there is no copyright licensing issue](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/05/16/1612228/judge-to-oracle-a-high-schooler-could-write-rangecheck).  You just learned something about the obvious way to accomplish something.

If the answer contains a substantial original contribution of ready-to-use code, then attribution should be required by default.

Let's take a hypothetical extreme example: someone publishes an [O'Reilly-style cookbook](//english.stackexchange.com/q/182437/16310) consisting of code snippets extracted from Stack Overflow, Code Review, PPCG, ….  Only the code blocks are taken; all of the surrounding text is reworded.  No attribution is given.  How would you feel about that?

### License fragmentation is bad

License fragmentation breaks the remix culture that Creative Commons seeks to establish.  With this proposal, we would have

- Pre-2016 contributions, which are CC-BY-SA
- Post-2016 code under MIT-but-no-attribution-required
- Post-2016 code for which the poster elected to use the standard MIT license
- Post-2016 non-code contributions

Distinguishing what content falls under which license seems like a bit of a nightmare to me.  And that's not even considering edits on top of existing posts, or questions that are loosely inspired by other posts (as [often happens on Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches)).

In summary, please don't do this to us.

Comment: I will want to thoroughly agree with this and point out that I do not want questions that I post to Code Review or answers that I post to Code Golf to be licensed with a permissive software license that allows inclusion of the contained code into other projects.

Comment: Thanks for this. While I don't agree 100% with your philosophy around sharing code on Stack Overflow and across the network, I value knowing that you and probably many others feel this way. We will carefully consider this feedback. Also, please feel free to start a related discussion on Code Review to let us know how that community specifically feels about these proposed changes.

Comment: @samthebrand Code Review did have a post to discuss the license proposal. I migrated it here to be closed as a duplicate so that we can centralize the discussion. It is important that we decide on a uniform licensing policy throughout the Stack Exchange network to ensure the free flow of information and to allow migrations to work. Let's not build walled ghettoes.

Comment: @200_success is there a license you'd prefer to see used? I think we can all agree that a licensed designed for code would be better than the current license. Your disagreement is about the MIT license, correct?

Comment: @RubberDuck [Like BilltheLizard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256656/148099), I view it as sharing knowledge, not sharing code, so I don't agree that using a license designed for code would be better. Furthermore, as other have pointed out here, the line between code and text is blurry (e.g. math and pseudocode).

Comment: Well, then I suppose we don't agree that a code license would be better. I guess I see the code I post for review as "feel free to use this if it helps" and a code license makes sense to me.

Comment: But MIT license does require attribution, via the license text.

Comment: 200_success, this is a good summary of why this is a bad idea. I'd like to add, almost all my code is GPL 3. If stackexchange insists on making it mit licensed, the result would be that I would simply not post any GPL code on stackexchange. The purpose of these sites is to help with code, and I think the GPL is actually quite good about explaining what can and can't be or shouldn't be licensed, and shorter code blocks are one of those things. Other code is proprietary, but could be posted as an answer as a snippet. You can't magically change the licensing at will without repercussions.

Comment: @congusbongus The current SE proposal includes an SE Terms of Service clause waving the attribution requirement unless the copyright holder explicitly demands otherwise.

Comment: `We want the Internet to take the knowledge and advice that they learn from answers to improve their code and their skills. We do not expect them to just take the code as a product.` -- Well, OK, but doesn't that push Stack Overflow even further into "How do I fix my broken code" territory?  The answers that are most useful to others are the ones that actually *have complete, working code* in them. Don't underestimate the educational value of that.  Otherwise, we might as well go down the Math.SE path, and make every answer a **HINT.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see how you jump from my statement to concluding that it pushes us into "fix my broken code territory". Code Review accepts _no_ broken code as questions, and it's entirely about improving programming skills. Answers may or may not contain code; it's irrelevant.

Comment: So your answer only applies to Code Review?

Comment: @RobertHarvey None of my answer applies specifically to Code Review. I believe it applies equally to Stack Overflow and other sites.

Comment: Well, none of what I said applies to Code Review, but the principles are the same.  If I post code to any "question-answer" type venue, I expect anyone coming across it to use it for any purpose whatsoever.  If I wanted my open-source contribution to be regulated specifically by some license, I'd put it on Github, not Stack Overflow or Code Review.

Comment: But then if someone took that code, and posted it minus the license info, here, what would it be? SE had no right to relicense it, yet they would have done that. Or if I post 10 lines out of 10k line gpl program here as a solution, that means those ten lines are now allegedly and magically MIT licensed? I like the spirit of what 200_success says in his answer, if this decision is being made for corporations that want to be free to slice out code for themselves, that's not why I post here, or why I use se. Technically this will have zero impact on me since I will just ignore it.

Comment: My first thoughts when reading this announcement were exactly the same so I'm glad that a highly respected user already wrote them up as a detailed answer. I'm a free software enthusiast. That's why I stand up for copyleft. When I decided to participate on SO, the fact that contributions are CC licensed was crucial for me to be convinced that this is the right thing to do. I'm posting code to build a repository for sharing *free* knowledge, not because I want to be a *gratis* code monkey for somebody who doesn't respect freedom and hence cannot be bothered complying with a copyleft license.

Comment: @Lizardx A ten-line excerpt out of a large GPL project would fall under fair use exception or educational discussion rights, in countries whose copyright law recognizes such rights. Quoting a short excerpt doesn't relicense anything.

Comment: It's an interesting discussion, heh. The problem with your answer above is not the spirit of it, but the fact that this is so much a question of that spirit that I'm not sure any license actually covers that spirit explicitly. As you said above, the MIT license most certainly does not. Re length, then you get to the slippery slope, how many lines then do trigger such events? I don't believe that's settled. Of course, if all code here is MIT licensed, what then is the cutoff? As I believe you noted. Pseudocode? 10 lines? 20? Standard SQL chunks? A 10 line javascript solution?

Comment: 200_success, I had to think about your answer, and you have it nailed: the cc license embodies the sharing aspect, and the MIT is a 'taking' license. I can see why you went through the mental steps to arrive at your conclusion. The only entities who would care about having a taking license are corporations that are worried about being able to freely take, ie, their goal is not sharing, but free and clear access to taking code. This is hostile to the spirit of sharing. I contribute because others shared with me previously, here, and elsewhere. This is also why I do GPL code, sharing.

Comment: @200_success Google was convicted of infringement for [a 9-line function](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/)...

Comment: @200_success: "A ten-line excerpt out of a large GPL project" *into a blog post with rights reserved* would generally fall under criticism or educational fair use exceptions.  Putting that same excerpt into a Stack Overflow question or answer is against the terms of service.  Specifically, you are violating the agreement that requires you to have permission to post the excerpt under CC BY-SA (or MIT, if this change goes through).  Fair use gives you the right to use it, but it does not give you the right to license others to use it in arbitrary circumstances.

Comment: `For Code Review, in particular, the code being shared is usually substantial, often a complete runnable program. The intention is to share code for discussion, not to give code away.`  Hmm, I actually never thought of that way and it's an excellent point.

Comment: @MichaelT Many, many thanks. Though your post is so short, it contains the gist of what I wanted to know: *Could others be permitted to use my free code in their programs?* And hey, I had not the SLIGHTEST idea that they *may* do that with that new, highly-dubious licensing model. So what the initial post on this meta page is suggesting ("tl;dr? No significant changes") is simply a PACK OF LIES. To me it's a __huge__ change if there is a "chance" I will find my own lines in other people's code, and this nasty license even _allows_ that!! And the SE/SO team just nods, saying "That's purpose".

Comment: @syntaxerror They say it makes little difference to those *using* code i.e. they can keep doing what they did before. That much is true. But it does not, of course, follow that it makes little difference to those *posting* code since those using it can *also* use it without attribution. So it is not lying. It is just (deliberately?) misleading.

Comment: "common sense says that there is no copyright licensing issue" - the one big issue I see in this answer is that lawyers who try to abuse copyright to extort money never go by what common sense says, but by what is, in the most remote of interpretations, feasible. Judges are a different story, but actually fighting over a case in court is a significant investment that must be avoided at all cost in the first place, so relying on common sense sounds problematic.

Comment: If we don't want to give our code as the MIT, we can always make a screenshot of our code and embed that, as it is an image then.

Comment: While I confess license fragmentation is something that makes me chill, the content itself can show the corresponding license on each piece of code (supposing the system can confidently distinguish it). Yet, the fragmentation is still there - just with a bit less burden for the user.

Comment: you confused 4: it's actually settle, not win. Winning is irellevant. Settling allows you to make far more broad and spurious claims using the judicial process simply as a punishment- recognizing no necessity of *winning* the suit. For trolls it's about suit quantity not quality.

Comment: I pick the MIT license when I publish code where I don't care if people eat it up and do whatever the heck they want with it. I'm certainly not comfortable with that being applied to everything I and others post on SE. Anyway I'll bbl, I'm gonna go start preparing a blog series on how to code your own proprietary commercial application using only Google, stackoverflow, ctrl+c and ctrl+v just in case things go this way.

Comment: @MichaelT: Your code is *already* permitted to be used in other projects - I'm not sure why you think this changes anything about *that* particular issue.  The only difference between these two licenses, effectively, is attribution.  You could not before, and cannot now, control distribution.

Comment: I think you are the one with a wrong attitude, though it is subjective. For you to say that we are here to get free code is a bit insulting. Ideally in a crowd sourced knowledge base we share. By us sharing questions we make it easier for others to solve the same problem. I don't care if someone use my code in a question. If you are worried about that ask in a private group or pay a consultant on a site like clarity.fm

Comment: @ferrybig I hope you're saying that to highlight the problem of identifying what counts as code, not suggesting that an image of text is a way to get around licensing or copyright.

Comment: Perhaps exceptions can be made for Code Review and Code Golf, so that code there would still be cc-by not MIT. Would have to be indicated somewhere in the GUI? Might be a bit distracting. Perhaps an info dialog if one selects text?

Comment: @KajMagnus I'm not sure separate licenses are the right approach - what happens when a question is migrated or it turns out someone posted to the wrong site?

Comment: I just don't get how licensing of short code snippets matters. It's like trying to claim "Hello, world" has a license. Maybe absurd, now. But imagine we have StackOverflow back in 1974 and are discussing this. Do we have to ask Brian Kernighan if we can change the Hello world license to MIT or whatever??

Comment: @Brandin: If you read the post (again?), you will see that it's not all short code snippets, but sometimes even whole and quite involved working programs.

Comment: @Deduplicator "Hello, world" is a complete working program. And for someone first learning, it can be argued to be "quite involved" as well.

Comment: @Brandin: Arguing that "Hello, world" is "a quite involved working program" is a bit disingenious, certainly in this context.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe, but the point is, that the snippets posted on Stack are of the same category. To someone learning a language, Hello world is no different. It does not need a separate license, nor do the "programs" (code snippet examples) posted here.

Comment: @samthebrand will you automatically be checking all the individual meta sites for feedback, or should we add links here to the relevant site-specific discussions?

Comment: So, all the proprietary, closed-source projects out there won't care, because their code will never be seen.  It is only open source projects that can be hurt by this...  and just who do you think the authors *contributing* code to Stack Overflow are?  You guessed it, open source authors.  So, to protect a small group of helpful people, you put at risk every member of the whole group of which your users are but a subset?

I link to SO content when used in code, but only if it is a good resource that makes sense.  If I had to link to SO every time I use a technique I learned, well... I wouldn't

Comment: "If the answer is trivial, then common sense says that there is no copyright licensing issue." It's unclear where the line is drawn between 'trivial' and 'not trivial'. That's something that would need to be decided in court on a case-by-case basis. And, even if you win, a court case is expensive and time-consuming. I don't want to worry about this when I use answers, and I don't want anyone worrying about this when they use my answers.

Comment: "No attribution is given. How would you feel about that?" Fine, actually. My answers are truly public domain and I want absolutely nothing to do with copyleft-restrictive. The obvious solution here is to allow us to choose licensing - which itself is a really bad solution (license fragmentation). It means there are more steps a person needs to take in order to correctly use code from SO - decreasing the likelihood of them obeying the restrictions. For that reason I agree with your conclusions, but *most certainly* not all of your assertions.

Comment: ""No attribution is given. How would you feel about that?" -- Fine, because I'm not a child who needs ego-gratification for my every action.

Comment: @JimBalter and Jonathan, that's great that you're fine with not needing attribution. What's not fine, more specifically at Jim, is slandering people who do want attribution. I'd rather converse with someone with a bit of ego than someone who believes that the entire world should universally share their opinions.

Comment: So the question is, how do you personally "separate the knowledge from the code" enough in your head if you use the code for learning a method or technique but you learn it by reading the code? How do you _make sure_ your version of the technique is written "differently enough"? Particularly when you're dealing with a project that is not closed source but uses incompatible licenses?

Answer (score 281):

**Please don't add a blanket exception to the attribution requirements.**

I live on the [Open Source site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/). Now, if someone came along and asked a question along the lines of "is it ever a good idea to add an exception to the requirements of an existing license" (and, lo and behold, someone has now [asked that question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/ramifications-of-the-proposed-new-se-licensing-model)), I'd tell them it's not - for these reasons:

1. **You're essentially creating a crayon license.**
   If you modify the terms of an existing license, you create what is known as a [crayon license](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.licenses.open-source.general/11857). Those are a problem - see ["How can a “crayon” license be a problem?"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem) for the reasons why.
2. **It's far too easy to claim an illegal use is legal.**
   See [this answer of mine](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2122/98). Essentially, someone can get my code from somewhere I use it - perhaps in a commercial open-source product of mine - and not attribute it to me. When I chase them down on that, they can simply claim "oh, I got it from Stack Overflow", and get away scot-free.
3. **It's *massively* unclear how to reverse that requirement.**
   Say I don't want to have this extra exception applied to any of my code. How do I note that? If I put a note in my user profile that all my code snippets *must* be attributed properly as per the terms of the full MIT, is that enough? Do I have to add a note to *every* answer? I'd rather not have to do that, but I also don't want to be chasing people down endlessly for misusing my code.

**Make it easy to opt my code out of this exception, or don't do it.**

Comment: *"It's massively unclear how to reverse that requirement."* It's not unclear in the slightest. You do it in the same was as you opt-out of the current license agreement: you don't. This is a great rationalization and simplification of the licensing environment on Stack Overflow, and allowing exceptions would undermine that.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The post clearly says "This _optional_ exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service" (emphasis mine), so yes, you can opt-out.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom You're misunderstanding. The optionality of applying the new clause falls on the licensee/consumer at time of use -- because they may prefer to exclusively use the standard MIT terms for consistency. The licensor/author does not have the option to opt-out of this clause in general (at the Stack Overflow account level), just to directly request that specific projects add attribution.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Okay.  What about the "as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder" part?  Can I request it of all users by stating so in my post, or do I need to track down each user individually?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That's definitely worth clarifying, and Enderland brought it up in his post. My opinion is that polluting user's posts with licensing noise would be a bad idea, and they should be required to track down projects individually. This is the most legally pragmatic approach to the reality of the situation. Most users will be using the code without proper attribution, and this provides a framework for accepting that use while still allowing the author to demand attribution.

Comment: Yep, MIT with attribution only on request -- when the "repo" (SO) of MIT licensed code does nothing to notify the copyright holder of the reuse -- **is for all practical purposes to put the code in the public domain**. Either explicitly say that we're public domain-ing this stuff with a giant USE AT YOUR OWN RISK sign, or honestly copyleft code as @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ requests. (I'm partial to the former.)

Comment: The whole idea of a licence is that it tells you what you can do. "You can use this without attribution unless and until the author or SE says otherwise" is just asking for trouble. If you've used the code in a released product, what do you do then? If the answer is, "to be safe, attribute in the first place", then the "option" is just a misleading "feature" encouraging people to get themselves into trouble. This makes no sense at all to me. Why would you do this other than to store up trouble?

Comment: I hesitate to jump into a comment duel with a moderator of the open source site, for I am merely a cat herder and messenger, and I have fairly narrow (arguably deep) experience dealing with this topic. But I'm struggling to find major showstoppers here or in [your answer on Open Source SE](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2208/367). How is an attribution-by-request framework any less user-friendly than a public domain requirement? I'm genuinely curious to hear your feedback. I'll probably learn something.

Comment: @samthebrand I know I'm somewhat engaging in the duel you weren't hoping for (surprise! I'm another OS moderator) but the way I'm seeing this MIT + exception business is that we're putting this into the public domain. You're letting anyone take it, use it without a proper license file, and at their discretion. The only thing that we preserve is our moral rights, which in many jurisdictions, is required and *irrevocable* by law. The problem with this attribution framework is that there may be no communication, and people will be negligent in their due diligence to attribute code 'at request.'

Comment: **TL;DR** This is basically public domain with moral rights preserved, particularly for the jurisdictions that allow people to relinquish those rights

Comment: No, just no.  Code posted on SE has always been intended for people to _just use_ with little to no strings attached.  If you're not happy with that, then you shouldn't be posting code on SE, regardless of what licensing terms are officially in use.  The only thing this change does is bring the official licensing terms in line with how people actually use the site.  Anyone who posts code on SE with the intention of chasing down people who use that code and telling them "you have to give me attribution" or "you can't use my code like that" is basically trolling.

Comment: Noob question: Why `MIT` license particularly? Why not `Apache APL or Mozilla MPL` which are more modern and more explicitly transfer you the right to code? Also, if I already have a FOSS project under APL, what should I do? Switch to MIT or consider the exception in the ToC and just not do anything?

Comment: @samthebrand My problem is not the MIT license; my problem is the optional exception. (a) because it makes a crayon license, (b) because the "attribution by request" part hasn't been sufficiently explained, as I've noted in this post. If I want someone to use the *full* MIT attribution (i.e. copyright notice and license), how do I do that? Or can I not do that, and only ask for that "reasonable" attribution? I'd like to see either the former, or no exception to the license.

Comment: @PrahladYeri MIT not AAPL or MMPL because that's what SE chose. Your second question could be asked on [opensource.se]; basically you don't need to change your license.

Comment: @aroth then why aren't we putting this into the public domain? This is exactly what this is.

Comment: @PrahladYeri 10 hours ago MIT license essentially does nothing but *protect the original contributor* from liability and loss of copyright. That's an important distinction - **Now Little Bobby Tables can't get sued, and you can safely keep using the code in your own closed source software**. The sticking point is the removal of the requirement of attribution *unless the author requests it upon discovering reuse*. That's ~a distinction w/o a difference... I guess if you posted code that was in Apple's Swift repo later - & you cared - the difference could be useful in such *extreme* edge cases.

Comment: @Zizouz212 - From what I understand, because "public domain" isn't legally a "thing" in all jurisdictions.  But the MIT license is permissive, so it's not much different in principle.  And I'd also fully support declaring code snippets public domain, if that was a valid thing to do in all jurisdictions worldwide.

Comment: @aroth It is. It's called relinquishing all rights that you can.

Comment: There is this thing called the [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0); maybe that would be a better way to do this?

Comment: @aroth People may think that they're posting code on SE intending for it to be used with no strings attached, but they're doing so out of ignorance. Those who know and care about the current CC BY-SA licensing don't want attribution to become optional.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Fair enough, however the core of the issue isn't about attribution.  CC-BY-SA requires _both_ attribution _and_ "ShareAlike".  It is, in essence, a [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) license like the GPL.  The vanilla MIT License does require attribution the same as CC-BY (or CC-BY-SA).  The proposed changes retain your ability to require attribution if you want, while removing the copyleft aspect of the license.

Comment: @aroth: No, they don't.  The proposed changes give the consumer of the copy the option to include the MIT license (including attribution) or not.  They give no options to the *author*, you must accept the new ToS or stop contributing.

Comment: @BenVoigt - How do you figure?  The proposal states that the consumer must give "reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder".  I take that to mean that whether or not attribution is required for a particular code snippet is something that's left up to the _author's_ discretion.

Comment: @aroth: Reread the first three comments on this answer.  And also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271083?noredirect=1#comment878866_271105  Stack Overflow has no intention of allowing authors to require attribution.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I don't think the comments form part of the proposal.  Although the second half of the third comment says essentially what I've said, that it's the author who ultimately gets to decide.  I think the first comment is more in advocacy of nixing the option to require attribution altogether (also fine, as far as I'm concerned) than an accurate description of the proposal as currently drafted.  I'd say there's a technical issue for SE to solve in terms of how authors request attribution, but it's kind of neither here nor there in terms of whether the proposal, in general, has merit.

Comment: @aroth: I don't see a way for the author to require that consumers of his code apply the entire MIT license.  Nevermind an actual reasonable freely-use-code license such as BSD.

Comment: Posting an image of code is one possibility. Another is to post the code elsewhere with a link from here and a notice stating the licence. Nobody else will have the right to repost the code here or, at least, their doing so will certainly not legally relicence the code under SE's terms. So people could pair up. Each person posts their code elsewhere and the other person's here. That way, the code ends up here, but not under an SE licence. Now, if the terms prohibit this, they will also prohibit a significant proportion of answers concerning GPL/LPPL/etc. code.

Comment: You can have a permissive license or a copyleft licence, and either way people know where they stand. If you say "permissive unless I request otherwise later" then no one will know whether it's safe to use your code, and you'll have the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @trichoplax - this, exactly.

Comment: Why would you be "chasing" them down anyways? your code is not that special and programming evolves so fast that it becomes obsolete anyways.

Comment: @JGallardo It's perfectly reasonable to want to be attributed for the work you've done, no matter how big it is or what effort went into it.

Comment: @cfr Both posting an image of text (be it code or not), and just pointing somewhere else are simply unacceptable and make the link-only-post subject to deletion.

Comment: @Deduplicator Only the code needs to not be here. Explanation can stay here. Besides, deleted posts are even less useful, so it hardly addresses the basic problem. I'd certainly consider doing this if it might help somebody. In most cases, even a link-only post would get deleted only after the OP had got the link and been helped, so the post would still serve its main purpose as far as I'm concerned. Of course, it is not ideal because it is nice if future users can also benefit. But many questions are too specific for answers to be of general help in any case, and those primarily help the OP.

Comment: I feel that what SO wants to do is to reduce the burden of using code posted on SO for its users. I don't think people would mind adding a small comment linking to a post when they copy a significant amount of code from it. That is just good documentation. An insignificant amount of code should be already covered under fair-use with no need for such comments. SO needs to better explain the goal of the proposed exception to the MIT license.

Comment: @ArtCode re "It's perfectly reasonable to want to be attributed for the work you've done" [*"no matter how big it is"* - sorry, but you are really saying *"no matter how minor, well-known, or obvious the code I posted is"*] -- because if you *aren't* saying that, then you are putting the burden on every reader to decide whether your code "should" or "shouldn't" be worthy of attribution, which is not practical -- I'm in the "then don't post your precious code on an SE site" camp. It would be a nightmare to have to attribute every snippet of code. To me, the point of SE is "shared knowledge".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve (a) this post is 3 years old. (b) you *already* have to attribute every snippet of code you use from SE, as per the CC license and SO's attribution requirements.

Answer (score 230):

## What?!

Am I the only person that doesn't understand what this all means? This really needs a TL;DR.

I was under the impression that any answers I provided on Stack Overflow that contained code are to be used freely, otherwise why would we post the code?

What I want answered is **What do I need to do as someone who wants my answers to be used freely?** *Nothing?*

Comment: Depends what you mean by "free". If you mean *no requirements at all*, put a note in your profile saying you put your code into the public domain (or CC0 where public domain doesn't exist).

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ Can't do that, it's part of the terms of the site when you sign up, you use their license.

Comment: @Raystafarian But you *can* dual-license your *own* content. You can't revoke the CC BY-SA license, but you can grant an additional license.

Comment: @Raystafarian The contributor is still the copyright holder and can choose to offer their code under additional licenses or release it into the public domain; the user then has a choice of which license to use the code under.

Comment: You can only use existing code on SO under the terms of CC-BY-SA, which is rather problematic.

Comment: As far as I understand this, the TL;DR here is: *you are free to copy any code you see posted in Stack Overflow and do whatever you want with it. From January 2016, the author of the post having the code has the right to ask you to add a comment with link to the post on Stack Overflow*. Would love to stand corrected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, you are not currently "free to copy any code you see posted in Stack Overflow and do whatever you want with it." All posts on SO, including any code within them, are licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) (a "viral" license similar to the GNU GPL), and you must comply with its terms if you redistribute any code from SO. [...]

Comment: [...] Of course, that's assuming that the author of the code hasn't granted you some other, additional license to use it; for example, I have a statement in my user profile releasing all my (original) code on SO under the [CC0 public domain dedication](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/), unless otherwise noted, so when using my code, you can choose to rely on that instead of having to comply with the standard CC license.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thanks, I was basing my assumption on "You can do everything you did before and maybe more when you visit Stack Overflow: copy code, tinker, fiddle, put it in your project, and keep building", posted by Sam. So this sentence is not true and/or accurate?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Technically, no, unless either: a) your project is licensed under CC-By-SA, *and* you properly attribute the code to its original author; b) you've received permission to use the code under some other license terms; c) the code you're copying is trivial or unoriginal enough to be ineligible for copyright protection (the threshold is fuzzy and varies by jurisdiction); or d) nobody cares enough to sue you.

Comment: Just read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro

Comment: @Raystafarian On Open Source: [Can I Override a Licensing Policy?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/504/can-i-override-a-licensing-policy)

Comment: @TinyGiant - If by "plagiarize" you mean "use", then yes.  But if you were worried about plagiarism of your code and intent upon delivering repercussions unto anyone caught plagiarizing it, why post it on SE in the first place?  The outrage some people are expressing over the attribution issue makes no sense.  Does SE exist to help solve problems, or to inject attributed code snippets into random codebases?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for that tldr, I think that's what I was scrolling through the answers/comments trying to find.

Comment: Yes that's what this page was missing.--Besides, why not simply start picking on the words? Share-__Alike__. It's exactly as the English word means: your project which intends to use someone's code seen at SO/SE __must__ be free software *as well*. That's because the original code was free software. It must __not__ be embedded into commercial projects. I've read something about CC-BY-SA being similar to GPL: I reckon that it's more similar to GPL v2 than v3, because the latter is way less restrictive than v2 used to be.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "you must comply with its terms if you redistribute any code from SO" - Small correction; any code _or any derivative works involving any code_ from SO.  Such as compiled applications and binaries, for example.

Comment: It seems to me that if I answer a person's question using a block of code, I *expect* that person to use my code in their project. Period. Whether they attribute the code to me or not is a matter of legal minutiae.

Comment: @aroth it's not all about code getting copied intro code bases somewhere. I've had answers that have had techniques that seem to be novel and have been subsequently mentioned in academic publications.  I don't care as much about what code bases those end up in, but I would like attribution when those appear in papers or books.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - Fair enough.  Though as I understand it the proposed changes don't significantly impact upon how attribution works.  They make it optional, at the _author's_ discretion.  So you can still require attribution if you want.  The substance of the change is moving from a copyleft license to a permissive one, which is mainly relevant with respect to CC-BY-SA code being copied into closed/proprietary codebases.

Comment: I wish they added a TLDR to this post, as well. I am not well-versed in licenses, especially since I mainly work with closed-source software. I am worried that people will misinterpret these changes, without a layman's terms guide, leading to issues with SE. People may not post as often, if ever again, on sites like Code Review.

Comment: @aroth: And that's where you are wrong.

Answer (score 149):

A few thoughts:

## 1. Don't pretend this is the MIT license

Don't pretend you're using the MIT license when you're not. If you need a unique license for a unique situation then just use a unique license. While crayon licenses in general are a problem, I think that this the Stack Exchange network is a situation where a new ultra-basic license would be warranted. And I know you'll use your legal team to prevent the problems with other crayon licenses.

## 2. It would be best to make a new license

If the purpose of this change is to make it easy for post authors and easy for those who would use the code in those posts, then what you're doing won't help. I think it would probably be best to write a new license which is very basic and allows reuse as long as a URL of the post is attached to the borrowed code. If you want to have any user choices, then it should be between this and the existing CC BY-SA. It would also be possible to give users the option to do a CC0 type opt-in too, but the default must be attribution.

## 3. The license needs to be self contained.

You can't have the license, and then list exceptions to it in the *terms of service*, and then also require users to check a poster's profile to see whether the exception hasn't been opted out of. If you want to have two options, then just have two completely distinct licenses. Users also need to be able to see easily what the license of each post is...

## 4. Each post should show its applicable licenses

Each post should indicate below it what the relevant licenses are. If the user has selected only CC BY-SA or CC0 then it could show it. Old posts would show only CC BY-SA (unless perhaps their author edits them and ticks a box saying "update to the new SE-Attribution license"). Posts edited by multiple authors would show only the compatible licenses: new posts without any user opt-ins would be the same as if they only had one author, but if the user did opt-in to CC BY-SA only, then the posts would be only CC BY-SA.

## 5. Fix your footer "attribution required" link

It is [against the terms of the CC BY-SA license to require specific attribution formats](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/429/136). It is dishonest and disingenuous to keep that link in the footer.

Comment: I completely agree on your points 1-4, but I don't think that link in the footer is wrong. Yes, imposing additional "requirements" is a bit dubious, but I think it is important to highlight "*attribution required*" and provide a link to what we expect reasonable attribution to look like, for those who don't understand what it means and how important it is.

Comment: @Bergi Giving suggestions for how to attribute is fine, but the CC BY-SA license just doesn't allow you to demand attribution in any particular format.

Comment: Perfect answer, summary of all the necessary points IMHO.

Comment: I agree that SO needs to be more transparent in the licenses that apply to each question/answer.

Comment: This is just what I was hoping to see, an option to filter out non public code.  I want to see _only_ public code, and anything I post will be public.

Answer (score 132):

I have two thoughts about this.  The first is that the line between code and non-code is sometimes blurry.  This means that depending on how we write answers, different things are protected differently.  That seems odd.  The second is that the change in license should probably be accompanied by a reminder about the community standards for plagiarism:  just because the code is licensed permissively doesn't mean that it's OK to copy *within* Stack Overflow.

### Where's the line between code and non-code?

I know that we discourage code-only answers, but there are cases when they're appropriate: namely, when the code is well commented and self-documenting.  Some languages have documentation strings, comment block conventions, etc., to support this.  Suppose I write an implementation of an algorithm for a Stack Overflow question.  In order to make the implementation idiomatic, I include a nice description in a documentation string in the code.  According to this change, the description is now MIT licensed, whereas exactly the same prose description would have been CC-BY-SA licensed if I had written it outside of the code block.  This seems very, very, odd.  What happens if I write some "code", but don't put it in a code block?  Maybe I put it in the answer text, but in **boldface** because I don't need monospacing.  Which license is it under?  E.g., if someone asks how we can convert a number into a list of its digits, I can post this as a code only answer (that, I think, doesn't have the typical issues characteristic of code-only answers):

> ```
> (defun digits (n &optional (base 10))
>   "Returns a list of the digits of N when written in a specified the
> specified BASE.  The digits can be extracted from least significant to
> most significant by repeated division.  When N is divided by BASE, the
> remainder is the least significant digit of N.  The quotient is then
> taken as the new value of N, and the process is repeated until N
> reaches 0.  Note that in the case that N is zero, DIGITS returns the
> empty list, rather than a list containing 0."
>   (do ((digits '() (list* r digits))
>        (n n)
>        (r 0))
>       ((zerop n) digits)
>     (multiple-value-setq (n r) (truncate n base))))
> ```

Now, if I posted it like this, I'd get attribution requirements for the explanation:

> Such a function returns a list of the digits of N when written in a
>   specified the specified base.  The digits can be extracted from least
>   significant to most significant by repeated division.  When N is
>   divided by base, the remainder is the least significant digit of N. 
>   The quotient is then taken as the new value of N, and the process is
>   repeated until N reaches 0.  Note that in the case that N is zero, the
>   function returns the empty list, rather than a list containing 0.
>
> ```
> (defun digits (n &optional (base 10))
>   (do ((digits '() (list* r digits))
>        (n n)
>        (r 0))
>       ((zerop n) digits)
>     (multiple-value-setq (n r) (truncate n base))))
> ```

This seems odd, especially for languages with strong documentation traditions.

But one of the comments from a mod seems to indicate that even the "code block ≡ code" rule (which I just made up;  I don't see any actual guidelines for determining what's code and what isn't in the announcement) isn't really fixed either (emphasis added):

> Just to clarify, we never said code is anything inside a code block.
>   It might be up to a user to decide what's code and what isn't, just
>   like he/she may have to make a judgement about whether something
>   crosses the threshold of originality. *Ultimately, always, it's on a
>   code **user** to decide how he/she wants to use what they find here.*
>   – [samthebrand♦ 12 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-on-the-stack-excha/271100#comment879049_271100)

I think there must be some misunderstanding here, because it seems like this would make the official policy:  "You posts are licensed under CC-BY-SA, except for the code portions, which are under a MIT license with the attribution requirement removed, and it's up to the discretion of the people who use your posts to determine which parts are code."  That can't be the intent, can it?

I think this would get especially blurry with any questions about Markdown or HTML, where the answer "text" itself might also count as the code.  E.g., if someone asks "How do I make text bold in Markdown?" to which someone replies "Like **this** (see source)."  The same issues could come up with TeX/LaTeX, since some sites support MathJax.

That's obviously a contrived example, but it highlights that **we need some clear guidelines about how to determine which parts of a post are code, and thereby licensed under the MIT license (and whether the author requests attribution), and which parts are non-code and thereby licensed under CC-BY-SA.**

(One more edge case that's probably not really important comes to mind:  if we do, as some users are suggesting, or at least asking about, decide that edits should no longer turn text into code blocks, or vice versa, what happens with all the posts that (mistakenly) use code blocks instead of blockquotes, or that use backticks instead of quotation marks?)

### Remind users that attribution is still required *within* Stack Overflow

I had some concerns that the more permissive licensing of code would make it much easier for a badly-behaved user to attempt to justify code plagiarism.  After all, if they can copy it without attribution outside of Stack Overflow, why not *within* Stack Overflow, too?  [Shog9 pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code/271100#comment878884_271100) that this is actually covered in the Help Center, [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).  You can look through the edit history for some earlier thoughts before that clarification.

Comment: This is a great catch. I should quick copy/paste it as another answer here for the upvotes!

Comment: @enderland And all you might have to do is wrap it in a code block and comments...

Comment: **Plagiarism is orthogonal to licensing.** Plagiarism is frowned upon on Stack Overflow (and other sites) *because it is seen as hostile by the community*, not because it violates a license. Nothing being discussed here changes that; if you get caught using someone else's work on Stack Overflow without attribution, you're gonna have a bad time *regardless* of what license applied to the original. Heck, ripping off someone's public domain code you found on pastebin is just as bad as ripping off someone's licensed code; morally, you're just abusing their generosity for your own selfish gains.

Comment: @Shog9 But what's the problem in this case? If you lift code from someone else's answer, attribution is no longer required, right?  So is there any meaningful way to flag it?  Copy and paste code without attribution would be within the license permission, wouldn't it?  I agree that it's still just as *bad*, but what community guideline would it run afoul of?  Someone who copies and pastes could easily say "I'm just using code according to the license."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You're still pretending that some code is your own work when it was actually written by someone else. That is plagiarism, even if the code is in public domain. Shakespeare is entirely in the public domain now, that doesn't mean that people will just accept it if you pretend you wrote Macbeth.

Comment: @MadScientist: So if not providing attribution is pretending that you wrote it (plagiarism), then what does not requiring attribution really do?

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, I understand what plagiarism is.  My point is that there's not really a good way to flag it now.  It seems strange to say to users that "code you post can be copied and used by others without attribution" but to then punish other users who do exactly that.  It's like we're saying "Hey everyone, come use this code that you can find on Stack Overflow. **BUT**, you'd better not use it on Stack Overflow, because that's against the rules."

Comment: I'm not taking any firm stance on the actual licensing proposed here.  I'm just saying that Stack Overflow is now saying "hey, attribution of code isn't required anymore."  I'm saying (and Shog9 seems to agree) that "but if you're using code on Stack Overflow, you still need to provide attribution, even if the license you got the code under doesn't require it."  It'd just like to see that spelled out somewhere.  Hence, the title, **"Attribution should still be required when copying within Stack Overflow"**.

Comment: It's spelled out [in the help center on every site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), @JoshuaTaylor. Which in turn was motivated by [this discussion here on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq) (and, let's face it, a huge number of flags and complaints over the years). Doesn't matter who you're ripping off or what license their work fell under, if you get caught doing it here you're gonna face the music.

Comment: @Shog9 Alright, that clears that up!  I'll touch up my post.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: [Here's a related - recent - discussion on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism) just for the hell of it.

Comment: Heh... I wondered how long it'd be before someone brought up literate programming.

Comment: Just to clarify, we never said code is anything inside a code block. It might be up to a user to decide what's code and what isn't, just like he/she may have to make a judgement about whether something crosses the threshold of originality. Ultimately, always, it's on a code user to decide how he/she wants to use what they find here.

Comment: @Samthebrand it's up to the **user** of the code, not the **author**?  So if anyone can come along and use anything from our posts by calling it code, is there anything left that's still necessarily covered under cc by sa? This seems like it would make the whole site mit licensed... that can't really be the intent, can it?

Comment: @Shog9 [Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - It is not plagiarism if you give the person permission to represent the code as their own work. If I tell someone "you don't have to say that "rolfl" wrote that code", then it's no longer "wrongful appropriation". You cannot say "there's no need to attribute code", and "you have to attribute code" (and keep a straight face).

Comment: In the words of Picasso, *Good artists copy, great artists steal*. Does that mean great artists plagiarize? Certainly not. So what if I copied a piece of code from SO (or in fact, anywhere). If I adapted my answer to the needs of the question seeker, that happens to be a good answer. By the same token, a reasonably minded question seeker will only accept those answers that provide him/her a complete solution, not some lines of code that run without errors. So, why does it matter at all if anyone posts copied answers on SO, if those answers aren't going to be appreciated in the first place?

Comment: The blurry line is a good point and raises a question: if the formatting changes the license of (parts of) an answer, does that mean that non-authors can no longer change the formatting of a post – since they don't have the copyright to relicense?

Comment: To pile on, what about *pseudo* code, our weapon of choice on [cs.SE]? Which license applies? Does the answer change when the code compiles in any language (maybe by accident, the author may not even realize that)? (cc @Shog9)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier While I think the lines are getting blurry, I don't think there's any real problem different requirements for posters vs. people using content outside of Stack Overflow.  There's no reason Stack Overflow can't impose additional requirements on posters to say "if you use content that you didn't create, you have to provide attribution, even if your license to that content wouldn't otherwise require you to."  I think it's weird to have this sort of asymmetry, but I *don't* think that's it's unworkable or entirely unreasonable.

Comment: @Raphael The comment that samthebrand (a mod) left says that "it's on a code user to decide how he/she wants to use what they find here."  So it sounds like anyone could come along and say "this is pseudo code, which I'll count as code, so I don't need to provide attribution."  Now combine that with the idea that someone mentioned to create an "O'Reilly style cookbook" from code taken without attribution from Stack Overflow, and you've got a situation that I bet lots of contributors won't be happy with.

Comment: I was going to leave an answer that was to this effect, but I would take it a step further -- it would be possible for a user to completely subvert the CC-BY-SA intentionally if they chose. If I answered all of my questions in the form of a python function like: `def my_answer():\n    print "Blah blah blah blah that answers your question"`, then it is absolutely code but should it be licensed as such? Should I really be allowed to subvert the CC-BY-SA just by wrapping my answer in a function?

Comment: @Joshua fair enough

Comment: "Where's the line between code and non-code?"  For my money that was SQL-92.

Comment: @rolfl: Take your claim of "It is not plagiarism if you give the person permission to represent the code as their own work" over to academics.SE and see how long it survives.  It absolutely is plagiarism to represent someone else's work as your own, and having their permission may free you from having them taking any action against you for the plagiarism, but it does not stop it being plagiarism, and it does not stop other parties from taking action against you.

Comment: @BenVoigt has basically pointed out that plagiarism is not a crime. Rather, it is considered a social offense in journalism, _academic_ and literary circles, and that includes Stack Exchange. The punishment is not through the legal system. Rather, it the punishment is ostracism. It's a community-imposed disciplinary measure based on peer opinion.

Comment: That seems like a pretty big stretch, @rolfl; on Stack Overflow, this is rarely discovered or enforced by the authors themselves - it's usually someone else who discovers the deception and raises an alarm. I've yet to see anyone mollified by the perpetrator claiming that they were allowed to do so by license. This is why I say the concepts are *orthogonal* - after all, what does it earn you to be legally clear if your posts are downvoted, trashed and deleted?

Comment: I'd have a real problem considering pseudocode as "code" for this purpose, @Raphael. What does an MIT license even mean if applied to pseudocode? I suppose we'll need a proper definition at some point, and that's best left to the lawyers... But I'd hope something like "machine readable" would be a factor there.

Comment: @Shog9 Well, [you tell me](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50762/98). That's basically working, copy-pastable code for some languages, modulo some syntax details. I'd say it's pseudo code. So, if you copy-paste that into your project, make minor adjustments so the compiler likes it -- which license applies?

Comment: Well, is it pseudocode or code then, @Raphael? I mean, the scenario you're describing - taking an algorithm and translating it into compilable code - seems like a standard use for pseudocode, and *not* one that would normally require a license of any sort. If that translation step isn't necessary... Then it *is* code.

Comment: @Shog9 TeX parses a document token by token. All of it. Is it all machine readable?

Comment: Another problem of not using the same licence for the entire post is that people would copy the code part without the explanations (to avoid having to add two distinct licences), which will end badly; if the entire post is covered by only one licence, much of the explanation could be merged into a code comment, for example.

Comment: If you think the line between code and text is blurry, use a code block, then intention is clear. If not, don't, and mention you don't want it touched and it'll stay under the CC licence. If the code already has a licence then people should really be adding a link to the licence in answers anyway if the *spirit* of being helpful is what they're really doing. Job done. All this other nonsense about finding exceptions to rules should be posted in PhilosophySE under "why did I never read up on the Perfect Solution fallacy?" ;-)

Comment: @Iain And when someone comes along and edits your non-code-block code to to be a code-block, the license suddenly changes?  I absolutely agree that most of the points I'm bringing up are things that are edge cases, and probably are easy to determine in practice.  The problem is that this is supposed to be a legally binding license, and a lack of clarity around the details can be a real problem.  Other have brought up issues with their employers allowing (or not allowing) them to incorporate code depending on the license;  if it's not clear what license something is under, that's a problem. And

Comment: @Iain the same sort of thing happens for the contributor as well.  Some of my answers on Stack Overflow, as far as I can tell, present novel solutions to non-trivial problems.  Perhaps it's just hubris, but I'd those original solutions to require attribution.  And at the very least, I'd like to have some confidence in which parts of an answer will require what amount of attribution.

Comment: @Shog9 So if I adapt your C code to work with my Java compiler, I'm not bound by the license you chose for your C code, because I used it as pseudo code?

Comment: That would actually make a pretty good question for [law.se], @Raphael. To the best of my knowledge, *translations* are considered derivative works under US copyright law, and thus an attempt to faithfully translate code from one language to another would be as well. This assumes you are actually **translating** however, and not writing new code inspired by the ideas of the original. Copyright cases are littered with examples of how blurred the line between the two is... See, for example, the ongoing litigation surrounding the song "Blurred Lines".

Comment: @Shog9 You have still not convinced me that there is a meaningful distinction between code and pseudocode when derivative/inspired work is concerned. It is completely unreasonable to expect *readers/users* to decide which term and therewith which license applies, imho. (Note that even English text can be pseudocode!) As soon as you have different licenses for different parts of posts, you need to have clear-cut rules as to which applies to what, and I don't see a reasonable rule here. Ergo, the plan as presented is flawed.

Answer (score 107):

Sorry but I think this is a pretty terrible idea.

Code on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc. isn't "code" in the typical sense of licensing where you're concerned about distributing it for use by others. It is an example of one way (but not the *only* way) in which a particular problem presented in the question can be solved.
It is more akin to code snippets in a textbook than a software project on github.

CC-BY-SA is (IMHO) the most appropriate license for code posted to a Stack Exchange site: We're licensing the documentation (including snippets/examples) to you. If you happen to cut-and-paste bits of it into your production environment that's fine - my understanding has always been that you should attribute it the same way you would if you posted it to another site (by a URL pointing to the source) and you're good to go.

We (contributors) are not providing any kind of warranty or statement of suitability for a particular purpose with our code snippets, or any other part of our answers. If you want to go ahead and make language to that effect prominent in the terms of service by all means do so, but I don't think muddying up the license terms for site content makes sense!

---

That said, if you feel we must have a separate license for "code" posted to the site taking an existing license with specific requirements and saying in your terms of service "…but it's OK to ignore requirements X, Y, and Z" is ***REALLY TERRIBLE*** -- you're creating two legal instruments (*Terms of Service* for the site and a *License for Use/Distribution* of the code posted therein) with **conflicting requirements** - this is the kind of stuff lawyers charge hundreds of dollars an hour to bloviate about in front of judges.

[artofcode already spoke about the dangers of "Crayon Licenses"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271083/142424), and I think those points are well made, so I won't reiterate their points here.
Suffice it to say I think you should either find a license without a notice preservation/license reproduction requirement, *create* one without that requirement (dear $_DEITY, another freakin' Open Source License! Kill me now!), or craft one specifically for Stack Exchange code snippets that describes precisely what attribution is necessary (e.g. a link to the page you got the code from) and what notice preservation is required, if any.

Comment: This answer doesn't consider sites like Code Review, where whole, working, real live solutions are routinely published.

Comment: @RubberDuck I would think the same principle applies: The question posted (code under review - full working solutions as it were) is part of a larger exercise in documenting/analyzing/critiquing the features and flaws of that code. By posting it your users are allowing others to take it (in whole or in part, with or without modifications) under the CC-BY-SA license terms ("Attribute it appropriately and you're fine"). There is however some fuzz around what constitutes appropriate attribution in a complied product (as just one example) which could stand clarification.

Comment: I will say that Code Review (or other sites where a "full working solution" is a major part of the question or answer, like maybe Code Golf) are an interesting challenge here. Code Review in particular may involve large portions of projects under their own licenses, which may conflict with all or part of the MIT license being proposed here. That however is a legal quagmire I do not want to wade into. There is no License Tequila in my office.

Comment: if you wrote the code, then it's not much of a quagmire. You have the right to license as you please. It's when it's not your code that it gets sticky.

Comment: @RubberDuck Very few large projects (like "operating system scale") are exclusively the work of one person - what part of code you originated which was then modified by someone else and refactored by a third person is "yours" in the sense of the right to dictate licensing? Also worth noting that some projects assume copyright on code contributed to them as part of *their* conditions of contribution (and pretty much *every* corporate job does, as it's "work for hire"). And now we're waist-deep in legal mud and I STILL have no License Tequila!

Comment: @voretaq7 Did you overlook the SA part of CC-BY-SA?

Comment: @CodesInChaos No, nor did I at any time claim that CC-BY-SA was completely without flaws in this regard: The same issues emerge in either case when someone posts content they don't wholly own (though saying "The code is MIT licensed" if it was C&P from a GPL'd project adds a new layer of legal horror to deal with). Frankly I just don't think that split-licensing (especially split-licensing with a ToS that says it's OK to ignore parts of one of the licenses) would be an improvement here: It adds complexity and creates *new* problems, while not alleviating any of the existing ones.

Comment: @CodesInChaos your point does lead into what probably prompted Stack Overflow to start thinking about this though: "Does including a code snippet (in whole or in part with or without modification) invoke the `Share Alike` requirement and mean you have to distribute the resulting product under CC-BY-SA?" -- As I alluded to in my answer I see the license covering the content as "documentation with examples" (and I'm not in the habit of wholesale C&P Coding), but I can see lawyers bristling over it. (I think there's an alligator swimming in our quagmire now.)

Comment: @voretaq7, re "*by a URL pointing to the source*"; **Where?** Within the source code that no one has access to? Or at the website's about page?

Answer (score 92):

I'm not sure that this would be a good move for Code Review, as questions and answers there often involve substantial amounts of code that are intended to be public knowledge, but not necessarily freely incorporated into other projects' code bases — especially for private commercial gain.

I haven't thought through what the ideal compromise is, but I think that this non-trivial change should be reframed more as a question for discussion than a proposal for ratification.

Comment: We normally do like to have more discussion when implementing decent-sized changes, but in the case of licensing, Sam and the rest of the team (both within and outside SO) have put an enormous amount of work over literally years into investigating alternatives. It would be unreasonable for us to ask the community to do that kind of work to have an exhaustive discussion of *all* possibilities, so we did most of the heavy lifting and are coming to you with the best solution that doesn't make SO hard to use, protects user contributions, and that we as a company believe fits our philosophy.

Comment: @Laura Does that mean that it's a _fait accompli_?

Comment: No. If there's something truly awful about this proposal that we somehow overlooked, we'll reconsider. But saying "here's what we'd like to move forward with; what do you think?" is a far better option than "out of all the possible licenses out there, which one's your favorite?" (in my opinion).

Comment: @Laura: I fail to see how removing all requirement of attribution "*protects user contributions*". Do you mean that it protects user contributions from the users contributing?

Comment: Maybe add drop-down list to your questions and answers to clarify which license the code in the question/answer uses?

Comment: @Morwenn It's not that simple. We remix code as encouraged by Creative Commons. Answers inspire new questions (see the [rags-to-riches](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) tag on Code Review). Answers often contain excerpts from the question, plus some original contribution.

Comment: Are you genuinely positing the premise that code posted to Code Review is "for educational purposes only, not intended to be used in production code," and that there is any practical manner whatsoever that could ever enforce such a principle?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I post a question to CR, I have no expectation that it should become virtually public domain. (Whether I'd actually follow through and sue someone for stealing the code without attribution, I don't know, but enforcement is a separate issue.) If I post an answer on CR, my motivation is to help the asker learn, and if it also educates other Internet users, that's great. If the answer happens to contain a substantial amount of original code, the intention is to have them study the code, not to feed them the code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like you can just brush-off the issue of enforceability.  I understand what you're saying as a matter of principle, but without enforcement, that's all it is: a principle, one without teeth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you believe that it's all unenforceable anyway, then we might as well stick with the simplest solution that works: CC-BY-SA for everything, the status quo.

Comment: Why should it be less enforceable than code in open source repositories? There are questions about whether it would be worth enforcing and that might differ. But it is no less enforceable.

Answer (score 92):

> Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder

Sounds like a recipe for boilerplate

```
# I hereby explicitly request attribution under the MIT license
# for this code, as stipulated in Stack Overflow TOS § NN ¶ n.
```

popping up in half the code blocks on the site. I think we can all agree that this is noise.

It may also be legal noise; I have no idea if it counts, honestly, but I want attribution for my code. I also have no way to track who takes it from the site, so what else do you want me to do?

Comment: I've seen people do this already; usually not for trivial amounts of code though. I guess formalizing it ain't awful; if it becomes *pervasive*, that's reason enough to build a UI for it.

Comment: This is a good point Josh (OP). I agree comments like that smell like noise and we need to reconsider the way we explain the license to discourage them. Rounding up with the lawyers on this one.

Comment: @samthebrand, your comment makes it sound like you just need to *explain* the license differently, not actually *change* the license, in order to "discourage [such comments]".  Does that mean that code users *can't* use code without attribution regardless of attribution being explicitly requested or not?  Why would you "discourage" comments requesting attribution unless attribution is legally required by default?  And if attribution is legally required by default, then what is the exception to the MIT license about?

Comment: @samthebrand When you say you want to "discourage" these comments, it sounds like you're just hoping we will acquiesce to the waiver even if we have the right to require attribution.

Comment: @samthebrand A blanket exception to attribution requirements would probably make me add comments like that to all my answers. I love sharing my knowledge, but sometimes answers take hours(or days) of self-education and research before an answer can be given. Attribution is the least I can ask for as recognition for my contributions. Sure, Shog's suggestion of adding a UI for it makes it easier to put back what was taken away, but I don't think that makes the noise no longer noise.

Comment: @Josh, would you mind if copy that boilerplate into my own future answers? I will of course add full attribution to this post when I do it: `# Original attribution request taken from Josh Caswell at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271105/188823`

Comment: Heh, @RichardLeMesurier. You and anyone else who reads this comment may use it under the terms of [the CC0 license](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode).

Comment: @Josh imagine that header now taking over all code snippets on our site :)

Comment: What if we reduced legal noise by [letting people choose a license and displaying their choice clearly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271115/146232)?

Comment: Also, what happens when someone edits a post to remove that comment?

Comment: "I also have no way to track who takes it from the site" - In other words, no matter what the license says on paper, it's effectively unenforceable anyways.  All the more reason to simplify the 'on paper' version.

Comment: As I read it ***users will not be ALLOWED*** to require attribution through anything they do here. The choice will be between not posting code here and accepting the waiver. The only thing you'll be able to do is to track down any project which uses your code, after it uses it, and retrospectively request attribution. If that's right, I would expect people who care to cease posting code here. It might be worth exploring other options. Code could be posted elsewhere and a link provided in the answer. I can see a lot of link-based answers, maybe an image of the code. Sound useful? Well....

Comment: @cfr Link-only-posts are *already* disallowed. Which answers your rhetoric question...

Comment: @Deduplicator It need not be a link-only post. The explanation can be here. Only the code needs to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 91):

> You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Overflow on behalf of the contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

How will this be allowed/enforced/implemented on Stack Exchange itself? For example, if I add a disclaimer to every post I make saying I require it - will this be allowed?

What if I modify my user profile to include an indication of this? Is this equivalent?

If most regular users require attribution how is this an improvement to the status quo?

---

> Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the terms of CC-BY-SA
>
> Code contributions will be available for use under the terms of the MIT License

This might be pedantic but... what is considered "code" for this?

If I write an answer that talks about code, is it a mess of licenses? Where parts of sentences are CC-BY-SA and parts are MIT? What about pseudo code?

Comment: How is it enforced? The same way all copyright is enforced. By lawsuit.

Comment: @Zak I think that by "enforced", enderland is asking what labelling conventions we should use to distinguish between CC and MIT portions of the content.

Comment: Even worse, some math is so close to code that it's confusing which it would count as. Don't believe me? Look at Lambda Calculus. Is that non-code or code? It used in math papers, but can also be compiled into programs. (The answer is it depends on how you use it.)

Comment: Markdown can help to some extent here. Almost every code posted by an experienced user is indented by four spaces and easily processed by markdown. Thus, post content identified as code by the markdown is MIT (whenever this thing gets implemented).

Comment: @PrahladYeri: So if I post it without the four spaces because I don't want it under the new licence and someone changes it to a code block. What then? Will that be forbidden in the future to avoid such things?

Comment: @PyRulez You might also want to start asking "which *type* of code is covered?"  Here's an interesting issue:  on the TeX site, people post lots of TeX/LaTeX *as code*, to answer people's questions about that language.  On other sites that support MathJax, TeX/LaTeX code is used within answers to show formulas, etc.  It's probably not a huge issue, but an interesting corner case.  If you ask the question, "how do I typeset XXX" on TeX.se, the answer should be code, but on another site, the answer could be something like ".... (see source)".

Comment: How would adding your attribution preferences to your profile be helpful? I almost never look at the profiles of people when reading questions/answers. I'm usually too busy trying to solve problems I'm having.

Comment: On TeX SE it is not uncommon for people to include explanatory explanation in the source of the code they post such that typesetting the source outputs a document which includes the explanatory comments. So all of it is indented by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 73):

I have sent an inquiry directly to the OSI for a comment on this situation. Frankly, I am surprised that they would be recommending the changes that are proposed here. I hope to hear back from them shortly.

On the other hand, I would like to know more about what parts of this recommendation are suggested, or endorsed by the OSI? When you say "you consulted with them", does that mean "you spoke with them and they think it is a great idea?" Does it mean "We spoke to the OSI, they think it Sucks, but, hey, 'we consulted them'!"

Does the OSI have any statement regarding what they feel is relevant from a objective perspective?

Comment: I have not yet received a response from their "contact us" page. Hmmm. Anybody else contact them?

Comment: @rofl Any news? I'll contact them as well.

Comment: @Tim - I have heard nothing. I contacted them using their "contact us - general enquiries"

Answer (score 61):

### Please make it clear that code will be dual-licensed, not just pure MIT.

At least, that's what I *hope* you're trying to do, but the way you've phrased it, it could be interpreted to mean that new code posted to SO after this ToS change will no longer be licensed under the CC-By-SA license, but *only* under the MIT license.

Such an interpretation could mean that people currently reproducing content from SO under CC-By-SA, e.g. on a programming blog, would now have to change their licensing terms if the content they used included any code posted after this change.  The option to just make everything CC-By-SA and not worry about any other possible requirements might no longer exist.

Also, arguably, *this might put SO itself in breach of CC-By-SA*.  The "viral" ShareAlike clause of CC-By-SA requires that, when *any* CC-By-SA content is used in a combined work (that is not merely a collection of separate, independent works), the *whole* work must be released under CC-By-SA.  While SO as a whole, or even a single Q&A thread, might count as a mere collection of separate posts, it's hard to argue that *a single SO post* containing both prose and code would not count as a single work that must be released under CC-By-SA, if any of it is.

(The original author is, of course, allowed to release their own work under any license terms they want, however self-contradictory they might be.  But SO, as a redistributor, must abide by the license terms granted to it — and if those terms for prose are still just CC-By-SA, then arguably they must include CC-By-SA for *all* content, for SO to be allowed to distribute it.)

<sup>Also, off-hand, I kind of wonder just how compatible CC-By-SA and the MIT license actually are.  As a permissible license, I'd assume that the MIT license does allow redistribution under CC-By-SA, *provided that* the requirements of the MIT license — i.e. including, unless waived, the copyright statement, license text and disclaimer — are followed.  What I'm *not* 100% sure about is whether or not those requirements themselves, if not waived explicitly or via dual-licensing, might not fall foul of some language in CC-By-SA that forbids distributors of derived works from imposing additional restrictions on them.  Honestly, it's been a while since I took a close look at those licenses, so I'm not sure; I'm just pointing this out as one more *possible* reason to prefer explicit dual-licensing.</sup>

Comment: If something is dual licensed then the compatiblity of those licenses is irrelevant. You can dual (well multi) license something as GPL, MIT and a All-Rights-Reserved commercial license.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Exactly, that's why I brought up the issue as one more reason in favor of explicit dual-licensing.

Comment: Until now I have used the dual licensing approach (CC-By-SA + GPL) for complete or nearly so programs, though omitting this for code fragments that are small (relative to comments outlining the GPL license grant).  I'm not as familiar with the MIT license as I would like to be to offer full throated agreement to the proposed policy change.  In my mind MIT = BSD + attribution requirement.

Comment: Your answer is intriguing, but, to me, what I really am confused about, is who in the OSI actually helped with this. My respect for them is diminished.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Compatibility isn't irrelevant.  Any forks of the content will carry only one of the licenses.

Comment: **Yes, dual-licensing the code is best**. However! MIT isn't copyleft, so I doubt there would be issues incorporating MIT works into CC-BY-SA works. The only real requirement MIT has is mentioning the copyright holder, which is satisfied even by CC-BY; reproducing the license itself is often done simply by naming it in a ode header... The derivative, CC-BY-SA work is a separate thing and can be under its own license. That said, it would be useful to first get Creative Commons to say that MIT is compatible with CC-BY-SA (one way, of course)... except, what SE proposes isn't even MIT.

Comment: Interesting answer which seems...wrong. You say "make clear that they mean dual licensing" - when every way I read their post, they are saying it will explicitly be *not* dual licensed. I don't think they should make it's dual-licensing clear unless they change their minds to decide they want to dual license..

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I do wish to give SO the benefit of the doubt, and assume that they simply phrased the proposal poorly. As I note above, *not* actually making all content available under a single license (or, especially, not requiring contributors to give SO the right to distribute everything under a single license) would seem a... rather badly thought out choice.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it's really not a "benefit of the doubt" situation though. It's stated quite clearly. I would encourage you to elaborate on why the single license distribution is a "badly thought out choice" in your answer so you can clarify *why* you suggest dual licensing over single licensing (since dual licensing is a recommendation you're making in a somewhat backwards way - and absolutely nobody else is fronting the idea)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa perhaps you and I are reading a different post, but Ilmari's answer has 3 out of 5 paragraphs on why dual-licensing is better for SE, SE posters and reusers.

Comment: @Nemo, You didn't catch AP's point. If the prose is viral, and the code is dual-licensed, **then their combination cannot be MIT**, Therefore Stackoverflow needs to publish an additional page (with the submitter's permission)  without the bundling.

Comment: @Pacerier I think I did; I'm saying there are ways to distribute things under cc-by-sa. What do you mean by "their combination"? There are differences between a collection of works and a derivative work, for instance.

Answer (score 60):

GNU LibC [didn't become MIT licensed just because I traced through it in a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444508/211160).

That you wouldn't in your right mind derive from that particular code in your own program isn't the point.  It's that *having a code excerpt put on StackOverflow is not an instant carte blanche on that code's license*.

Others mentioned that regarding Code Review...someone wanting to get feedback on their GPL project may not want to see their code relicensed MIT just because they put up a page or two of a routine.  If it was important enough to bother framing up and asking for community feedback about, it may be something they *specifically* don't want to see adapted and made closed-source somewhere proprietary.

Beyond that...an attribution line in the source and a link to the StackOverflow answer that provided it isn't just good for *"following the license"*, it's good documentation.  SE URLs to questions and answers can be shortened down to just the stem, so `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080` instead of `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-across-the-stack-e?cb=1`.  Someone can not only see the reasoning behind why code is the way it is, they can go check up at a later date and find new information or raise new critiques of whether that's the real answer.

I have two competing feelings overall:

- **feeling one:** If you're the sort of person who has to worry so much about licensing and lawsuits, and have to make sure there's not one bit of GPL'd code in your project (or whatever)...*it should be your culture of development that pays the tax on fretting about it*.  [Stallman was Right](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/manifesto.en.html), FSF/EFF 4eva.
- **feeling two:** I don't want to answer emails asking if someone can use code I post here, because if I wrote it and posted it inside an answer on this site, I don't care and they can do whatever they want with it.

So I don't really know how that translates into an answer, other than to agree with those saying this is probably not something that should be done unilaterally and on a quick timescale.  It may need a more adaptive solution, like a process of pinging a post for a license audit...then on an as-needed basis various factors are gone over.

*(e.g. I might in my profile tick the "anything by me is ok for being MIT licensed", and then all that would have to happen would be someone would look and make sure I didn't source the material from elsewhere, and perhaps it could be 'vetted' for license even if I'm not on the site anymore.)*

Comment: Note that FSF recommend not using the term 'MIT Licence' since it is ambiguous. SE are further compounding that ambiguity by creating yet another variant on top of whichever of the other MIT Licences they began with. One assumes that SE did not consult FSF on this. There are similar issues with the LPPL as you mention with GPL. Posting code here cannot provide carte blanche if it is derived from LPPL code. That makes it a derivative work and there are specific requirements which apply in that case.

Answer (score 55):

I haven't read all the answers here, so this is probably a repeat. But given that you're only giving us two weeks to react, I'll say my piece anyway.

**This is far too rushed**. You may have been working for a long time, but

1. Your proposal is clearly not ready yet. You don't have a clear picture of how it would work.
2. Two weeks (including what is a holiday period for a large part of your audience) is ridiculously short time for feedback.

**PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ON JANUARY 1ST 2016.** Even February 1st seems far too close. I'm not fond of the status quo, I think we must do something about it, your proposal is certainly something, but it is not the right thing.

Your proposal is a huge change, since it would allow code posted on Stack Exchange to be used anywhere with no restriction whatsoever. **Please do not call this “MIT license”**. The MIT license is about as permissive as it gets, but it does require one thing: to maintain attribution. Removing the attribution requirement should more properly be called putting the code in the public domain.

**Your proposal is legally dubious**. Some jurisdictions, including the one I live in (France), grant the author of a work moral rights, which for the most part (especially in the case of software) are limited to the right to attribution. These moral rights cannot be waived by contract. Does the fact that Stack Exchange operate under US law mean that if you waive attribution requirements in the terms of service, this applies to French contributors to? I don't know — you'd better clarify that with your lawyers, otherwise this puts users of code posted on Stack Exchange by French contributors at risk.

Given the impact of the change, you really should first consult, and then inform, all the users on Stack Exchange. For consultation, meta is the right place — but not just this meta. In addition to MSE, you should consult sites where code is routinely posted, and whose denizens don't frequent MSE much. Keep in mind that **Stack Overflow is not the whole Stack Exchange network**. You should consult communities that have different code posting patterns such as [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), [TeX & LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), …. To *inform* users of a change of such magnitude, meta is not enough; it's a change of the terms of service, and must be communicated to users before it takes effect.

You have not managed to present the change in a non-contradictory way. Do not change anything until you can explain the change. You claim

> we will be licensing all new code contributions to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange under the MIT License.

But then you go on to say

> Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder

Give attribution *upon request*? That's… crazy. How would I know that someone is using my code, in order to make such a request? How would I contact them?

Oh, and by the way, since I don't know where this is heading, **I hereby request that attribution be given in any creative work derived from my contributions on Stack Exchange**. This includes both past and future contributions. This includes contributions in the form of executable code. This does not include contributions that do not meet the minimum threshold of originality to be considered copyrightable.

> But to future-proof your work, we recommend you do one of these 2 things, or both:
>
> A) Add a comment to your code that links back to the post where you found it, or
> B) Comply with the MIT as it’s typically used, by including the full license text in your source

Wait: “to future-proof”? Proof against what? Against a contributor making an attribution request? That opens a huge maintenance cost. What on earth could possibly be the benefit of introducing such an uncertainty? **Pick a license and stick to it**. Make it a dual license if you think it's best, but don't make it something that can change later.

Sorry, you really need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: The update on the top of the original post says that they're postponing it until Feb 1st.

Comment: This post appears on the "Featured on Meta" sidebar on every site.

Comment: @200_success a.k.a. the box nobody reads. And anyway I wasn't referring to the announcement, but to the consultation. A post on MSE is not the way to get feedback from people who have better to do than care about the other 150 or so sites but have something to say about their community.

Comment: I upvoted, but I really want to strengthen that: I could not possibly agree more, with everything you write here. I also wonder what will happen in case a contributor claims to have been unaware of this change, given that they are not making much of an effort to publicize it and certainly cannot decide such a thing unilaterally. But, I think the fact that the terms are so ill-defined matters little to StackExchange, so long as they aren't responsible for the unintended consequences.

Comment: Is there a 'we may change the ToS at any time by...' in the existing ToS? If not, the only way would be to force all users to agree to the new ToS on first visiting the site after 1st Feb. Even if there is such a clause, it would be dubious to rely on it, legally, if you were a company wanting to use code. At least, I imagine it would be, though I'm not a lawyer. And it might depend on where you are and.... If I were a lawyer, I imagine that I would advise extreme caution if I were advising a company about code use after 1st Feb. I cannot imagine the situation will be legally clear anywhere.

Comment: @cfr “Stack Exchange reserves the right, at its discretion, to modify these Terms of Service at any time by posting revised Terms of Service on the Network and by providing notice via e-mail, where possible, or on the Network.” I presume that sending an email to every user would meet these requirements, although it isn't completely clear since having a valid email address is not required. It would be safer with an additional notice that you'd have to click through before posting or editing.

Comment: @Gilles If I was a lawyer, I'd still feel happier if users had to actively agree i.e. by clicking through a new notice, as you suggest. That statement reads as if 2 things are required (1) update ToS (2) either email (if possible) or notice on the network. But it isn't clear what would count as providing notice on the network except by a click-through-new-notice of the kind you suggest. And any hint of ambiguity will worry the lawyers.

Comment: @cfr in many (most?) jurisdictions, a contract cannot be formed or changed unilaterally, and the parties have to have a consistent understanding of the terms and their interpretation in order for it to be construed as properly formed. In the USA, for example, [*Specht vs. Netscape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht_v._Netscape_Communications_Corp.) found that "reasonable notice" of the licence terms has to be provided. On the other hand, click-through licences have usually been upheld. I think your suggestion is the only reasonable approach, although I doubt SE will bother with it.

Answer (score 48):

I think that the change is in general a good idea. I'm not a lawyer, and I assume most people that use Stack Overflow and other SE sites about programming aren't either. Licensing can get very complicated quickly, and removing ambiguity and fuzziness is a good idea. The Creative Commons licenses weren't meant for code, and that leaves some issues with how to follow them when reusing code from any Stack Exchange site.

But I don't think this change goes far enough, there is still enough potential confusion left when copying code, or especially when you're not copying directly, but also rewriting it. This confusion might be mostly caused by my lack of knowledge in this area, but I guess most programmers aren't experts in copyright law either.

In my completely irrelevant and non-lawyer opinion, a very large part of the code on Stack Overflow doesn't meet the [threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality) required to be copyrighted. A lot of snippets are short examples on how to use a particular library function or language feature. There aren't many different ways to use the same API, so I don't think it makes sense that this could be subject to copyright. This is pretty much based on my opinion on how the law should work, not how it actually works, so I might be entirely wrong about the actual legal issue.

If I would copy and paste a reasonably large piece of code directly, the rules are pretty clear, I have to attribute it. But what if I just copy it, and then play around with the code until I understand it? It might look pretty different afterwards, it arguably is a derived work and I should attribute it.  What if the code is simply a short example showing how to use a particular function, do I really have to attribute that? But what if I read the code, look up the documentation of the involved feature, and then use that knowledge to write something that looks pretty similar, but I don't attribute because I didn't actually copy it? There's probably a good reason why people do clean-room implementations of copyrighted code, but once I've seen an answer on SO I can't unsee it.

I think some of my arguments in the previous paragraphs are rather unreasonable, but the problem is that just going by common sense in the area of licensing doesn't seem to be a good idea. The only way to remove all ambiguity is to use a license that grants unrestriced rights without any requirements, or putting the code into public domain. I don't know how well it is legally tested, but something like the [Creative Commons CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) license might work for this purpose.

It it still not entirely clear to me how this attribution exception is supposed to work. So I suggest to get rid of it entirely and use the least restrictive license you can find and avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: A really well considered post. Thank you for this. I'll have more to say on this proposal soon, but I look forward to reading any and all related comments.

Comment: @samthebrand It really didn't feel well considered while writing it, it is more of a train of thoughts dumped into a post. But I think that the part that makes it a bit incoherent, the fact that I don't actually know what I'm talking about when it comes to legal issues in licensing, is an important aspect that applies to most users that actually copy or adapt code from SO.

Comment: It's a welcome train of thought. We've been reading between the lines on this for so long that we've probably lost a little bit of the forest for the trees.

Comment: +1 for mentioning CC0. Honestly, I don't really think forcing all new code on SO to be released under CC0 would be a good idea (even though [I do so myself](http://stackoverflow.com/users/411022/ilmari-karonen)), but I do think it *would* surely be better than the proposed "MIT + exemption" hack. Actually, one possible option would be to just use CC-By for code; dropping the ShareAlike clause makes code reuse a lot simpler, while still requiring attribution, and CC-By just requires attribution to be given "in a reasonable manner", without any lengthy boilerplate text like the MIT license has.

Comment: Regarding threshold of originality, what do you make of [this 9-liner](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/)?

Comment: None of the CC licences really works for code. In addition, after reading through it, I think CC-BY is actually a weak copyleft and nowhere as free as the absence of -SA makes people think it is. CC themselves ask people to not use CC0 *at all* for new works due to perceived problems with it, but have postposed fixing them in favour of bringing out CC-* version 4 licences. Public Domain is not a licence grant, and thus does not allow reuse by people e.g. from different countries, and cannot be granted by most EU citizens either.

Comment: @mirabilos [The FAQ on the CC0 license does state that it is appropriate for code](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F).

Comment: @MadScientist “speculation that we did not anticipate CC0 usage for software at the time is true” on [CC withdrawl of CC0 from OSI process](https://lists.opensource.org/pipermail/license-review/2012-February/000231.html)

Comment: A link to the witdrawal request of CC0 from the OSI process that actually works (pointing to the internet archive): http://web.archive.org/web/20150906005825/https://lists.opensource.org/pipermail/license-review/2012-February/000231.html - the problem with CC0 referred to in that context is the explicit non-waiving of patent rights.

Answer (score 41):

How does this work with edits?

Say I have an answer containing code, written in 2015. In 2016, I edit part of the code. Is the part I didn't edit still CC BY-SA? Or does my edit implicitly indicate it's all under this MIT crayon license? How is this indicated to readers unfamiliar with the site?

Comment: samthebrand addressed [editing in a comment above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code/271105?noredirect=1#comment878796_271080), but not the "How is this indicated" question.

Comment: Extending this question: what if I edit someone else's answer from 2015? Does that (or *could* it) trigger a license update?

Comment: They shouldn't: copyright belongs to that of the original author (for more background: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/licensing-community-wiki-posts-at-stack-exchange)

Comment: @Zizouz212 But that would mean that the portion of the code that is edited after Feb 1 wouldn't have the new licence applied, so you can just generally say that all code added to SO after Feb. 1 would have the new licence.  Of course, the very idea of portions of a snippet having one licence and portions having another sounds like pure evil, but the alternatives don't sound great either.

Comment: No, any edits to code after Feb 1st are legally not allowed to carry the new MIT license. @Servy

Comment: @Zizouz212 Where is that stated?  Does that apply if I edit an entirely new snippet into an answer from before Feb. 1 that didn't even have code in it before (and I'm the author)?

Comment: Nope, because the snippet would belong to the post, which belongs to the original author. Just because something is edited means that it can't be relicenced. It's the same idea

Comment: How have other sites driven by user contributions handled license changes in the past? I remember Wikipedia changed its license a few years ago, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @gengkev see https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Licensing_update for the update. Note that it was possible only because 1) CC-BY-SA and GFDL are both copyleft and similarly restrictive, 2) FSF released a new version of the license on purpose! Also, dual licensing.

Comment: There is no doubt on the answer: CC-BY-SA is a stronger license than the MIT/SE crayon license, hence CC-BY-SA survives (or the new work is plagiarism and copyright violation).

Comment: hmm, so basically the only solution is for the license to depend on when the original post was submitted. but that's much better than having different licenses in the same post!

Comment: and from the link @Nemo posted, it looks like Wikipedia actually asked its users about the change *before* deciding it would happen. huh.

Answer (score 41):

I'm primarily concerned by the lack of attribution requirements.

Right now, all content on Stack Exchange is CC-BY-SA, which requires attribution. However, the proposed change to the source code license won't require attribution. The original post does say that the users of code must give "reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder". I'd like to see more information about how this will work. Specifically, I want to ensure that whenever people use any content that I created that they obtain from Stack Overflow, there is a requirement for attribution. I'm not clear how that will happen.

I'm also not convinced that "a comment to your code that links back to the post where you found it" is sufficient attribution, especially in a closed source project where users can't see the source and therefore won't see that my original work was used as part of the project.

I do understand that copyright has restrictions. For example, some things cannot be copyrighted. I understand that if I can't copyright the code sample, then there's no need to license it and anyone is free to use it. [Mad Scientist's post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271102/572) talks about [threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality). But for things that can be, I do want to ensure that attribution is required uniformly across content.

Comment: Sounds your goal is pretty much the same as mine when I wrote the license comments for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150

Comment: On the other hand I would like to be able to mark all the content in my answers as public domain/CC0/WTFPL/anything that allows everyone to use it for any purpose without attribution.

Comment: @user31389 My understanding is that you can, if you choose. You could also dual license under a more restrictive license, but the people who find the content can effectively choose either license. That's why I choose CC BY and Apache 2.0 for content I post on my site, which would allow anyone to use the content for any purpose, and if I repost my contributions to Stack Exchange there, people have the freedom to choose.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes, but currently I have to mark everything manually as CC0 licensed. Or I can write that on my profile, but then people would need to visit it. It would be great if there was some generic mechanism to mark a piece of code as requiring (or not) attribution, preservation of a license text or something else.

Comment: @user31389 That could possibly work, though I'm not sure how it would be implemented. However, I find it unacceptable to have the terms state that attribution is not required for a portion of content, especially when attribution is required for the non-code content. My assertion is that all content posted on an SE site, if used elsewhere, should require attribution unless the author specifies otherwise.

Comment: TEX SE has a question on Meta on which people who wish state any additional licences under which the code they post here is available.

Comment: [As I read it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?cb=1#comment880367_271105), it can't happen. That is, the idea is that you cannot demand attribution other than retrospectively for a particular usage by a particular individual or organisation....

Answer (score 39):

**Does this potentially make answering pre-February 2016 questions illegal after that date?**

If someone asks on January 31st:

> I have this code, it doesn't work, how can I make it work?

then two days later, I might know the answer and just copy his code, change a few characters to make it work and post that as an answer.
Except, that **I am not allowed to**. His code is licensed CC-BY-SA but by putting it in my answer, I would license it as MIT. I am not allowed to do that.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Of course to make it legal I can answer it like

> In line 5, you have to change the 3rd 'a' at position 16 to 'b' and in line x...

But if it is that cumbersome to answer, I might just not.

Comment: What if OP puts in his question "attribution required"? Then every answer has to use proper attribution. :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's the problem that Josef describes. Since the proposed modified MIT license does not require full attribution it would be imcompatible. Basically it may be possible that you are not allowed to use code from old answers in new answers.

Comment: Yes, it would be illegal. That's why the Wikimedia licensing update in 2009 required FSF to update the GFDL license, a mass migration to GFDL 1.3 and then a retroactive dual licensing to CC-BY-SA. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Licensing_update

Answer (score 35):

If this happens, I think it needs to be very explicitly shown on each code block what license it falls under. Having multiple licenses co-existing and trying to determine which one a particular code block falls under by looking at the date will get messy fast (especially if people have to manually add boilerplate text to require attribution).

Users should be able to set their preferred license in their profile and new code-blocks that they write will automatically default to this license, but can be overridden if needed.

Old code blocks will default to the existing license but users can go back and edit to change the license going forward (and maybe provide a mass-update tool if people want to change the license for all their answers at once).

Comment: What happens when someone creates or splits a code block in the process of editing a post? You're right that this split licensing is going to be a mess, and your suggested solution to help manage the complexity will really help highlight how messy it's going to be.

Comment: Relevant: [a proposal to let users choose what license to use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271115/146232).

Answer (score 33):

### I don't get it.

Sorry, I fear this is exactly what you wanted to prevent, but **I don't understand how to attribute** any more.

> You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

WTH does this mean? By shortly skimming over it, this sounds like I would not need to give any reasonable attribution whatsoever, until the contributor asks me to do so. **This can't be right**.
After reading it again, the "ignore" seems to refer only to the "*License’s notice preservation*", which is… [wait](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)… only the thing that follows the `Copyright (c) …` line. Right?

I fear that this is what will happen for most people. They read "*You don’t have to include the <License stuff>…*" and think "*Ah good, no attribution required*". This should not happen. So please be explicit in your licensing requirements, and state something like

> You have to include the line
>
> ```
> Copyright (c) 2015 [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271299/183280, MIT-licensed
> ```
>
> above the used code, and should (if possible) or must (if requested by the copyright holder) include the full terms of the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) below that.

Answer (score 30):

> always been a little ambiguous how CC-BY-SA covers code

No, most ambiguity is gone at this point. [CC BY-SA 4.0 now one-way compatible with GPLv3](http://creativecommons.org/weblog/2015/10/08/46186)

You are changing from a copyleft to a permissive license. A lot of people, including me, care that our contribution is "shared alike," (the sa in cc-by-sa).

https://opensource.com/law/13/1/which-open-source-software-license-should-i-use: "the choice of license reflects as much of the social contract that is being made for the project as any legal requirements"
The the social contract should not be changed unilaterally like this.

Edit: after reflection, I'm mostly ok with the change because copyleft for small code examples is usually more effort than it's worth (gnu recommends against copyleft for small < 300 lines https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-recommendations.en.html), but I still do not agree with how it was changed, and think the reasons I mentioned are still valid reasons for being against it.

Comment: What about the whole lot of people who _don't_ want their contributions to be copylefted?  And the whole lot of people who just want to be able to use code without having to worry about what license terms apply to each snippet?  It's the third group that dwarfs the other two.  Do their wishes not count?  You can both ask and answer on SO, which I think implies that the social contract includes "I'm going to help you _without expecting anything in return_, because one day maybe you'll do the same for me".

Comment: I'm not exactly sure  how to respond, but I'd like to point out that no one seemed to be clammering for cc-by instead of cc-by-sa, or starting an alternative site because the existing copyleft was too onerous.

Comment: I'd posit that may have been because many people weren't aware and/or don't pay attention to these sort of things.  Hell, until I saw this thread in the list of promoted subjects, I was positive that content on SO _did_ use CC-BY.  Most of the previous discussions I've stumbled across on the subject were focused on ensuring that the attribution component was handled correctly.  I haven't personally seen a discussion where someone wanted to assert copyleft over a third-party codebase because of a snippet they'd authored on SO.

Comment: While I don’t agree on principle with you (I prefer to not deal with GPL projects, especially GPLv3, if I can avoid it, as BSD person), you’re completely right about this breeching the social contract here (and, as such, got an upvote from me, considering the added justification, links, etc). Maybe you want to summarise what some of the links say, though?

Comment: Actually, it's *not* a unilateral change. It applies to new code contributions so, if you don't agree, don't post. If you *do* post, that's acceptance of the "contract" on your part, hence bilateral. It's really that simple :-)

Comment: Just to be clear: Stack Exchange currently uses CC-BY-SA 3.0, not 4.0.

Comment: Can anyone carefully explain why CC-BY-SA 3.0 is copyleft because I don't think it is. Here's the full text of the license: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode  It seems to me that when you are copying code snippets from StackOverflow, that you are adding those snippets to a Collection, from the point of view of the license. So that means that the copied snippet is still covered by CC-BY-SA 3.0, but the rest of your code is not.

Comment: @Ron: I guess it’s only a *Collection* if the code snippet stands on its own ("each constituting separate and independent works in themselves") and is unmodified ("in its entirety in unmodified form"). Think: a list of code snippets. Including/integrating a snippet in other code (i.e., so that it becomes part of a program) can hardly be understood as *Collection* (… I hope).

Comment: @200_success: If we are talking about adaptations (which is probably the common case if using code snippets posted here), [CC BY-SA 3.0 and 4.0 are compatible](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2213/138) licenses (one-way). So if adapting code posted on Stack Overflow today, you can license your adaptation under CC BY-SA 4.0 and/or under GPLv3.

Comment: @aroth: On SO/SE we have a copyleft license since the beginning. Someone who wants to license their contribution under a permissive license could and can do so with dual-licensing. If we would change to a permissive license, users that want a copyleft license can’t do so (well, they could dual-license, but that of course doesn’t offer the desired protection). -- I’m [interested how many users know about the licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310531/1591669), but even if there are "many" that don’t know/understand/care about copyleft, there are for sure also many that do.

Comment: @paxdiablo: "My way or the highway" is unilateral, in the same way that "buy a diamond from De Beers, or not at all" is a monopoly. (Yes, I know De Beers is only about 65% of a monopoly.)

Comment: @unor "If we would change to a permissive license, users that want a copyleft license can’t do so" - I don't fully agree.  Users that want a copyleft license on their snippet can still have it, so long as they don't embed the snippet directly in their answer.  So for instance, create a github project, set it up with the GPL (or CC-BY-SA, or whatever), put your snippets there, and then link to them from your answers.  I think it's fair for the onus to be on the people who want a more restrictive license in terms of setting up a structure that enforces their desired code-snippet license terms.

Comment: And come to think of it, if you set up the GPL'ed project on github it probably _would_ be valid/safe to include your code snippets directly, so long as the audit log/timestamps clearly show that the snippet was published _first_ to your GPL'ed github repo and _then_ copied onto SO/SE.  Obviously copying a GPL'ed code snippet into an answer would not have the effect of removing the GPL from that snippet.

Comment: @aroth "Users that want a copyleft license on their snippet can still have it, so long as they don't embed the snippet directly in their answer" Which means their answer depends on external content, and thus is not acceptable. And no, first publishing as GPL and then as public domain doesn't mean the second publishing action is in any way gimped.

Comment: @aroth: "Obviously copying a GPL'ed code snippet into an answer would not have the effect of removing the GPL from that snippet"  Actually, the proposed Stack Overflow terms of service would do exactly that.  If you are the copyright holder, you've just dual-licensed.  If you are not, you violated Stack Overflow terms of service (and this latter statement is true already).

Comment: @aroth, each of your significant claims in this thread has been debunked already. I'll add: you ask, "What about [1] the ... people who don't want their contributions to be copylefted?" Those people don't need a license change: they are [already catered for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?cb=1#comment881971_271080). "[2] people who just want to be able to use code without having to worry about what license terms apply..." Those people are [plagiarists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) at heart.

Comment: @sampablokuper - I'm unclear what significant claims I've made on _this_ thread.  But naturally I respectfully disagree.  And I think calling 'plagiarism' on someone for wanting to freely use that which was freely given is inconsistent with SO's underlying purpose.  Or certainly, it's in no way representative of the reasons why I contribute content, or how I view or would have others view the people who use that content.

Comment: @aroth, *"calling 'plagiarism' on someone for wanting to freely use that which was freely given is inconsistent with SO's underlying purpose."* Straw man! (And vague language!) I'm not calling plagiarism on anyone for wanting to "freely use that which was given freely". I'm calling plagiarism on anyone who uses stuff with total disregard for the wishes of the licensor(s). That isn't "using freely", it's plagiarism or theft.

Comment: @aroth, It's saying, "It's not enough that you're generously giving me this information free of monetary charge, I also demand the entitlement to use it without giving back *anything at all* to you or the community." As for SO's underlying purpose: (1) I see zilch in SO's Tour or other documentation that is inconsistent with CC-BY-SA 3.0 as the default license for user contributions, and (2) I strongly hope that rewarding the plagiarist mindset *isn't* SO's underlying purpose. That being so, it would make sense for SO staff to vindicate that hope by dropping their new licensing proposal.

Comment: @sampablokuper Based upon the links in your profile (first one is dead, btw) I doubt we'll ever agree.  For me "free software" means "do whatever the hell you want with it".  I think it's different for you.  As for misleading language, I'd like to know how you got from preferring "not having to worry about [...] license terms" to "total disregard for [...] the licensor"?  The former is a _preference_ to avoid license technicalities.  The latter is a willful breach.  It's the former group I named and that you originally accused of being plagiarists.  The latter group is a new invention.

Comment: @sampablokuper - Entitlement flows both ways.  Why should authoring 5 lines of code give you an entitlement to dictate license terms to anyone else?  And why are you entitled to ignore the common sense prerequisite of 'if I want to dictate certain license terms then I should either get explicit agreement _before I code_, or else _not code at all_'?  Nobody is forced to answer a question (or to answer _with code_), and in my opinion "volunteering" an answer only upon proviso of getting something back is plenty exploitative.  Help people or don't; don't play quid-pro-quo and call it helping.

Comment: @aroth, Re: the morals (*"help people or don't!"*), why the [black and white thinking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271166?noredirect=1#comment881973_271080), and whence the notion that quid pro quo is inherently unhelpful (esp when just about every constructive economic model - bartering/socialism/capitalism/... - depends on it)? Look at it positively: CC-BY-SA says, "Give as ye have received," which is more engendering of helpfulness & respect than "Give if you want, but rip off all and sundry."

Comment: @aroth, you ask, *"Why should authoring [something] give you an entitlement to dictate license terms to anyone else?"* Whether you like it or not, that's typically the law, and I'm not going to debate legal philosophy in this comment. As has already been pointed out to you *several times*, if you personally prefer to (dual-)license your own works under MIT or CC0, etc, you can! You are in no way disadvantaged here. Lastly, "common sense" is completely subjective. By appealing to it in your argument, you have committed a logical fallacy, so your argument is inherently logically unsound. Sorry.

Comment: @sampablokuper - It's unhelpful because it limits the contexts where the code might be used; technically through strict interpretation of copyleft, and practically due to the knee-jerk reaction copyleft tends to inspire.  And you've understated it; being obliged to open-source 5000 lines of code because you copied 50 that were copylefted is not as proportional as "give as ye have received" makes it sound.  Ultimately it's a purely ideological point.  Either you think 'Torvalds was right' or 'while a genius coder, Torvalds's licensing views approach the point of zealotry'.  It's an impasse.

Comment: @aroth, again the all-or-nothing, black/white thinking. Things don't necessarily become unhelpful because they have strings attached. If you run gratis proprietary software, there are strings attached (EULA); if you learn from friends, writers or school/college teachers, there are strings attached (don't rip them off). If you insist on not sharing with those who have shared with you, either do so where that's fine under the license (e.g. GPL typically makes no difference for SaaS); don't incorporate CL material; or use the material as instructional, and reimplement differently. Simple!

Comment: @aroth, also, your example is not globally representative. Yes, on SO the code posted is typically more like 5 lines or 50 rather than 5000. But that's a restricted context. There are lots of 5000+ line codebases in the wild that you can learn from equally well precisely because their authors were generous enough to share them under a free software license for you to read, run, & experiment with. Sometimes, those programs can be great sources of inspiration for a 5-line snippet, including maybe for an SO answer. I hope you can agree that credit & share-alike is pretty fair in those cases!

Comment: @sampablokuper - It's all or nothing because SE has to settle on a single policy.  Though I'm just saying, a thing that can be used in 500 places is objectively less helpful than an identical thing that can be used in 501.  I don't think there's any middle being excluded there, or any absolutes being invoked.  Permissively licensed code is no less useful to people with open-source projects, and is often more useful than copylefted code to people with closed/proprietary projects.

Comment: @aroth, *"Permissively licensed code is no less useful to people with open-source projects"*. That is not guaranteed to be true in any temporal universe. It is almost certainly false in this one. An expansion in the size of the commons allows every *person* to benefit (albeit not under all circumstances). Permissively licensed code permits the size of the commons to remain static with all kinds of re-use. Copyleft code permits the size of the commons to remain static under fewer kinds of re-use, thus providing a greater potential benefit to people with open-source projects, *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: @aroth, *"It's all or nothing because SE has to settle on a single policy"* SE's current policy is respectful of contributors' intentions whether they want their contributions CC-BY-SA or instead permissively licensed. It promotes respect for the community by requiring attribution & share-alike, but allows contribs to opt out of that if they wish. It therefore lets contribs pick a place on the spectrum that's comfortable for them, rather than being dictated to by a third party's business requirement. It's not all or nothing, not my way or the highway. It's better than that: it's inclusive :)

Comment: @aroth, *"It's all or nothing ... I don't think there's any middle being excluded there, or any absolutes being invoked."* See the contradiction? ;)

Comment: @aroth For clarity: by "a third party", I don't mean the contributor or Stack Exchange, Inc.. Those are the 1st & 2nd parties. I mean parties who have an arbitrary business requirement to distribute code contributions from Stack Exchange sites, that they didn't write, in proprietary non-SaaS software. (Which is a pretty sketchy business requirement!)

Comment: @sampablokuper with reference to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/271235#comment884199_271166) comment, I feel it is worth mentioning that it depends on what conception of "benefit" one cares to choose. If there are fewer capable coders than there are users, perhaps there is a social benefit to having one's code incorporated into a widely-used tool--even a commercial/closed-source one. So, I find this kind of argument for the moral superiority of copyleft licensing unconvincing. Of course, it is still beholden on everyone to respect your choice of terms.

Comment: @OleksandrR. code in the commons provides all the benefits of the [four freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=695656324#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) to every person who wishes to avail herself of them. Code in proprietary software doesn't.

Comment: @OleksandrR., *"If there are fewer capable coders than there are users, perhaps there is a social benefit to having one's code incorporated into a widely-used tool--even a commercial/closed-source one."* That is a non-sequitur, sorry.

Comment: @sampablokuper it must be nice to have a moral calculus so rigidly defined that one can read its consequences off from a list and dismiss as unworkable all other systems of ethics. Well, I don't really want to get into an argument with you, because I really have no problem with the majority of your rebuttals of aroth's comments, so let's leave it at that. Still, this says something about the depth of feeling about the fundamentally political act that is open-source software licensing. I think it is despicable that SE has decided your views on the subject are unwelcome here.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I'm grateful you don't object to my rebuttals of aroth's comments; thank you. I would like to note that nowhere here (nor anywhere else, to my knowledge) have I "dismissed as unworkable all other systems of ethics." As for politics: copyright is inevitably political. Not so much due to software licensing, but more because we are (almost) all subject to national & international copyright laws that we did not write, that were often shaped by political lobbying by wealthy copyright owners, & that may or may not benefit us, depending upon our own interests, beliefs & desires. Peace.

Answer (score 28):

I agree that requiring the inclusion of the full MIT license for a small snippet of code from SO is unreasonable, but I feel entirely waiving attribution is also unreasonable, and directly against the principles of user-contributed content SO was founded on.

I propose that attribution continue to require a link to the SO post where the code originated and the name of the poster, in the same way that CC-BY-SA attribution works now.  In open-source code the standard "link in a comment" practice you recommend should suffice.  Commercial code will add the link in the usual "disclaimers and licenses from third-party code" spot; they might choose to include the full license anyway to keep things simple for their lawyers.

(I think this is basically using CC-BY for code instead of CC-BY-SA for prose, but I am not a lawyer.)

Comment: Yeah, what I think you're saying is that it should be either A or B and that there should be no option C where a user doesn't include attribution?

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, this is not how OSS licencing works (others have pointed out the problem with crayon licences already). It’s better for *all* parties (poster, SO/SE, user) to use an established licence, despite the boilerplate (and, c’mon, it’s under 1 KiB).

Comment: @mirabilos CC-BY is an established license, and its text allows attribution to be given "in a reasonable manner". If the laywers like the rest of it, I think the flexibility is valuable.

Comment: The only issues with CC-By that I can think of are that a) it's not specifically designed for code (but it's no worse than CC-By-SA in this respect), and b) despite being a permissive license, it still contains an anti-DRM clause that some might find objectionable or problematic (although, again, CC-By-SA has that too). Other than that, I do like the suggestion.

Answer (score 28):

- If I'm reading you correctly, henceforth code is available *only* under the MIT license (or your modified version thereof), not the CC BY-SA license. Why not retain the existing license, and *add* the MIT license? This would make life a lot easier for people copying posts from here. It's much easier to copy an article if the whole thing is under one license.
- Define, please, "code".

  > This condition is met when `a > 3`.

  Is that "code"? Is most of that sentence CC BY-SA, but those final characters MIT? Is this not a mess?
- If I edit someone's post to format their code properly, am I changing their license terms? Do I have legal permission to do that?

Comment: Bullet point number 2 was [also one of the first comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code/271105#comment878727_271080), and to my mind really needs to be addressed. I just came back here to post about it.

Comment: And "define 'code'" is now [its own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271117/what-is-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-proposed-mit-license-switchover).

Comment: Does it matter whether `a>3` is code? It's not copyrightable either way.

Comment: It matters a little bit, @MSalters, because the entire post is copyrightable, so depending on the location of the "trivial" line, it's unclear whether you're dealing with one or two licenses.

Comment: Is `<3` code too?  (Say it is!)

Comment: I `<3` your comment, @tripleee.

Comment: +1: "In order to determine which license applies when reusing this text, first solve this intractable problem"...

Answer (score 28):

Here's my two main points:

#### How is it shown what license a post is licensed under?

Once posts become licensed under different licenses, how will we know which license is used by a particular post?

- Will there be an icon next to your flair at the bottom of the post which indicates the license?
- Will code blocks be colour coded based on license?
- Will a footer be added to every code block stating the license?

Whatever approach is used, it needs to be clear and understandable to everyone, even those who haven't used SO before.

#### How can I make it clear that I still want my code to be attributed?

> Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, **as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request** of the copyright holder (emphasis mine)

I may request to have all my code attributed. How can I make this clear to those who use my code?

[@Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271105/285368) stated that you can probably use something along these lines in your code blocks:

```
// I hereby explicitly request attribution under the MIT license
// for this code, as stipulated in Stack Overflow TOS § NN ¶ n.
```

Is there a way this can be implemented into the UI (i.e a checkbox which adds a notice to the bottom of the post or a preference in your settings which automatically does so to all posts) or will we just have to do this ourselves?

Comment: Seems that all your existing posts continue to require attribution and share-alike, since they continue to be governed by CC BY-SA.  Only new stuff will use the new license.  So we at least don't need to worry about noise edits pushing old code to the front page.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point- I forgot that existing posts would not need to be edited.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I wasn't intending to _recommend_ "that you can probably use something along these lines in your code blocks", but just that I foresee that happening. To me, this tidbit is noise, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 27):

If people are using code I've written on SO, but are not publishing the MIT license with attribution... What's to stop me or someone else from suing them proclaiming they *didn't* receive a copy under the MIT licensed form published on SO? They are using unlicensed versions of my code at that point...

I have a hard time believing I won't have a leg to stand on in court exerting my IP rights when they've no indication of licensure for said code of mine.

The MIT license I extend to SO is given to them but I still maintain personal IP rights to productize said code and sell it to others holding them to separate licenses than that which SO and people who receive the code on SO are given. Per SO's TOS I am still the right-holder, they are merely provided a license by me upon my submission.

Honestly, I think the whole MIT licensure thing is a perfectly good idea. I think that "you don't need to publish the license upon your usage of the code" exception cannot function reasonably, and if utilized opens loopholes in the whole concept of licensing the code to begin with.

Comment: If you post code on SO, and you also sell that code to someone else under another license, they are free to use the license you sold them or the license they get from taking it from SO.  Relatively clear.  You could get them to sign a contract requiring them to not use any other licensed version of the code you licensed them for-pay if you where really worried about that.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not worried; I'm merely trying to point out possible holes which not requiring people to publicize a license may create. When folks go around using code without putting a clear license on it, I just see this as walking into a large legal gray area that is a bad idea. I would encourage no one to use code they received by an MIT license and *not* include the MIT license - this "optionally include the license" provision they're adding encourages people to do that.

Answer (score 26):

> Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor).

There are two fairly obvious problems with this:

1. It's not always possible to add attribution later when requested by the copyright holder. E.g. if someone makes a paper book which teaches a subject using code taken from various posts, and then the authors of some of those posts request attribution, the best that the publisher can do is to pulp the unsold copies and put an erratum on their website.
2. About half of the MIT licence is a disclaimer of liability. Replacing the notice preservation requirement with "*attribution*" means not needing to state that the author and copyright holder has disclaimed liability. If you're saying, in effect, that half or more of the licence you've chosen is irrelevant and unnecessary, why on Earth did you choose that licence?

Comment: Additionally, not requiring the disclaimer to be retained is a bad feature of e.g. the ISC licence, which has been commented on in the Open Source community (OSI mailing lists, and others) several times (OpenBSD still uses the unfixed version).

Comment: Upvoted mostly for point 2. Couldn't we get the same (or better) effect by using CC0, and putting the liability disclaimer in the SO TOS? This seems like trying to drive a screw with a hammer.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want people to use your code snippets, why did you post them to Stack Overflow?

**Reality:** The purpose of the CC-BY-SA licence is to stop link-farmers ripping off the content to auto-generate a vast Internet of Crap. It's not to make sure you get a mention in the comments in Contoso's internal web portal because you knew the correct way to deserialize a widget.

The new licence should be that the code snippets in answers are public domain, or at any rate are licensed with the only obligation not to hold the author liable, and no other obligations.

If you have some code you want to protect with copyright, it's not appropriate to post it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately *"code fragments are public domain"* is not legally recognized language in the USA and many of the countries adhering to the various WIPO treaties. The best you can do is explicitly lay out every right you grant in a license, which is why we have a plethora of licenses, and why the OSI is working doggedly on trying to bring order to the whole situation.  I wish it were simple, but it's not and never will be. Choosing the MIT while making attribution optional is probably the closest they can get to public domain from a legal perspective. It's not a bad move.

Comment: @AdamDavis that's complete crap. They could write their own licence which was the same as MIT but with no attribution requirement rather than an optional one.

Comment: By the time you posted this answer, the question had already been migrated from meta.SO to meta.SE because it affects far more sites than just SO. I can't think of any code snippets I've posted to SO which I'd be worried about people reusing without attribution, but I definitely want to preserve my moral rights under the Berne convention with respect to some of the code I've written on other sites in the network.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, for example?

Comment: [Example 1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9342/194), [example 2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5911/194) (which is also an example of code which can't be put in a code block), [example 3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41072/194), [example 4](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39751/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor, you've persuaded me that it shouldn't apply to Code Golf. Not Stack Overflow, or DBA, or ServerFault or poweruser.

Comment: +1, I can't believe how many people want attribution for their code snippets. Guys, isn't it sufficient to get rewarded with public reputation in exchange for your time/free contributions?

Comment: "The purpose of the CC-BY-SA licence is to stop link-farmers ripping off the content to auto-generate a vast Internet of Crap". Totally wrong: Stack Exhange doesn't hold the copyright and cannot use copyright in any way against competitors.

Comment: @Nemo To add to your point, the proposed license change would of course make it *less* likely that anyone (even the original author / copyright holder) could legally restrain scrapers/spinners. E.g. if an answer contained only code, it would be fair game for scrapers. In short, the proposed change means that SO/SE's competitors would have *more* freedom to scrape, not less.

Answer (score 23):

I think there's been an excessive knee-jerk reaction against this change.  I'd encourage the skeptics to:

**Read the label**

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional** and
>   enthusiast programmers.

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

The mission-statement for Stack Overflow, at least, is to provide a useful resource for both professional and amateur/enthusiast programmers.  It's intent is not to primarily benefit the open-source community (or any other niche), nor to take sides in an ideological debate on IP/software rights and licensing.

The 'professional' part is important here, as it implies operating for commercial gain.  Typically in the employ of a corporate entity, and/or with at least some codebases that are not open-source or otherwise publicly available.

Responsible professionals know better than to incorporate copyleft code into a proprietary/closed-source codebase.  Which makes CC-BY-SA licensing a *very big problem* (technically speaking), to the point where it's in direct conflict with SO's published mission-statement.

**Understand CC-BY-SA**

[CC-BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license) is essentially a [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) license.  Note that the 'SA' in CC-BY-SA stands for "ShareAlike", which is a licensing requirement that any derivative works which incorporate CC-BY-SA content *also* be released under CC-BY-SA.  And that's where the copyleft problem comes in for professional use.

Interpreted in the context of a software codebase (though as noted in the OP, CC-BY-SA was not really *intended* for use with software in the first place), it means that if you use a CC-BY-SA licensed snippet in a codebase then strictly speaking you must release the entire codebase under the same license should you distribute any works derived from your codebase (such as a complete application/compiled binary).

Or in other words, copy a snippet from SO into your Android application, then by a strict interpretation of CC-BY-SA (or any other copyleft license) you must release your application's source-code under the same terms if/when you submit it to Google Play.  That makes code licensed under CC-BY-SA technically unusable for most professional (i.e. commercial) purposes.

Which, again is at odds with SO's stated purpose.

**Consider the reality of the situation**

The SO community advertises itself as a place for professionals to collaborate and discuss solutions to technical challenges.  And there are undoubtedly plenty of professionals to be found here.  And certainly some of them have probably used some code snippets in proprietary, commercial applications.  And it's certainly likely that an even greater number of non-members who find a useful snippet on SO through a Google search have used it in closed-source projects of their own.

To pretend that this hasn't happened, doesn't happen, or isn't happening *right now* is silly.  To argue that it *shouldn't* happen is a denial of SO's published mission-statement.  And to try and force the issue and litigate someone over violating the CC-BY-SA license on a code snippet would be virtually impossible if they don't self-nominate (how on Earth are you going to find out that they used your snippet?).

To have all of the code on SO licensed under the terms of CC-BY-SA is actually a massive impediment to the site's intended use-case.  It's incongruous with the way that people actually use the site, in practice.  On paper, it's a massive risk for any professional users.  And in actual fact, it's probably an issue largely ignored by the majority of users (and non-users) who turn to SO for coding help.

The only thing the new changes do is bring the 'on paper' licensing terms in line with the way people actually use SO.  Which is something that we should all welcome.

**Consider why you post code on SO**

Are you here to try to help people solve problems?  Or are you here to get your name listed against as many projects as possible, one small snippet at a time?  Or to play 'gotcha' with unsuspecting professionals, litigating them when you catch them *actually using* the code *you gave to them*?

*Unless you're here for the third reason, you don't need to have your code snippets licensed under copyleft!*  And if you are here for the third reason, you're participating in a highly ideological debate.  Which is entirely your right, but which is also something that SE probably shouldn't get entangled with.

And besides, would you really litigate someone for using your code snippet commercially, and do you believe it would really be *ethical* to do so?  Considering that you know there's a good chance the person asking the question is a professional developer, and that you know that professional developers often work on commercial, closed-source code.  If you object to your code snippet being used in such a context, then why are you answering their question *with code* to begin with?

If your motivation is to help others, the licensing changes do not impact you in any way.  Or, they might make it possible for you to help even more people, as the new license makes your code usable in places where CC-BY-SA code technically is not.

And note that there's really no issue with respect to attribution.  CC-BY-SA requires attribution, and the new license terms *still* permit you to require attribution.  So you can have your attribution if that's what you're after.

The substance of the change is removal of the 'ShareAlike' component from the license, which changes code on SO from being copylefted to being permissively licensed.  It's very similar to changing the license terms to CC-BY, which requires attribution, but drops the 'ShareAlike' requirement.

**Consider what's fair and reasonable**

Forget for a second about the legal precedence that establishes that IP creators can essentially dictate terms according to whatever arbitrary criteria they choose.

Instead look at how much time and effort actually goes into code snippets posted on SO.  FGITW means that the average snippet is authored in minutes, not hours.  A *good* FGITW player will at least invest some additional time curating and improving their snippet after it's posted.  However, all up it's probably *very* safe to say that most code snippets on SO are authored in 60 minutes or less.

So what's a fair reward for 30-60 minutes (at *most*) of effort?  Is it a thank-you, some +rep, and being able to (should you so desire) require attribution from people who find your code helpful and use it?  I'd say that's fair enough.  You made a helpful contribution, and are entitled to recognition for the effort.

But is it fair or reasonable to demand that the person who uses your snippet release their *entire* codebase under CC-BY-SA, when that codebase may contain many thousands of lines of code and be the product of many person-years of combined effort?  I think not.  The snippet is a drop in an ocean; it shouldn't allow you to lay claim to the entire ocean.

But that's exactly what you could do if code snippets are licensed under CC-BY-SA (assuming no legal hurdles and technicalities get in the way).  And personally I think that's absurd.  The value of an answer is real and nontrivial.  But it's not so large that providing someone with a code snippet should mean you have a claim to every codebase that snippet gets used in.  Attempting to do go goes against the spirit of collaboration, community, and helpfulness that underpins SO, in my opinion.

As such, the new license terms strike a better balance on the 'fair and reasonable' scale, and address a potential imbalance between the value provided by a CC-BY-SA code snippet and the scope of the claim that can be staked against a much larger codebase by leveraging the 'ShareAlike' component of CC-BY-SA.

**In closing**

I welcome and fully support this change (though I think the suggestions to implement this as a dual-license as opposed to a wholesale swap have merit, so long as it's the *consumer* of the code who chooses which license they want).  You should too.  There's no reason not to.  Information wants to be free.

The sooner this can take effect, the better.

Comment: I appreciate that you contribute to SO to help people solve problems. You seem to post many more answers on Stack Overflow than questions. Do you feel that "information wants to be free" (and therefore we should force it to be free) applies equally to code that appears in questions?

Comment: @200_success - The problem with code contained in questions is that it's often broken (otherwise the question wouldn't exist).  But generally speaking, yes, I don't see why the same rules shouldn't apply in either case.  In terms of asking a question, I wouldn't put up code that I'm not entitled to share, or any nontrivial amount of code from a proprietary codebase.  And if people find it useful, even though its presence in a question implies that it's broken/buggy in some way (and therefore non-useful as written), then good for them.

Comment: This answer has a tiny nod to the fact that this doesn't just affect SO in "*Stack Overflow, at least*", but otherwise the impression that it gives is "This suits SO, and none of the other sites in the network matter". Those who are more active in other sites may disagree quite strongly.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Fair enough.  My answer is a fairly SO-centric as that's where I spend the most of my time.  Though that's also probably where the majority (though certainly not all) of SE's code-snippets live.  I wouldn't say there has to be a 'one-size-fits-all' solution to license terms across all SE sites, but at the same time I can't think of a really strong counterargument against that approach either.

Comment: Note also that some of the other sites have code which isn't just a snippet. E.g. there are full self-contained programs in answers to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22144/194) which represent several hours of work.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "if you use a CC-BY-SA licensed snippet in a codebase then strictly speaking you must release the entire codebase under the same license". I would argue that the copied source code is being added to a Collection in your software project, from the viewpoint of this license. That means that the copied source code is under the CC BY-SA license, but the rest of your source code is unaffected. My full analysis: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300861/386091

Comment: @Ron Are you sure? 100%? Are you a lawyer?

Comment: @Ron - That's not how copyleft works.  As another answer points out, CC-BY-SA is GPL-compatible, and certainly under the GPL _all_ of the source-code that's _compiled with_ the copied code is affected.  You could, of course, make the argument you describe in court and hope the decision goes your way.  But few developers would be willing to take that risk.  And CC's [description of ShareAlike](http://tinyurl.com/odbps7g) does not agree with your analysis:  "If you remix, transform, or **build upon** the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original".

Comment: @assylias No, I'm not a lawyer. I wish there were clear guidelines on StackOverflow about how to obey the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license with source code. Since, there are not, I've had to do the analysis myself.

Comment: @aroth Can you point to a careful analysis (from a lawyer, ideally) saying why using a snippet of code from StackOverflow requires redistributing your whole proprietary code base under CC-BY-SA 3.0? You would think that if that were the intention, there would be prominent warnings about that somewhere!

Comment: @Ron - Unfortunately no, as there doesn't seem to be any prior litigation of software usage under a CC license.  Most [prior cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Legal_aspects) involve media (pictures, music, newsprint, etc.), which is why I tend to use the GPL as an example.  I can point to [previous decisions involving GPL-licensed software](http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/new-york/nysdce/1:2009cv10155/355978/131/).  Also the decision in Drauglis v. Kappa Map affirms that 'ShareAlike' applies to derivative works under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: You can take MIT (or SO)-licenced code and use it almost everywhere, distributing the whole under whatever license you want. Dual-licensing is thus (mostly) moot, and adding that just complicates stuff. Better leave it out, the final result is the same.

Comment: The GPL software case you linked to was not decided based on anything to do with the license -- the judgement was a default because the _defendant did not participate_ in the case. The decision in Drauglis v. Kappa Map was in favor of the _latter_ -- the "Share Alike" claim was _denied_. (Additionally, none of the other CC-related cases you linked have anything to do with the Share Alike terms.) Your citations do nothing to support your portrayal of Share Alike.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Yes, it was a default judgement.  However if you read the actual decision ("Westinghouse infringed on Plaintiffs' copyright by distributing BusyBox [...] in a manner that did not comply with the License"), it _does_ uphold the validity and enforceability of the GPL.  The default judgement would have gone _against_ the plaintiff had the License not been enforceable; a default judgement doesn't mean you win if your claims are prima facie invalid.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - And you misinterpret the Drauglis case.  Yes, the plaintiff lost, the rationale being that _ShareAlike applies to derivative works and not to Collections_.  From that one can conclude that the defendant would have lost the case had they created a derivative work instead of a Collection.  What's relevant is the text of the judge's decision, not the particular outcome.  That's where legal precedence is argued from.  The only question is, as Ron raises, whether the courts would tend to view software as a derivative work or as a Collection of code snippets.

Comment: No, that's [not how it works in civil suits](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_55). There's no presumption of innocence as in a criminal trial. If you don't defend against the complaint, the default judgement means you've lost, _without the court considering the merits_ of the complaint. See the second footnote of the Westinghouse PDF you linked.

Comment: I'm a professional.  **All my code is copyright my employer**.  Unless Stack Exchange makes some kind of realistic exemption for me, I will have no choice but to stop contributing code altogether.  This was also applicable to CC-BY-SA, of course, but I only got hired on the 7th.  The point is, SE is moving in the wrong direction here.

Comment: (The plaintiff would have had a default entered against _them_ had they brought the complaint and then failed to show up.)

Answer (score 22):

### Reasoning

I don’t think this is a good idea.

#### Background

I’m a BSD developer myself, so I’m normally happy with putting things under BSD/MIT-style licences, but there are two **big** things that go against BSD spirit there:

### The exception from reproducing the licence ☹

This is really bad, as attribution is all a BSD developer usually gets (and, occasionally, patches to the eMail INBOX). It also creates a “net” licence by itself, the problems with which others have already pointed out.

**So, if you’re going to switch to MIT, use MIT, not MIT with some exception.**

### What is code?

I’m a very big fan of putting everything under the same licence, be it code, data, documentation, etc. so I cannot help but disagree with distinguishing between “Non-code contributions” and “Code contributions”. In addition, someone has to decide what is what, and that usually falls to judges, and we all know things just go down the drain when lawyers are involved.

### This means:

**All three bullet-points** you stated are **against** the spirit of those who use MIT-style licences in the wild the most.

### Other problems

Some people have pointed out that e.g. “the GNU libc doesn’t become MIT because I traced through it on SO”. This is true, you obviously can only licence content where you have the permission to do so. However, including such information on SO posts is still necessary; this is just as true currently though, so there needs to be an amendmend to the ToS that it’s fine to post content one does *not* own as long as it’s under an OSS licence. As things currently stand, [HostileFork admitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271145/234382) what’s basically violation of the ToS by posting content where he doesn’t have permission to post it under CC-Wiki.

## My own solution

I’m okay with the current situation, where the entirety of the post is published (harmonically) under a weak copyleft licence, but where I have the following snippet on my network profile:

> **I hereby offer all content I author on the SO/StackExchange network also under [The MirOS Licence](https://www.mirbsd.org/MirOS-Licence) ([HTML version with less WTF-8](https://www.mirbsd.org/MirOS-Licence.htm)) in addition to “cc-wiki” (CC-BY-SA 2.5 or 3.0, depending on the SO/SE network site, apparently). I urge everyone else contributing here to do the same.**

(I should probably plug the full terms there; had to do so for opencaching.de (on which I put my geocache listings under those terms as well) have requested I do that *and* add a German translation as that site is also used by many people who don’t speak English… which I did.)

This allows authors to choose more free licence terms for their posts (of course I’d be able to exclude individual postings, and postings in which I posted content that’s not mine, such as GNU libc excerpts), but preserves the copyleft-and-attribution-requirement of the general site.

And everyone who does take content of mine under [The MirOS Licence](https://www.mirbsd.org/MirOS-Licence.htm) will note it also has a requirement to retain full attribution and licence terms (all three of copyright statement, terms and discaimer), while permitting inclusion in other works.

Circle back to harmony of code, data, documentation, media content, etc: this licence specifically uses the term “work” instead of “code” while otherwise being a mostly standard BSD/MIT/HPND-style licence. This is precisely to facilitate putting *everything* under the same licence terms.

### What SO/SE should do, IMHO

- Stop this hurried action
- Add some wording to the ToS about excerpts from works one does not own (permit it as long as the work’s under some OSS licence), as that’s as much a problem with the current terms as with the new proposed ones
- Rethink, read community feedback
- Possibly allow opt-in or even opt-out (per (site, not network) account) to use a permissive licence **but** do **not** waive the notice preservation requirement for them
- Allow opt-out of the permissive licencing for individual posts

This makes it fine for sites such as Code Review to continue operating on the current terms (it’d probably qualify for opt-in) while still permitting you to put e.g. SO under an opt-out scheme for more permissive licencing terms (with more advance notification, this time).

I do hope any changes to the terms such as these would be prominently featured in a to-be-acknowledged page the first time anyone posts after they go live, right?

Comment: Quoting is always fair use, so there shouldn't need to be any special clause for quoting code.

Comment: @curiousdannii “fair use” is a US-american concept and as such does not apply internationally either. In fact, in Germany, citation has rather harsh boundaries.

Comment: If quoting wasn't legal then academic writing would be impossible. I've never heard of a country where quotes are illegal, have you?

Comment: @curiousdannii there are extremely specific rules to quotes/citations; unfortunately, Google Translate doesn’t do [this article](https://www.rechtambild.de/2012/06/der-bgh-zum-zitatrecht-oder-die-wulst-zu-zitieren/) well, but here’s the important part (slightly edited): […] That is, the quote must serve as evidence of the citing work, as basis for discussion, or at least engage critically with the cited work. Basically, there must be a connection between the outer own and inner quoted work. For this purpose it isn’t enough to use a work only to illustrate or solely for informational reporting.

Comment: So there may be some situations where quoting code wouldn't count as "fair use" in some jurisdictions, but for many common ones, such as asking for explanations or reviews of code on CR, they should be okay if they're the basis of the discussion.

Comment: There is no such thing as “fair use” outside the USA (and possibly select few other countries). Quoting to-be-discussed code is okay, obviously, but that’d still be part of a posting someone is licencing to SO/SE under CC-BY-SA (if not, they’d violate the ToS), but they cannot give that licence for the quoted part (as they don’t have the licence to do that in the first place). Basically, in CC terms, quotation is -ND, which conflicts with -SA.

Comment: Having the notice non-waived makes it basically impossible to take small snippets of code directly from SO and incorporate it into larger projects, as you'd end up having copyright notices longer than the code you are writing all over the place, with legal consequences if they ever get removed (and a high difficulty determining what exactly each copyright notice applies to, so you could never remove them).

Comment: @Yakk this is wrong, as really small snippets don’t fall under copyright protection anyway due to lack of Schaffenshöhe (don't have the English legal term handy this late at night, basically the amount of creativity and effort needed for a work to become © protected)

Comment: @Yakk please learn to spell correctly if you want people to take you seriously. Anyway, the threshold is not size/length but creativity (the oft-quoted 10 lines rule by the FSF is only a rule of thumb and only works for _some_ programming languages and styles).

Comment: @mirabilos So you are saying you are wrong, and that there is ambiguity in short snippets being covered by copyright, which means everyone who does a snippet into a large program will have to include a large license comment or open themselves to potential liability, and it becomes exceedingly unclear if the code base evolves when/if that license comment can be removed legally?  Personally, I don't want people to have to consult international copyright lawyers to safely use code from stackoverflow in their projects.

Comment: Inspired by you I copied the snippet into my profile, but unfortunately I'm retiring it now to boycott this proposal / announcement for the same reason as you detailed here. :(

Answer (score 21):

Well... I see after only three hours many people have some very strong opinions about this.

I opened a question about clarifying SO's intentions on licensing a while back so I would simply like to say thank you.

Thank you for taking the time and resources to address this issue. I'm sure there were a lot of tough decisions to be made and I'm sure handling the reaction is going to be pretty difficult as well.

So again, thank you for addressing this.

To the people who want to offer an opinion on the outcome I'd recommend you read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro) and others before throwing in an opinion. It breaks down the complications with the prior license and seems to demonstrate interpretations fell one of two ways. If you want to have a constructive impact on what's happening it will benefit to be aware of what has already been discussed.

Comment: I'm not gonna say that months of going back and forth on this, drawing up plans only to scrap them and start over, nagging lazy co-workers for feedback and trying to parse legal objections have driven Sam & Tim completely mad... I have entirely too much respect for them to say that. But they could probably both use a gallon or two of strong drink at this point.

Comment: @Shog9 - If anybody involved is in the bay area I'm more than happy to buy them a drink or 10. :)

Comment: @Shog9, probably better if they don't start over, nor get sloshed. Instead, I'd welcome a clear-headed announcement to drop the proposed change and just leave the licensing as it is. CC-BY-SA 3.0 is a great license for user contributions, and the proposed change is frankly incoherent.

Answer (score 21):

So we've got

1. Contributors who want their code to be used as freely as possible,
2. Contributors who want their code to be used only with attribution,
3. Programmers who want to learn from code examples without copying from the code itself,
4. Programmers who want to use code under clearly defined terms so they can steer clear of copyright infringement, and
5. Programmers who just want to use code in their projects without having to worry about all that legal mumbo-jumbo.

Keeping everything CC-BY-SA works well for group 2. Maybe for group 4 as well, except that CC licenses (aside from CC0) are generally [not recommended for use on software](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software).

MIT-licensing all code from 2016 onwards is also fine for group 2. It might help group 4, except you don't know for sure whether the user who posted the code is actually the author... or got it from somewhere outside StackOverflow... or modified it from another StackOverflow question or answer which isn't necessarily MIT-licensed... etc.

A quasi-MIT license that makes attribution optional, unless the author comes and asks for it later, adds future uncertainty and thus is even worse for group 4.

A less restrictive option would be to make code contributions available under the Unlicense, the CC0 Public Domain Dedication, or similar "do what you want" terms. That would satisfy groups 1 and 5, although group 2 wouldn't approve. Group 4 might be a little worried as well, since there's some dispute over whether waiving copyright is legally valid (though that's a much longer discussion).

Group 3 would be satisfied with pretty much any licensing terms.

---

I think the best way to strike a balance is to make everything CC-BY-SA by default, and allow individual contributors to share their code under more permissive terms if they so choose.

A good start would be providing an option to add licensing/permission notices in user profiles. For example:

> "All the code I contribute to StackOverflow is copyright <My Real Name> and open-source under the MIT License (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)."

Or

> "All the code I contribute to StackOverflow is available under the CC0 Public Domain Dedication (https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/deed.en)."

This helps groups 1, 4, and 5 by lifting at least some restrictions on code sharing. It also satisfies group 2, since the attribution requirement is preserved for those who want it.

---

I won't pretend there's a perfect solution. Certainly not for groups 4 and 5. The safest option for avoiding copyright infringement is always to write your own code -- possibly using the same ideas you've seen elsewhere (since ideas can't be copyrighted), but expressing those ideas in your own words.

And from my perspective, the central purpose of StackOverflow is to learn. Not just to learn how to fix some specific code, but to gain the ability to solve problems of that type in any form. And for that purpose, reading the answers to learn from them -- without copying their text -- is perfectly fine.

Comment: Nice summary - Group 2.5: Contributors who want to prevent their code from being used in commercial projects or open source projects with permissive licenses.

Comment: No CC licence works well for code, and CC themselves recommend to *not* use CC0 for *any* new works of any kind due to problems with it. Public Domain is not a licence grant, many people (e.g. most EU citizens) cannot place their work into PD if it’s eligible for copyright protection, and it does not, unlike licences (which work under Berne Convention), cross country boundaries, so it would not make reuse by people with different nationalities possible.

Comment: @mirabilos the op clearly says that there is some dispute over whether CC0 or unlicense are valid and does not recommend using them.

Comment: @assylias sure, but while he mentions dispute I can confirm that waiving copyright does not work ⓐ for citizens of some countries, and ⓑ across country boundaries (as the Berne Convention only deals with copyright protection, which is the tool regular OSS licences use).

Comment: Even in the U.S. it's very hard or impossible to make something public domain -- basically, public domain only applies to government works or if the copyright term expired. [CC0](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ) is meant to be a waiver of rights to the extent possible, with a permissive license as a fallback. Not everyone's comfortable with it, though. For example, it's [recommended by the Free Software Foundation](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#CC0) but not by the [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/faq#cc-zero).

Comment: @jkdev [it’s not, in its current form, suggested by Creative Commons](https://lists.opensource.org/pipermail/license-review/2012-February/000231.html), which is why OSI cannot recommend it (as CC withdrew it from the OSI approval process).

Comment: Seems they're sending some mixed messages. Here's from the [CCO FAQ](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ): "CC0 is suitable for dedicating your copyright and related rights in computer software to the public domain, to the fullest extent possible... Unlike CC licenses, which should not be used for software, CC0 is compatible with many software licenses, including the GPL. However, CC0 has not been approved by the Open Source Initiative and does not license or otherwise affect any patent rights you may have. You may want to consider using an approved OSI license..."

Comment: Just want to add that one also learns by copying... as long as one understands what one has copied. Sometimes it's just difficult to do things different, even if you do them kind of on your own (with help).

Comment: @Trilarion Very true. There's a reason that developers often use [the Chinese Wall technique / clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) to write non-infringing software... It's not always possible to un-remember code after you've seen it.

Comment: What about group (6) Programmers who don't want to have to spend 40 minutes figuring out what they have to do to copy 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 19):

Have you considered what this means for those scraping off SE? If I make a scraper that just keeps the code snippets -- say, just the code from answers that are more than 70% code -- I suddenly have very real, very useful content for very free to keep alongside my very sponsored links, and it's all very legal. Hooray? Is this the desired outcome? Because that's probably all that this suggested change will really get us.

I agree that some people have been using SO as if this proposal was already implemented ([humorous related tweet](https://twitter.com/old_sound/status/650490638308409344)). I also think that scrapping attribution by default is wrong. We have been fighting the attribution fight quite strongly, and now... we're just sort of giving up on it?

Please keep the requirement to have code be attributed. You do agree people should do it, so I don't see why this shouldn't also be enforced. If you want to treat code differently from non-code -- and I think you do -- only require linking back to the post (with the usual no-nofollow caveats). In practice, this won't change anything, really: people who just wanna copy paste without giving credit are just going to copy paste without giving credit. There's a big difference between doing so and doing so *rightfully* until busted.

Comment: Actually this change would make things much harder for scrapers, unless the code is dual-licensed under cc-by-sa + MIT/SE crayon license. Scrapers would have no mechanical way to determine what license they need to apply, practically making the entire StackExchange unfreely licensed and completely impossible to reuse. This *might* be the goal, as StackExchange is also proposing to *transfer* your copyright to them, which they previously didn't.

Comment: Where is the transfer proposal, @Nemo?

Comment: @nemo just approximate code block = MIT. For most popular languages you can probably even run a syntax check. Hell, wouldn't that be sweet: as a user you get the guarantee that all of the code in the site compiles

Comment: @JoshCaswell "or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor". This is only possible if StackExchange is the copyright holder (by any meaningful sense of the word), as it gives them the right to represent the copyright holder in contracts and lawsuits.

Comment: Recourse against scrapers was a factor in coming up with the proposed terms. Consensus was that scraped code displayed without context just doesn't provide enough value to the scraper or to the world at large for this ever to be a serious threat.

Comment: @Nemo There is no transfer happening here. Perhaps that wasn't clear. The clause you're referring to is intended to give us (the company) the right to ask a scraper or other bad actor to give a contributor (or many contributors) credit.

Comment: @samthebrand, *"Consensus was that scraped code displayed without context just doesn't provide enough value to the scraper or to the world at large for this ever to be a serious threat."* The fact that you and your colleagues assumed that to be true does not mean that reality will bear out your assumption. You're proposing to gamble on that assumption with *our* contributions. I'm sure you can see how that comes across as both arrogant ("Crystal ball, check!") and - despite your wording - *non*-consensual, especially without a strong opt-out available (other than ceasing to contribute to SE).

Comment: To be fair my point is invalidated by the "or SO on behalf of the contributors" bit

Answer (score 18):

I'm finding it extremely bizarre that people are complaining about the fact they seem to be being forced to give up certain rights over the code they post on SO<sup>(1)</sup>.

The stated *purpose* of SO is to be a Q&A forum where people come to get answers to programming-related questions and that *includes* providing code in your answers. In fact, the vast majority of answers could be considered useless without *some* code.

And, to be honest, if your code is so damn precious, why would you post it here anyway? Because, despite the attribution requirements of SO in the past, plenty of people will use your code with absolutely *no* attribution (changing structure and variable names to hide the fact, if they're truly paranoid). I could understand if you were posting your hyper-advanced operating system or your string search algorithms that would make Google run six times faster.

But nobody really cares about (for example) code showing how binary trees work because that information is available in dozens of other places as well, and would be unlikely to pass the Abstraction-Filtration-Comparison test laid out by SCOTUS (other jurisdictions may, of course, vary).

In any case, this is supposed to be a *community,* a place where we help each other out. No-one is forcing you to be part of the community: if you don't agree with the rules of said community (and SO is well within its rights to change those rules going forward), don't participate. Despite my answers far outweighing my questions, I still have garnered much use out of those questions and the "loss" of exclusive rights over the stuff I've posted is a very small price to pay.

All the code I post on SO is covered by the "do whatever the heck you want with it" licence, the official text of which is:

> You are hereby permitted to do whatever the heck you want with it.

That's because I find even the MIT licence too restrictive for code samples that any reasonably experienced code monkey could come up with :-)

I've now added that to my profile so that there's no doubt.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keeping in mind that the rights are most likely gone anyway, under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: What about the questions?  While I don't mind sharing most of my code, I don't have the "giveaway" mentality on all of my code in my questions, at least not without attribution.  That especially goes for Code Review.  I certainly agree that my code (notice how I said 'my', not someone else's) in answers is free-for-all.

Comment: I strongly disagree that "the vast majority of answers could be considered useless without *some* code". For answers code is like images: it can add to clarity and explain some things more concisely, but actual code (rather than just inline names of functions/keywords) is rarely *necessary* for a useful answer. Or else the question may be suspect.

Comment: @B.K.: so you want to ask other people for help, but you're not willing to give them your code?  Then don't post questions.  It seems like somehow you're trying to say "well I'm going to put this here, and show it to you, because I'm so smart, but you can't use it.  I just wanted to show you how smart I was."

Comment: The "In any case ... don't participate" part of your answer, combined w/yr apparent disdain for CC-BY-SA, is logically inconsistent severalfold. (1) Copyleft licenses ensure people do help each other out, not rip each other off. Copyleft thereby helps ensure the "community" aspect of SO as you've defined it. (2) The rules of a community come from the community. SO is within its legal rights to change the T&C of its website, but it is *not* within its rights (or even its ability) to dictate the rules of a community.

Comment: (3) You seem to want SO to be a place where people help each other out; but on the other hand you appear to be happy for the community to become unwelcoming, which is obviates helpfulness. To paraphrase you: "If you don't like the new SO, go away and don't come back (even if you've been a pillar of the community for years)!"

Comment: @NickBastin That's exactly it, you got me.  Grow up -- that is obviously not what I meant and you know it (or too immature to know it).

Comment: @B.K.: you understand that I have no idea what you are complaining about?  CC-BY-SA already allows the code in your questions to be used by anyone, for anything.  Yes, with attribution, and that's a fine thing to care about, but you *cannot* restrict distribution in any way, with the existing license.  Not liking the MIT change is fine (although you have an option - stop contributing, no one is changing old contributions), but attribution is the *only* change, and questions are not treated separately (now, or in the future) from answers.

Comment: @NickBastin Yes, I understand that you have no idea.  Who said anything about complaining?  I brought up a point; I did not complain about it.  SO can do what they wish, I just provide my input on the issue.  You're the one that's getting all aggressive and insultive.

Comment: What if someone else edits "your" code? @B.K. Who owns it then?

Comment: @Cypher Editing should not be to the point where it functionally alters the original code, as that's not what OP posts and any edits to the actual code must not be beyond simple formatting. Therefore, if there's an edit to the actual code, it's not the code they're trying to run and encounter issues with/have question in regards to.  Therefore, the OP owns that code, unless that code came from somewhere else and they've altered it. I understand what you're getting at, and it's a very complex situation. I've never had issues with sharing; but I feel that it's important to discuss it.

Answer (score 17):

Like most people, I'm not an expert on licensing, so if you were to ask me to choose between MIT and CC-BY-SA, I would just say "Meh, do what you like, it doesn't make any practical difference to me." I imagine that the majority of users will be indifferent about the change. In fact, I would be surprised if half of the users could tell you off the top of their head what the current license policy is.

And for people who *do* care about licensing, the change brings a number of headaches:

- The license depends on the date something was posted.
- It is not clear what license applies when edits of varying significance are applied to posts that were made before the license change.
- Precisely defining the difference between code and non-code is almost impossible and opens all sorts of potential edge cases.
- Any change is annoying for slow bureaucratic organizations that have to be careful about licensing, which might lead to a policy of "Don't use content from Stack Overflow until we figure this out".
- Mere mortals trying to understand how the license works have to spend at least double the effort: They need to know the rules of two different licenses, which one applies in which situation, and how the optional exception to the attribution requirement works.

In other words, I see the change being mostly inconsequential, except for some annoyances to the minority who are careful about this stuff, which leads me to the question,

### What's the motivation for this change?

Is there something bad about the status quo? Can you give any practical examples of real problems people have faced because of the CC-BY-SA license, which would be fixed by changing to the MIT license? If not, I don't see any benefit.

Comment: The motivation for the change is that the CC-* licenses (except for CC-0) are unsuited for source code: source code is routinely transformed in a number of ways (eg. compiling, binary linking) that artistic works aren't.  The CC-* licenses don't really cover these situations.

Comment: @Mark I more or less understand the theory, but can you give me a real-world example where this has actually prevented somebody from doing what they needed to? For an example of the sort of thing I'm looking for, Crockford's eccentric license for the JSON library led to [software being removed from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692614) since it included a library that was [considered nonfree](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#JSON).

Comment: The motivation for this change is that legally speaking, [you are not allowed to include code from SO in a project, even an open source one, unless it is licensed under a GPL-type of license](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/is-creative-commons-license-compatible-with-apache-license). And people keep talking about snippets not being subject to copyright because they are small, but Google lost a lawsuit over 9 lines of code. So the "threshold of originality" can be very low in practice.

Comment: No you can't include it in GPL code,  it requires things not required by GPL.

Comment: @Elin, yes you can, BY-SA [allows](https://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses) porting to GPL. (SE uses 3.0, but that can be relicensed to 4.0.)

Comment: @otus okay let's specify it can't be included in GPL2  but can in GPL3.

Comment: @otus What about content that's already licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0? Can it be relicensed under 4.0 without the consent of its authors?

Comment: @jkdev, yes, that same [link](https://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses) tells you so.

Comment: @assylias THis should have been explained in detail in the OP.

Comment: A real world example, If you sell your company, a standard part of due diligence for the purchaser is to review your code base with an eye toward ensuring that that it has not been virally contaminated with GPL code that would force you to allow anyone to compile and build and distribute your entire project for no charge whatsoever.  CC-BY-SA has the same viral affect as GPL. I have participated in such code reviews as a purchaser. And been subject to such code reviews as a seller.

Answer (score 16):

## `ISC License` – Even shorter than MIT

The [ISC License](http://opensource.org/licenses/ISC) is a briefer equivalent of the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT). Simpler words, more readable, easier to immediately comprehend.

And more up-to-date legally. [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license) that, while functionally equivalent to the BSD/MIT licenses, ISC omits language made unnecessary by the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention).

This Answer is not arguing whether or not the MIT License change is good or not… I am simply suggesting that if you *were* to go ahead with the plan for using the MIT License, and if the assertion of the ISC license’s functional equivalence is valid(*), then **consider switching from the MIT license to the even shorter ISC License** for the sake of simplicity.

ISC License text:

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

## `Free Public License` – No notice requirement

If the suggestion above for ISC License makes sense, and if it turns out that the issue of waiving the notice requirement does not make for a  “[crayon license](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crayon_license)“, then perhaps the best solution is the [Free Public License](https://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0) as noted in [the Answer by Trilarion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271346/203321).

The Free Public License text is the same as ISC, but **truncates the first sentence** to eliminate the copyright notice requirement.

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

(*) Caveat: I'm neither an attorney nor an expert.

Comment: I kind of like this idea. The one issue is, there was a dispute over whether the language "Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute..." allows distributing modified copies. At least that's what the Free Software Foundation says on its [Various Licenses page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ISC) regarding ISC.

Comment: I cannot see how even the craftiest of lawyers could twist `modify, and/or distribute` into *prohibiting* distribution of modified software, the exact opposite meaning.

Comment: Here's one way: "Modify or distribute" means modify a copy, or distribute a copy, but not both; "modify and distribute" means modify a copy for yourself, and distribute another copy. I don't know if that's what the University of Washington actually said, but there's probably a reason the FSF is concerned. Alas, sometimes you do have to spell things out to prevent intentional or unintentional misinterpretations.

Comment: `Free Public License` looks very tempting.  As I have mentioned elsewhere, notice requirements make incorporating code snippets directly from SO completely impractical in anything but a toy project.

Comment: The problem with the ISC licence, other than not using the and/or wording in some versions (e.g. OpenBSD's), is precisely that it allows disclaimer stripping, which may cause extended liability…

Comment: Found it. Here's [the University of Washington](http://www.washington.edu/pine/faq/legal.html) regarding an earlier Pine license: *"'Permission to use, copy, modify, **and** distribute this software... is hereby granted,'...but if you modify it, you have created a derivative work and must ask permission to redistribute it."* (Emphasis added.) However, the lists of permissions in [ISC](http://opensource.org/licenses/ISC)/[FPL](http://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0) use "***and/or***" instead of "***and***" -- which supports the argument that those licenses allow distributing modified copies.

Answer (score 16):

**Can we have a new post indicating what SE plans to do next, considering the fact that there is significant oppostion to the current plan?**

This post is overcrowded and it is difficult to make out which posts are (or are not) actually by experts who know the implications of what they are saying. And the upvotes are a very rough (if not inaccurate) indicator of how many people are for and against this idea.

And a lot of people like me do not understand the entire post as it is.

Comment: Indeed, this Q&A is busy. (Meta was never really made for extended discussions like this.) We'll be adding a new post in the next week or so addressing some of the concerns introduced here, but will continue to monitor this post in the meantime. Stay tuned.

Comment: @samthebrand Ok. Thanks for bothering to reply.

Comment: @samthebrand Did I miss the new post?

Answer (score 13):

This effectively makes any code posted to stack overflow after Jan 1 usable in other projects without any attribution or "work" on the part of the consumer, unless the writer of that code explicitly demands that the MIT license be displayed.

A mechanism to display what license a code block/post is under might be useful, and if the poster demands that the MIT license text be included in reproductions.

Some description of how mixed license content will work; suppose you have CC-by-SA code edited post Jan 1.  Does it remain CC-by-SA?

Some mechanism to allow old code by a given user to be "updated" to MIT en-mass would be useful; but every *editor* of said code would have to opt-in in order for the code to qualify.  More difficult, everything the code *derives from* (say it is a copy/paste of another CC-by-SA SO post with a minor edit?) may also have to be MIT'd.

...

The three states seem to be:

- CC-by-SA
- Explicit MIT
- Implicit MIT

Where Explicit MIT is when you require the license to be explicit.  Do we need a mechanism to auto opt-in to Explicit MIT?  If you do, does it apply retroactively, or does the fact you have posted Implicit MIT once mean that it should remain Implicit MIT on SO forever?  Because if I copy some code that is Implicit MIT, then later the poster opts-in to Explicit MIT, then someone audits my code and notices it is a copy without the MIT license (but I was never notified of the change), I will appear in violation incorrectly.

Crayon licenses are hard.

Comment: I think perhaps you're overstating the implications of appearing in violation of the 'Implicit MIT' license.  As long as you were to rectify the issue upon being informed of it, nothing bad would happen.  And also there's the broader question of _how_ an auditor would determine that a particular snippet of code came from SO if it was not annotated with a link or other forms of attribution in the first place.

Comment: @aroth Suppose I opt out of implicit by saying so in my profile, or in my answers.  Does that consist of informing?  Then if code is copied verbatim to some code base, with no attribution, "just fixing it later" doesn't fix the earlier violation of the license; what consists of "being informed" that the license must be explicit?

Comment: I'd think answers yes, profile probably not.  But really that's probably something for SE to puzzle out.  Perhaps there's a case for an actual account-level setting where people can indicate if their code snippets require attribution or not.  Though in terms of "fix the earlier violation of the license", I'm not sure what you mean.  How would you propose someone fix a past violation of the license on your code snippet?  Retroactively date their attribution?  Issue a public apology?  Pay you $$$ for "damages" (what damages have been sustained?)?

Comment: @aroth If you use copywritten content without a valid license, then it is a copyright violation.  Various criminal and civil penalties exist in legal frameworks, depending on jurisdiction.  These can include statutory damages (on a per-instance violation), and other kinds of redress.  One of the reasons why hand-rolling your own crayon license is dangerous, and using crayon licenses is dangerous, is that there are real liability issues here.  Hence my questions around the implicit MIT vs explicit MIT case; if you violate license agreements, the license doesn't grant you any rights.

Comment: Technically yes, you are correct on all points.  But what I was getting at is what _actual_ damages have you incurred if someone uses a code snippet you shared on SO without correctly following the license terms?  Not 'what damages does the legal fiction allow you to claim?'.  Keep in mind that the legal fiction was constructed largely to protect against the infringement of _commercial/for-profit_ works.  It's broad applicability to content that people share openly and for free, while technically valid in the legal sense, has always seemed a bit dubious to me.

Comment: @aroth I'm talking about the liability for the people who use the code.  They leave themselves open to liability.  Without clarification of exactly how the implicit/explicit exclusion of the license works, there is a minefield here.  The goal, as far as I can tell, was to make SO code relatively freely reusable; with this minefield of liability, it fails.  To clear up the minefield, some way to *clearly* indicate when the crayon license makes it an "implicit MIT" may be required.  Your philosophical objections to copyright law... well, they don't solve the problem.  :)

Answer (score 12):

## I think this is a nearly wholly good change.

There are a lot of answers on this question that voice potentially quite valid concerns, and I don’t doubt that they are real issues. But I am very happy with this change, and given that I haven’t seen any other answer that has expressed that clearly, I want to put it bluntly.

**I contribute to Stack Overflow (and open source in general) because I want my code to be *used*.** Perhaps I would hope that, in general, people won’t just copy it verbatim, but hey, I don’t really care. As long as some people find it valuable, it’s worth it for me. If people use it for immoral purposes, such as outright plagiarism, that’s their problem. Changing the license doesn’t make it not plagiarism. Anywhere that plagiarism is not okay (included Stack Overflow) won’t treat it any differently *just because the license is different*.

I’ve licensed all my open source code under the MIT, BSD, or (more recently) ISC licenses for years, and frankly, I never really considered the potential impacts of the CC-BY-SA license on my contributions to Stack Overflow. I want Stack Overflow to be an open repository of knowledge, and there’s little place for the idea of “ownership” in my vision.

I’m a fierce defender of the right to write proprietary code, and I have a grudge against “infectious” licenses like the GPL, but proprietary code has no place on Stack Overflow. If we’re going to be open, we should be *completely* open. I wholeheartedly support this change, and I thank the team for clearly giving it the thought it has warranted.

Comment: Does insisting on attribution make code not "open", in your view?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It certainly makes it *less* open in my mind. It implies someone *owns* that code. The code I post on Stack Overflow is not owned by me, it is open. It is owned by nobody.

Comment: You can always add more permissive licencing terms than SO’s “CC-Wiki” on your posts (or, to save space, profile), as I did. But while I agree with you on principle, I cannot as easily agree with you supporting this too-hurried change.

Comment: On attribution: Coywolf Qi Hunt wrote “I believe no one can invent an algorithm. One just happens to hit upon it when God enlightens him. Or only God invents algorithms, we merely copy them. If you don't believe in God, just consider God as Nature if you won't deny existence.” This does not mean the person who cast the algorithm into code/advice doesn’t deserve attribution, though – which is all most BSD developers ever get, after all, so don’t that *that* away.

Comment: @ mirabilos. Algorithms aren't copyrightable. So that's taken care of. Gods don't provide variable names (which are copyrightable); And gods don't provide open source code (which would be copyrightable). So all in all, a terrible example. And jealous gods are far more trouble than they're worth. Imagine the inconvenience of having to sacrifice an unspotted lamb every time you swiped three lines of source code from SE.The smell alone would be horrifying.

Answer (score 11):

Others have illustrated that the MIT license may not work for everybody. I want to address a more fundamental problem.

**What is code?**

On sites like SO or Mathematics.SE, we can expect that all code-like things are really code. On SciComp.SE and CS.SE (and others), it is not that clear. We usually use *pseudo* code which may or may not be accepted by some compiler (maybe without the author being conscious of the fact). Which license applies?

There are some options:

1. Sites with no or little "real" code do not opt-in to the switch to MIT licenses. Everything remains CC-licensed.

   *Problem:* Makes treatment of the real code there *is* inconsistent with SO et al.
2. Define some criterion that separates pseudo code from real code.

   I have no idea what that would be.
3. Give the authors control on a case-by-case basis.

   We can already specify the used language for syntax highlighting;
   we could have similar syntax for licenses, e.g. `<!-- license[-all]: (pd|mit|cc|gpl3|...) -->`. The default would be site-specific; maybe MIT for code sites and CC for science sites (to be discussed on site metas).

   The license could (and should!) easily be indicated in a nice way, integrated with how code blocks are displayed.

I think option three is superior: it gives authors full control if they want it, allows for several levels of "code" on one site, and deals with most cases by reasonable defaults.

Comment: You could also imagine that each user can specify a default license in his/her profile that gets automatically applied to each post unless manually overriden.

Comment: @assylias A three-level thing (site default, user default, block) is probably too much. I think the middle level is the most redundant, and on non-code sites probably next to useless.

Comment: Any form of customization of course prompts the question: why can't I choose a license for my non-code content?

Comment: let's say the default is X and I want Y, I will have to insert the license tag in every single answer I post - that is cumbersome...

Comment: @assylias Yes. My answer is mostly concerned with "is it code or not" -- which *has* to be decided on a case-by-case basis -- and not so much with personal preference (note that you have no choice now, so you don't lose much by just using site-default). Other answers highlight that requirement, and one possible solution is a user default.

Comment: Also a thing that occurred to me. If code is really just a bunch of instructions — the fact it is patentable seems to support the notion — then the amount of content on SE that can be qualified as code by extension of being a sequence of steps to perform in order is quite significant

Comment: Honestly option (3) seems the only real option, even without this change.  The *use* of the current license has been really whack at this point (people reasonably copying code from GPL software to make a point or example, which cannot be licensed in the way the site requires), and *that* is really what needs to be addressed.  Any license change won't solve the problem that code is contributed on a regular basis where the contributor has every right to reference the code, but not to change its' license.

Answer (score 9):

IIRC, the claimed purpose of Stack Exchange is to make things easier for programmers. I'm trying, and failing, to understand how this change contributes to that goal - or even how it avoids detracting from that goal.

First, we have this discussion. As we all know, the law is not logical in the same way that computer programs are logical. It's also rarely or never compatible with common sense. Most programmers don't understand legal logic, and many have an active distaste for it, often coupled with a distaste for lawyers, and sometimes a suspicion that the law is really just a false front wrapping some form of plutocracy, oligarchy, or other (ab)use of power.

As a programmer, I'm not happy that I now have to think about lawyers every time I consider contributing to Stack Exchange, or using already created answers.

I had hoped (and believed) I could simply use Stack Exchange in accordance with programmer common sense, and someone who did understand the law had created a reasonable tool to keep the monkeys off our backs, while not interfering with our use. I had also hoped I could expect most users to either behave in ways generally regarded as acceptable by programmers - or be run off the site for unacceptable behaviours (like asking us to do their homework), and possibly be chased down by lawyers for extreme unacceptable behaviour (such as collecting other people's answers and claiming copyright on them.)

Now I'm learning that if I ask a question and include real code, it's OK to copy that code - even into a commercial product. I'm learning that some people thought I should attribute their answer when it consists of something like `memcpy(dst,src,len)` - though not if it's in the form of "use the memcpy() function.

None of this was new - but I was thriving in the grey areas, and I'm sure many other users were thriving with me. Now some of that grey is going to be defined - but not defined in a way that anyone is equipped to truly understand. (We don't know what it means until it's litigated, and every law MOOC I've taken has stressed that this will be substantially affected by **political** reality at the time of litigation - implying to me that there's no way to test and debug a legal "program".)

Maybe Stack Exchange is big enough to need this level of pseudo-disambiguation. If so, that's a regrettable side effect of its success. On the other hand, perhaps this is not needed. Or - since I'm thinking in non-engineer terms - perhaps this is about the business interests of the corporation running it, not the claimed intent of value to programmers.

In any case, what I want is some input, from the folks proposing this change, about its intended benefits, other than a hoped-for reduction in ambiguity. (A cost-benefit analysis would be better, since it will surely have costs.) I'm unconvinced that ambiguity will really be reduced - legal-speak only seems to pretend to specificity, given the way real world law cases happen. And I can't see this churn as being beneficial. So all it's doing is putting a bad taste in the mouths of those of us who have managed to avoid legal entanglements, and creating a rush exercise for those of us who were already thinking in legal terms, and now have to evaluate the new license, decide what changes in their usage they may need to make, and meanwhile quite possible abandon the site entirely, until their lawyers get back to them.

Comment: The harsh reality is that if you include code from SO in a non-GPL project, you may be infringing the rights of the person who posted that code on SO. The proposed change makes it clear that this is not an infringement, "*making things easier for programmers*" (to paraphrase your first sentence).

Comment: @assylias that might be the intention, but it's certainly not achieved with a MIT/SE crayon license, which is not in the OSI-approved license list and hence is by all practical purposes unfree.

Answer (score 7):

To me that announcement reads like the code isn't licensed anymore via CC-BY-SA. Intuitively it seems to me like it would make more sense to dual-license the code with both CC-BY-SA and the MIT license.

Comment: There's no point in doing that. If you want to use code in a project with GPL or another viral license then MIT is fine. What do you gain by allowing people to optionally use CC-BY-SA?

Comment: @kjbartel : You can relicense individual parts under pure CC-BY-SA. If you for example want to create a database for an AI like Watson, you can combine in the status quo Wikipedia articles with stackexchange questions and relicense the whole thing under CC-BY-SA. You would need to add the MIT license agreement.
If then someone wants to print out part of that database to redistribute he has to print out the MIT license ageement as well.

Comment: I don't really see an issue with that personally and think there would be very very few use cases where that would come up as an issue. Leaving it as dual licensed wouldn't cause any problems but it could confuse people who then think that both licenses apply rather than just one at the choice of the user. Cleaner to just remove the CC-BY-SA license to remove that confusion (although removing the confusion regarding older posts and edits etc. will still exist).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like we might never agree on a single license, because [different contributors have different desires](/a/271179/148099).  If licensing were not a contentious issue, there wouldn't be [so many options for licenses](https://opensource.org/licenses/category), would there?

Could we perhaps **kill two birds with one stone**?  Here's a crazy brainstorming idea: **put the licensing decision in the hands of the poster** by offering two kinds of code blocks.

Four spaces of indentation would continue to be CC-BY-SA only, like the status quo.

[Using ``` to delimit the code block](/q/125148/148099) would mark it as permissive (whichever standard permissive license we settle on, be it MIT, dual MIT/CC-BY-SA, or CC0).

#### Implementation suggestions

1. Each community can decide which license is the default.  On Stack Overflow, perhaps the permissive license would make more sense.  On Code Review, the standard should probably be the status quo.
2. The <kbd>{}</kbd> code block button in the Markdown editor should reflect each community's standard code block license.
3. In rendered posts, the license choice can be distinguished using different coloured backgrounds, tooltips, borders, or whatever the designers choose.  (Please settle on a consistent network-wide convention, though.)
4. When submitting edits, the server should perform a diff, and quash relicensing attempts by anyone other than the original poster or a moderator (who, presumably, knows how to use that privilege responsibly).

#### Drawbacks

- I am fully aware that assigning an in-house special meaning to a variant Markdown syntax that is supposed to be semantically equivalent is bad practice.  (Using `<!-- license: permissive -->` or `<!-- license: copyleft -->` tags is a possible alternative, but those would more easily get lost during editing.)
- Note that we only get two types of licenses.  (In my opinion, offering both MIT and MITCrayon is a bad idea anyway.)
- Unfortunately, Code Review, the site that could perhaps benefit the most from ```-style blocks, would probably be better off with the CC-BY-SA license by default.  But that's just how it has to be, I guess.

The advantages are rather tempting, though…

#### Advantages

- We get the ability to pick a suitable license for each code block.
- The need not be a special cutover date: the license election is apparent in the post itself.
- The choice is "sticky", and robust to migrations, trivial edits, and paragraph rearrangement.  (It can never be perfect, but that's the [complex nature of the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus), and even expert lawyers and judges would differ in opinion.)

Problem solved?

Comment: Determining the license by the markup is horrible user experience both for editors and for readers. Most authors wouldn't know the difference, editors are likely to change one into the other without realizing the impact, and there'd have to be something visible for the readers to be able to tell. Something like license tags is the only viable solution here — if you want fragmentation at all, which I'm not convinced is a good thing.

Comment: @Gilles Editors changing one kind of block into the other can be rejected (or overridden) algorithmically. As for the coupling between markup syntax and licensing, I know that's a bad idea, and said so in the post.

Comment: This is just a brainstorm idea. I am open to any other tagging mechanism.

Comment: I like what this would accomplish, just not *how* it would accomplish it. HTML dropdown `<select>` elements would be much better than backticks-vs-4spaces. As for helping people choose a license, they could be presented with a very simplified choice or explanation such as "Require users of this code to give attribution to this post" / "Allow any usage of this code"...

Comment: @SimonForsberg But at some point, whatever license election is made in the UI would need to get serialized as Markdown somehow, I think?

Comment: This not the way to reach the solution. I would agree with a dropdown menu that could mark the entire post as either CC-By-SA or MIT with a default of CC-By-SA. Kind of like checking the community-wiki checkbox: it's metadata about the post and can be easily displayed with a small mention at the top-bottom of the post clarifying its license. By making CC-By-SA the default you don't introduce unwanted changes for people that didn't know about it.

Comment: @200_success yes, in the end it has to be saved into either markdown or some other metadata about the post (such as Jeroen's example of community wiki). For this, I think `<!-- license: xyz -->` would be good, or - if only one license can be chosen for the whole post - make it a dropdown box and store it as an extra field in the POSTS table (this would make it easier to prevent changes to the license after post was first posted)

Answer (score 6):

#### Thank you for sticking to a single license.

While I have yet to analyze this specific change sufficiently to weigh in on it, I am ***very glad*** the decision is to stick to a single license across all sites.  I've tried being part of communities where each author chose their own license, sometimes on a per-contribution basis, and it's simply untenable.

Regardless of the direction this whole plan and discussion go, please continue to stick to one universal license.

Comment: One problem I have with this proposal is it's **not** "sticking with one license" -- The Stack Exchange content base will effectively be split-licensed, with much of the content falling under CC-BY-SA, and the (as-yet-nebulously-defined) `code` contributions being MIT licensed. (Though I agree that if we're *going* to split-license the maximum number of licenses in the split should be two!)

Comment: I think what you mean is "Thank you for applying the same licensing policy to all sites".

Comment: With opt-in attribution there will be **three** licenses!

Comment: A licence per author is certainly extreme, but a licence for the entire network of sites is also extreme. In most aspects of life, the optimal solution is somewhere between the extremes. What is suitable for Stack Overflow is not necessarily suitable for other sites in the network (Code Review and PPCG have been mentioned elsewhere in this discussion). A per-site change would be a more reasonable level of granularity.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a great move to formalise what common sense suggested.

## This is a clear win for consumers of code

Whether you are working on a GPL, Apache/MIT/BSD, closed-source/commercial project, the proposed change will allow you to include code from StackExchange into your project *with no legal risk*. That was not necessarily the case before for non-GPL projects.

## Contributors lose the attribution requirement

The main change for contributors is the removal of the attribution requirement - that is maybe where additional work needs to be done. Some contributors will insist that there is some form of attribution.

That raises a few questions, in case you keep the MIT license as-is, without the opt-out for attribution:

- Can you clarify what a minimum acceptable attribution is under MIT?
- For example, if I copy some code from SO and add a comment in my code linking back to SO, is it good enough to comply with the MIT license?
- Can you clarify if there is a threshold below which attribution is not required under MIT (i.e. what is a *substantial portion* of code)?

Answering these questions and possibly keeping the attribution requirement would probably alleviate most of the concerns raised so far.

## But people will use my code in commercial projects!

If you were under the impression that what you post on StackExchange can only be used in GPL-like projects (due to the Share Alike part of the CC-BY-SA license), then you need to think again.

Under the current license, it is likely that people were already able to use code from StackOverflow in any types of projects, including commercial ones, [because code snippets are probably considered excerpts and the share alike part of the license is not applicable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957/179508).

CodeReview is possibly a bit different although questions are generally focused on a small feature as opposed to a whole software.

However this is a grey area, especially since [Google lost a lawsuit against Oracle over a trivial 9-line piece of code](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/). And the notion of *fair use* varies across jurisdictions.

=> The proposed change clarifies what common sense strongly suggested and removes ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, this proposal optimized one common use case — using code from Stack Overflow in commercial projects without attribution — at the expense of many other considerations (already mentioned by others).

Comment: @200_success not only commercial - non-GPL open source projects too.

Comment: Regarding your last section: such code (which Jeff Atwood seems to refer to) is not copyrightable anyway, no matter which license (or no license) is attached to it. The whole discussion is about code that *is* copyrighted. Something like the MIT license would allow inclusion of such code in software that is not licensed under CC BY-SA (or a compatible license).

Comment: Before this, my common sense said. (1) OK to use answers; that's what they are for. (2) Not OK to use questions. (3) It's on the net, so some scum will use things that aren't OK, relying on being able to get away with it. Now we have an explicit statement that  use of questions is legal, which tends to imply that this behaviour is OK. Net result - no social pressure in favour of what seems to me to be right behaviour, and some pressure in reverse.

Comment: @unor how many lines of code before something becomes copyrightable?

Comment: @assylias: I’d say this has nothing to do with the number of lines or characters. For mere mortals it’s by no means always possible to decide if something reached the threshold of originality or not (it’s for judges to decide, should it come to that). So to be on the safe side, I’d personally always assume that it is copyrighted (except for really obvious cases, of which there are many), possibly even if it’s only one line of code (i.e., a long/complex line).

Answer (score 5):

My observations:

**UX matters.**

I understand one of the *huge* advantages of your proposed approach: make our community do as little as possible while we tidy up legal loose ends.

I think the main goal of this license change should focus on the UX when considering licensing across SE. Approachability and ease of use is one of SE's best features. If you do anything that hinders UX from its current state, you risk losing that coveted pick-up-and-go charm that SE has.

**Documentation is not code.**

Not *all* the things that will be affected by this change would be considered code. I have no idea what kind of percentage breakdowns there are on answers/accepted answers and their format, but I see far more code snippets with insight/talking points on StackOverflow than I see fully realized programs, both for questions and answers, and *especially* comments! And yet, SE's Code Review and several others do not follow that pattern in the same exact areas. You could, and should argue that a not insignificant amount of what will be affected by this at specifically StackOverflow can be argued to be documentation, not code, *especially* code snippets that lack defined dependencies or fall into the realm of pseudocode. To use the same license for documentation as code is legally dubious.

However, as mirabilos mention, this is not truly a conundrum with certain languages and uses, where the line between code and documentation may as well not be distinguished, and all should be considered code.

**Stack *Exchange***

It's really important to keep an eye on the scope of this change. Who are we protecting? Better yet, who are we *hurting*? We can at least agree that the current license is not sufficient for the Stack Exchange's needs. We can also agree that using a modified MIT license isn't fulfilling the desires of the community either, even though you reasonably hoped it would.

**Tools at hand**

If all your tools are hammers, and you need to loosen a screw, looking beyond your toolbox is never a bad consideration. I understand you've already consulted various legal means, but please do not lose sight of how far-reaching a change like this can be. Sometimes you need to stop trying to figure out how to unscrew something with a hammer, and shop for a screwdriver. E.g., for a license this far-reaching, you need your own license. Yes, legal fees suck, but this is a business, and this choice *will* affect your business, and ultimately this community.

**The bad old days**

I may be young in this game compared to some of our regulars who have been in this industry since the beginning, but I'm no spring chicken. I remember life before SO, and let me tell you, it was not terribly pleasant. Even today, I'll often *add stackoverflow to my searches* because even though there probably already is documentation of the issue I'm having all over the place, this community does a great job of making sure we have distilled, quality information exchanging, with no shortage of professional insight and experience, across the globe.

Don't lose that lightning in a bottle.

Comment: No, documentation *is* code, it can be interchanged, often one can be generated from the other with a little annotation (javadoc and Python docstrings are just the beginning), or think of Teχ where there literally is no boundary.

Comment: I clarified that section. While I don't wholly agree with you, it comes from a point of ignorance. Can you explain to me what you mean about Teχ in regards to this? Or at least point me to a URL that can sum it up?

Comment: Teχ is where your “program” literally *is* the documentation; it can have comments and extra documentation, too, but it’s not unusual for them to have a circular relationship. But someone gave an even better example from the Maths realm: apparently they have a form of documentation they wrote a compiler for (Lambda Calculus, I think). In the end, documentation is just code for a human… and if it happens to be written according to some guidelines, a machine can parse it too.

Comment: @mirabilos A `.dtx` file is an even clearer case than a `.tex` file. It is code which, when compiled produces other files. These typically include something like a `.sty` or `.cls` file and a copy of the documentation for *that* code in compiled form. (An `.ins` is usually involved, too, but typically is just a wrapper.) The `.dtx` file can also be used directly as a `.sty` file. (For example, if you change the extension.) The documentation is code by design and an enormous amount of TeX documentation is provided in this form.

Answer (score 5):

I like this change, and think that most code on the website should be licensed under the MIT license, but removing the attribution requirement is not a great idea. If it is best practice to attribute people's code (so you can check back on that code later on for debugging purposes), why **not** just make it mandatory? It's only just a couple of lines in the source code anyway.

If a person hates attribution for whatever reason, he can relicense his code under WTFPL or the Unlicense or whatever. But make attribution "opt-out" instead of "opt-in".

Answer (score 5):

The big problem with cc-by-SA is not the requirement for attribution; it's the ShareAlike clause;

> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you
>   must distribute your contributions under the same license as the
>   original.

This is even worse than GPL because GPL is at least specific about how it virally infects your entire project with a license that allows anyone to swipe millions of lines of code you wrote independently. This license insidiously infects your entire code base for no other reason than that nobody bothered to really think through the consequences.

This kind of license may work for images; but under these terms, incorporating a three line fragment of code cut-and-pasted  from Stack Exchange means that I now have to publicly redistribute all 3 million lines of source code in my project that "build upon" those three lines (whatever that means) under the same CC-by-SA license.

I can't use code provided under these terms. Nor can most professional developers. Every company I have ever worked for in my very long career has specifically decided (after checking to see whether their corporate lawyers could make any sense out of the license) that GPL code can't be used under any circumstances. This license is in no way superior to GPL, and in many ways vastly inferior.

I do not give a damn about whether anyone gives attribution for code I post on Stack Exchange. And I think very poorly of anyone who would want attribution for code posted.

However, I very much do care about accidentally infecting my code with a viral license.

As users of Stack Overflow, you have to think very carefully about what kind of contributors you want to encourage. Do you want a community where everyone from beginners to seasoned veterans participate? Or do you want a community where professionals cannot participate, leaving only narcissistic amateurs who insist that you plant their name in the already-60-page-long legal notices section of your application because they provided a 3 line fragment of code that got cut-and-pasted through three generations of answers to a question, thereby infecting not only their own pitiable (and materially incorrect) contribution, but also the more substantial contributions of others who commented afterwards.

Please understand that for most people this looks trivial and inconsequential. But for anyone who writes software for living this a huge showstopping impediment. Serious enough it might lead to corporate policies that prevent people from using this site. As professional developers, we have to understand licensing issues. And the current situation is a nightmare. Action needs to be taken urgently.

I strongly urge everyone to support this initiative, and expedite its immediate execution.

Comment: You begin with "most professional developers" but you end up implying "all". Whether the statistical claim is accurate or not, the generalisation is not. Not all professional developers work on proprietary code bases. Some professional developers work on free software projects either in their own time or as employees of companies. Please resist the temptation to assume that free entails amateur. That is no more the case than the claim that non-free entails professional, though the latter claim is probably more obviously rubbish.

Comment: I can't see where I made such a generalization in the posting. You seem to be confusing examples with generalizations. Unless you're contending that professional software developers don't have to understand license agreements. 

But I don't think I'm wrong in thinking that professional software developers that share a few scraps of code on StackExchange really actually WANT a CC-BY-SA attribution for the code they have provided. That would be absurd.

Comment: Not really inclined to get into an argument about a comment I wrote almost 8 years ago, though 'anyone who writes' seems to be universal claim, albeit not one restricted to professionals.

Answer (score 4):

**My Concern:**

As others have mentioned, we need more time to think this over.  While I don't mind my code being used by others if I post it on SO as an answer, I certainly do not have the same feeling if I post something as a question either on SO or Code Review.  In the past I've simplified versions of my code to omit things I do not wish to share, but there's only so much simplification one can do before the code becomes too different to be applicable in the question.

Additionally, it seems to me that if someone forgoes providing all the correct information along with the code that isn't theirs and they posted as either question or answer on this network, the original author will have an uphill battle to fight with someone who chooses to use that code.

This is a serious matter, so let's not rush it.  January 1, 2016 **does not** give us enough time to rationally think about this and consider all avenues.  Not only is it a very short timeline, there's also the fact that this discussion is being started during a holiday period and many community members will not get the chance to voice their opinions.  This is a community-driven network and I think that everyone should be given a fair chance at voicing their opinion on such an important matter.  Let's give them that chance.

**A Possible Modification:**

As one possible addition to the proposal, we could have an option when an answer or question is being posted to specify license for that particular post.  The license would be right there on the display right next to the post, so there would be zero confusion as to what can or cannot be done with the provided information (although... some lawyer language can be confusing regardless).  This modification does not cover all of the concerns being voiced, but it's a step in the right direction if this network decides to proceed with the license scheme presented before us.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand what was written, even after reading it and many of the answers and comments here.

To me, it seems clear that it's absolute nonsense to post code publicly on the Internet and have any expectation that anyone else will read (let alone understand) a legal license, or that they will be bound to not use that code however they find it useful. I can hardly believe that intelligent people think that makes any sense. Multiply that feeling by at least 10x if it is posted on a Q&A code help site like this.

The idea that code posted on a public voluntary code help Q&A site would not be legally usable by anyone, just strikes me as "whoever thinks that is insane, or is thinking about it inside a painfully twisted legal context".

So, I have no idea whether this incomprehensible legal adjustment makes the supposed incomprehensible legal agreement more or less sane. Copyright laws are clearly ridiculously broken.

Edit: Thanks to @muru in comments, I finally get that this is just about redistributing code or text, *not just using the code and answers in projects whose code I'm not publishing*. I feel a bit like Emily Litella (attribution: Gilda Radner & Saturday Night Live), except for the part about it being so hard to follow what the licenses actually mean without a non-legalese explanation.

Comment: Read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro

Comment: @SpencerRuport Thanks.

Comment: The idea that just letting someone read my work makes them instantly able to use it without even acknowledging me just strikes me as "whoever thinks that is insane".

Comment: @JoshCaswell Wow. So you're hoping that in addition to getting thanked publicly on StackExchange (where it's naturally acknowledged and likely that anyone else who actually might care would find it), software (and phone apps, and web sites, and device owner's manuals) should have a credits section for answers got off the Internet for every bug and so on, and everyone should agree with you or they're insane?

Comment: I didn't specify the form of the attribution, and, uh, [the "insane" language is your own](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fb5Ty.png).

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's taken me 42 minutes to start to feel like I probably understand what the proposed change even means. I may be wrong, but it sound like the idea is that there was an expectation of attribution, and with this change, there wouldn't be? If you feel inclined, I'd be interested to understand what you do think the expected agreement should be for using a few lines of code from a Q&A site like this?

Comment: @Dronz Specifically, this part: "Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder". It used to be that you had to provide attribution, no exceptions.

Comment: @muru So I'm legally required to make a section on my ASP.NET web site where it lists things like "Thanks to MyCodeIsI337 on StackExchange for giving me 2 lines of XML that stop the site hanging for 20 extra second when loading certain pages", etc? I really don't understand what the requirement is.

Comment: @Dronz are you redistributing the 2 lines of XML?

Comment: @muru No, not unless the site goes into debug mode and dumps the XML as it sometimes does. Is this only for source code redistributed as source?

Comment: Yes, the CC-BY-SA license requires that you provide attribution when you redistribute it (not only for code, but any content here). The MIT License also requires it, but it's only applied to code. However, SE is now applying a waiver to that requirement on top of it.

Comment: @muru Aha! Wow, it sure took me a long time to even figure out what was being discussed. I think I've even studied those licenses several times before, even only a few months ago. Thanks! Makes much more sense to me now.

Comment: The [requirements for attribution under the existing license](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) are that the republished material be accompanied by a statement that the material comes from SO/SE, the username and link to the user page of the author, and a link to the post. There's no requirement (_as far as I can see_) that a _binary_ be distributed with "credits" for the source -- the attribution only needs to be in the source. Personally, I would be satisfied with my name and a link to the post (which thus implicitly mentions the site), but it's not up to me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for explaining. That makes complete sense to me, now that I have some idea what's actually being proposed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - The problem isn't with the attribution, it's with the 'ShareAlike' component of [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  Everyone is focusing on the wrong aspect, which isn't that attribution requirements have changed, but that a copyleft license has been replaced with a permissive one.  You can add "I should be able to force someone to open-source their entire codebase if I help them with a code snippet" to your list of 'things an insane person might think'.

Comment: @aroth Ah! That does sound rather significant. Does that aspect apply to distributing compiled code, or only to re-publishing the source or text of the help?

Comment: @Dronz - It's somewhat ambiguous, as the CC license was originally geared more towards media than software/code (which the OP alludes to).  However, as another answer points out, version 4.0 of CC-BY-SA is considered GPL-compatible.  And under the GPL, a binary (i.e. compiled code) is a derivative work, which means that yes, 'ShareAlike' applies _to your source code_ even if you're only distributing compiled binaries.

Comment: The [SE TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) refer to [**v3** of CC-by-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), not v4.0.

Answer (score 3):

The intention is well but it's doing more bad than good. If I use code from hundreds of different answers on StackOverflow (which is likely the case for anyone pursuing a career in programming) should I attach a huge name list to every project?

No.

And indeed that's why you propose a modified MIT license (wow, another license) that basically relieves me of this duty... unless you want actually the opposite.

This is not thought out.

Be consequent and use the [WTF license](http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/) or the [Free Public License](https://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0) (if you like liability waivers) and nothing else.

Only a really free license is the most useful license for code in a Q&A site. (And would make Stackoverflow equal to a code learning book or so because also there you do not have to give attribution when you use code from the content.)

The best is if we all just do what the fuck we want to with the codez that we give to each other freely.

This actually applies to StackOverflow where no attribution is just the only practical solution. For CodeReview for example much more strict rules should apply. But it's up to them to define them.

Comment: I would suggest picking up one of the licences approved by the OSI - a close match to WTFL is the [Free Public License](https://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0), which has a no liability blurb that is lacking in the WTFL.

Comment: @assylias Yes, that sounds even a bit better.

Comment: One quibble with the Free Public License, based on its similarity to the ISC License: *"Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software…" This is roughly the same language from the license of Pine that the University of Washington later claimed prohibited people from distributing modified versions of the software.* (Source: [Free Software Foundation, Various Licenses and Comments About Them, ISC License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ISC))

Answer (score 3):

I have one question about this proposal. I don't mind the license change, because MIT is super permissive. I only use the GPL when I feel it is absolutely necessary to ensure certain rights cannot be bypassed by a fork, but that's outside the scope of this discussion.

A lot of my questions include a complete sample program/MCVE/SSCCE/whatever you want to call it. I currently have them uploaded onto a github repo, [github.com/andlabs/misctestprogs](https://github.com/andlabs/misctestprogs) alongside other miscellaneous test programs I've written. For instance, the test program from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626549/what-is-the-proper-use-of-dtm-getidealsize-treating-the-returned-size-as-pixels) is available [here](https://github.com/andlabs/misctestprogs/blob/master/windtmgetidealsize.c). This repo is also governed by the MIT license, but with the copyright assigned to me.

Would my version of the MIT license be in conflict with Stack Exchange's, specifically in regard to copyright assignment?

I already know that the licenses are identical apart from copyright, so there's no issue with usage or duplication. I'm just curious if there would be a potential conflict because the two sites would have different copyright claims.

Or to put it another way, would my repo (which contains my MCVEs for Stack Overflow questions that I ask) in some way violate the TOS with this proposal?

Thanks.

Comment: If you own the copyright, you can license it to whomever under whatever differing licenses you please. You can post code on Github licensed under the MIT license (or GPL, etc.), and then post the same code on Stack Exchange which will be under the CC BY-SA 3.0 (currently). When you post to Stack Exchange, you do not give up your copyright. You merely license it to Stack Exchange (currently under the CC BY-SA 3.0).

Comment: In addition to what @cpburnz says, you can even permit SO/SE users to get it under other licence terms. The, currently CC-BY-SA, then not-quite-MIT, licence is **from you to SO/SE**, who then use that licence to publish to the world, but nothing is stopping you from offering the same content under different licence terms, *neither on SO/SE* nor elsewhere (e.g. github), unless you issue an exclusive licence contract to someone (and even then, e.g. in Germany, the exclusiveness can be revoked unilaterally by the author after 30 years). This is what I do, see my profile for the text I used.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to the existing CC BY SA license I think the new license better fits with source code and would address many questions which have been raised regarding use of code from SO. It also appears to be closer to the original intent of the license used on Stack Overflow, to allow the use of code excerpts without the CC BY SA licence applying since it would be considered to be fair use, [as stated in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957/260514) from Jeff Atwood:

> The cc-wiki license seems pretty clear to me on this point: free to remix and reuse, as long as you attribute and use a similar license.
>
> That said, a snippet of code falls under excerpt category and thus should be free to use under fair use.

This biggest problem with this change is the license mess it will create due to there being multiple licenses used for content.

- It isn't always clear cut what is or isn't code in a post.
- Different questions and answers having different licenses depending on when they were posted.
- What happens if you use code from an older question or answer which is then modified in the newer answer? Given the SA requirement then the new answer has to also use the old CC BY SA license.
- What license applies to edits of posts? Does fixing an error in an old answer then make all of the code use the new license or just the couple of letters changed?

To address the first issue I feel the license for everything should be changed, not just the code portion but the whole post. [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) would seem the the obvious choice and it just removes the ugly viral SA part of the license which is really the only problem this change is addressing. But really [no CC license is appropriate for software](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) so the "MIT" license would seem better. I don't see anything wrong with keeping attribution requirements and looking at other answers and comments it seems other people don't like the removal of this requirement.

To partially address the second issue there needs to be something on each post which indicates what license applies. It's not great but it's better than having to look at post dates and potentially even the history of the post to work out which parts are under what license.

It's pretty much impossible to address the other issues as they are effectively the same issues which currently exist now with the use of code from SO in projects which don't use a compatible license. But now it's being introduced into posts on SO itself, too.

Some users have tried to get around the viral SA license by stating in their profiles that all of their posts may be used under a more permissive license or even public domain. I think this could be a good way to address some of the issues. Indeed I think you should actually add a link to all profiles to allow users to opt-in to changing all of their past posts to use the new license and this to be shown on the profile when another user views it.

So bottom line, I'm in favour of the change but still see lots of potential problems that need to be thought through. The real question is why on earth did it take so long!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue at hand would have been easier resolved if not the *source* but the *target* determined which license would apply.

In particular, reusing SO code in a *program* could be licensed under the MIT license. It's fairly clear whether code is used in a program. Code fed to a CPU, compiler or script interpreter constitutes a program. Code mixed with prose, read by humans, is not a program.

Comment: So is a `.tex` document a programme or not? What about a `.cls` file? How about a `.dtx` file which includes the documentation and the package code and which produces both when compiled in different ways? That is, what about code which is both mixed with prose and read by humans *and* fed to a compiler?

Comment: @cfr: Like TrueType, I think you have to treat those as code.

Comment: So if somebody posts a question asking how to typeset their dissertation abstract in a particular way and is unwise enough to include the actual text of their abstract, that abstract can be used without even attributing it to them? So long, of course, as it is used in a `.tex` document which is compiled to produce the new document rather than, say, being copied into a Word document.

Comment: @cfr: I suspect we don't need formal rules for that. It would be plagiarism regardless of our license terms.

Comment: It is plagiarism whether it is code or not. The point is that it is not at all clear it is code. Indeed, it seems obvious that it is not.

Comment: The MIT license can't discriminate against fields of endeavor and remain an approved free software license in application. That is to say, we can't tell you that you can't print out every code snippet on the site and wallpaper your house with it. If we say "The MIT license covers code", we pretty much have to stop there.

Comment: @TimPost true, which is why I argue (in my answer on this Meta question) for harmonic licence terms that don’t distinguish between code and nōn-code contributions.

Comment: The proposed license does distinguish between code and text. I suppose there's a vague loophole in which somebody creates a website that contains all the code snippets found on StackExchange, minus all explanatory text. But how would you use such a site in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Figuratively speaking -- if Stack Overflow is a hammer, maybe code-sharing isn't a nail.

An alternative solution is to provide a one-click export of code from your Stack Overflow post to your GitHub account.

Then, if you are savvy about software licenses -- and if you are the actual author of the code -- you could edit your code on GitHub and apply an additional license to it.

Yes, this adds steps compared to just MIT-licensing all code. And it's certainly tempting to use code any way you want, especially if someone invites you to do so. But that doesn't change the actual requirements of copyright law...

Comment: You can just add a license-grant on your SO profile-page / the specific post, if you want to dual-license. No need to eport it somewhere else first.

Comment: It's a fair point. And posting code on multiple sites is often... um... duplicative. On the other hand, GitHub is where people generally look for open-source material.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see how simply linking to the original source is going to work in practice, since even with the best intentions at least some links will rot over time. But if S.O. itself provided a permalink service and a mechanism for managing and maintaining (and perhaps searching and adding links to) local copies of referenced sources then this particular problem would be addressed.

Comment: All the links to posts on any SE site are perma-links. It's just that some posts are soft-deleted for reasons of moderation, whereafter only 10K users, the post-owner and moderators can see it (and maybe reverse that decision).

Comment: @Deduplicator either you misunderstood what I meant by a permalinking service (I do understand that SE posts themselves are permalinked), or I misunderstood item *A* in the O.P. My point was that if an SE post contains an external link pointing to a github project page, for example, then that link will break (and whatever legal value it may have will evaporate) if github goes offline. My thought was that if SE itself kept full local copies of referenced sources then we could avoid both cluttered posts and broken links.

Comment: If the post depends on external content, it is link-only and either has to be fixed **by the OP** (only he can relicense) or deleted. Aside from that, referencing something in an answer here does not change its license.

Comment: @Deduplicator again I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. The point of the link proposed in item A in the O.P. above appears to be _to respect the conditions of an existing license_ when quoting code in an SE question or answer. My point was simply that the legal value of this link is no better than its referential integrity or uptime. If you're talking about what needs to happen to such references when the license on the original source *changes* then I think you're raising a different set of questions.

Comment: My reading of (A) is that it's about adding attributing links pointing *to* Stack Overflow in code you're writing elsewhere. You seem to be reading it as the opposite -- perhaps the wording could be clarified.

Answer (score -4):

This sounds like a completely pointless complication.

Code snippets most likely do not deserve copyright protection as they are small, many times trivial, and almost always describe facts and do not show any creativity. Since they will almost always fall under "fair use" the discussion under which license to put them seems pointless.

I, and hopefully all others, do not post in public code that I care about enforcing copyrights on. I have no ability to sue someone half way around the world because he copied 3 lines of my code, therefor the pretense of enforcing any kind of requirement like attribution is laughable.

Even if the license is meaningful and have a standing in court and I actually can afford a lawyer to sue someone, how will I exactly prove that he copied the code from my answer and not from some other one or some third source?

This sounds like a change being done for the benefit of some legal department at some big corp and not for the benefit of the contributors of SE. Frankly if someone is in doubt if he can use my code then the answer is simple - don't use it. I will welcome payment if someone really feels like he needs an explicit license to use my code ;)

Comment: Hint: [codereview.se]

Comment: Could you define a snippit?  Is [this code review post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114036/22048) a snippit?

Comment: If you can't define a snippet how exactly do you define "code"? If people are posting sensitive code (why code review people think it happens only there?) then how exactly are they going to maintain an IP to it? In practical terms, since it is impossible to prove code C&P in any project which is not open source those people are putting their code in public domain.

Comment: Big Co. Legal Departments don't care; they'll cheerfully tell programmers that they can't use SO if they want to keep their jobs. Meanwhile, scandalous coders will cheerfully pass off others' work without attribution and fly under the radar. So the perceived ambiguity really only hurts the programmers working at places with over-tetchy legal departments; so those are the ones Sam's trying to help here. We can talk trash about lawyers and copy-paste coders all evening, but it doesn't change who is actual affected, or how hard it is to make folks honest; best just make it easy to be honest.

Comment: @Shog9, that is exactly what I meant, but stating who these changes are made for is a good thing IMO. I don't hate lawyers but not specifying what problem this change is meant to solve removes context from the discussion. Personally I am not interested in the problems that corps have with utilizing my code and I will gladly MIT it, but for many worthy profiles it is possible to reach to the actual person and request a license grant explicitly.

Comment: I actually fail to see how you make life easier for the lawyers as they will still need to inspect the original post to make sure there is no attribution requirement and then make sure the code contains the attribution and do that for each release of the code. And this is before touching the edit problem.

Comment: I have no idea what makes life easier for lawyers. Gel pens maybe? Hopefully, this helps keep lawyers away from coders.

Comment: "for the benefit of some legal department", spot on, you nailed it. Why the downvotes? This is very close to the truth, the comments and original post say this in fact. Makes no difference to me, I've never used a snippet in my final code that has more than a passing resemblance to what I got from se. Nor would I ever attribute, so functionally there is no change, as you said, this is only about lawyers for corporations, not actual real people. If I post some gpl code as a solution, it isn't suddenly not my gpl code, it's just a code solution online, same as all the others. Just ignore.

Comment: "Code snippets most likely do not deserve copyright protection..." Don't be too sure. Even a nine-line function [that does something really simple](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/05/16/1612228/judge-to-oracle-a-high-schooler-could-write-rangecheck) can be protected by copyright (this happened in the recent [Oracle v. Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.) case).

Comment: @jkdev, sorry but summaries at /. is probably the least invormative thing you can read in the tech world (and I was reading ./ for about 10 years so I actually know). In theory you are right but that is an extremely rare case for which my "contact the user for permission to use his code" is the best thing to do

Comment: I've read other articles on the subject as well (and can share some links if you want). As I understand it, the court held that copying a simple nine-line rangeCheck function was still copying, and not trivially small (not 'de minimis') but the amount of damages to Oracle was zero dollars since Google could have very quickly written its own code that served the same purpose.

Comment: @jkdev,well if someone from sun have posted that code on SO with the "old" license scheme then google would have had hard time avoiding attributing properly attributing it but with the "new" scheme google could claim it is public domain even if that code was posted without any permit. Since you do not sign anything that claims that the code you post is your own it actually not going to help anyone for SO to say that it thinks it is licensed under MIT

Answer (score -4):

Who are these people who will stop contributing answers to Stack Exchange because they won't get attribution? And does anyone really care if they no longer contribute?

Comment: Hmm. Your first question conflates two different things: those who consider lack of attribution a dealbreaker (probably not all that common, though probably not as rare as you appear to think) and those who merely strongly desire it. You are certainly free to attempt to use monopoly power to coerce the latter to choose between contributing without attribution and not contributing at all, but quite frankly, I think this is uncouth. Fortunately, the inherent highhandedness of this approach is well reflected in the language of this answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to really add anything to the discussion over and above [your earlier answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271691#271691). Read uncharitably, it's rather inflammatory, although it fortunately doesn't seem to have sparked any fires.

Answer (score -6):

I think code in questions should be regarded as not licensed, and code in answers should be [public domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Domain) under [the Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/) or [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (as I have stated in reference to my own posts on my profile).

These non-licenses reflect the **reality** here -- we have no control over who duplicates the code we post, how it is used, or whether the code is attributed. Multiple contributors to the same posts muddy the water even more. The reality, too, is that it could be a full time job monitoring public code looking for violations; a few small tweaks to variable names or bracket syntax make this a nearly or actually impossible task, as does the fact that a lot of code isn't publicly searchable.

Face it: when you post code on Stack Overflow, you give it to the world. No licence.

Comment: Why should code in questions be considered not licensed, what does allow SE to publish it then, and are you sure building an answer based on the question should be prohibited?

Comment: This is basically an argument that the entire web should be (or be considered) public domain. Frankly, I consider that ridiculous.

Comment: @NathanTuggy For all intents and purposes, it is all public domain. I don't argue that it is a good thing, but the fact remains that you can download and use any art, music, literature, code, or video that you can see. DRM fails, for example, because no matter what they do to the file you must be able to listen to it, and if you can listen to it you can record the audio and make a copy. However, when an artist publishes music, their intent is to make money, so it makes sense to protect their property. When we post help on Stack Overflow, the intention is to give knowledge.

Comment: @Chris While I'm no attorney, my understanding is that "public domain" has two major legal issues: (a) many jurisdictions do not recognize the concept, and (b) being "public domain" does *not* necessarily absolve you of liability.

Comment: If code in questions is unlicensed, no answer can legally copy, modify or otherwise use that code. Indeed, I can't legally copy the code to my machine and run it in private in order to try to reproduce the error the asker wants help with. So I can't even post an answer which says "In line 3, change the fourth word to `this`. Replace line 5 by `that`." Unless I can be sure of the cause and the solution simply by reading the code without any need for testing. Note that this is what "no licence" means. No licence means you grant *no rights*. The default is all rights reserved in most places.

Answer (score -6):

## Different situations/use cases require different licenses

The Stack Exchange sites have obvious examples where the current and the suggested license models do not really work well (such as the previously mentioned Code Review, etc.). Therefore, I feel that the proposed change actually makes the situation more complicated without really solving the root issues. Also, there is the problem with the pre-change code which would still have the old license.

Why not generally aknowledge the need for different licenses, but in a different way?

- Every question defines which license it uses for code (or maybe also for the text - to be discussed I guess), both for code in the question and also for code in the answers.
- When one looks at a post or answers a post, the name of the applicable license is prominently shown (with a link to the full license). As a person seeking an answer, this tells me what I am allowed to do with everything I find in the question; as a person giving an answer, it allows me to decide if I'm okay with the license.
- What license is linked to a question is only editable by the original author and only as long as no question has been posted, or by moderators, as to avoid robbing content by means of changing the license.
- Everything posted until now remains with the license applicable to the respective site, so there is no transition issue at all.
- Migrating questions is not a problem because the license is attached to the question.
- Data exports and maybe even the data made available to bots could be made  dependent on the license chosen if necessary.

I believe that this solution should be able to address most (if not all) licensing issues, without generating too much complexity and especially without adding ambiguity.

The good thing is that this would enable programmers to specifically ask questions requiring a liberal license if this is related to some closed-source project they're working on, without violating the license as it quite certainly happens now (without anyone knowing). On the other hand, it would allow to protect posts with significant amounts of code such as on Code Review. Everyone could get what they need for their specific situation.

Comment: Are you proposing to let the asker select a code license which the answerers must follow?  I would see that leading to "plz give public-domain codes plz" questions.  Code from the question modified in the answer would be a derivative work, but plenty of questions either won't include code or can be answered without reference to the original code.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yes, that was my intention. If the asking person chooses an inappropriate license they will get no answers (but probably comments asking them to change the license), so I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: What happens if I ask a duplicate question but specify a different license?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom you mean if a question already on SO (for instance) is asked again just using another license? Well, it would probably be handled the same as today, which may mean that you don't get new replies. However, I believe that this would not often be problematic. Single-line API-Calls can easily be rewritten if one knows the name of the API without causing a license breach ; more complex duplicates where you actually need more than the textual answer are rare I believe.