# Why separate code and non-code licensing?

Tags: discussion, licensing, copyright, creative-commons

The rationale for the [license change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?lq=1) [proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/262711) is at least somewhat clear: i.e. to reduce legal concerns of using code from answers in software that may use incompatible licenses. However, what seems to be missing is a justification for why the distinction between code and non-code was or should be made.

From my point of view there are clear disadvantages to having separate licensing: additional complexity, the difficulty of defining code, as well as the fact that you then would have the same concerns (such as they are) if you wanted to include some of the *explanation* in code comments, rather than just copying code.

Therefore I would like to hear the reasons Stack Overflow (the company) and the community have *for* this separation of licensed material, and am posting this as a new question as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273168/a-new-code-license-the-community-edition/273207#comment888087_273207) by Tim Post. That is: Why not use the same terms, whatever they may be, for all content?

Comment: I suspect many people will disagree with using a “permissive” (i.e. non-share-alike) licence for complete posts. Many more people than when it’s about code, that is.

Comment: There is some precedent for separating code and non-code content. Google's developer docs are CC-BY for content + Apache 2.0 for code samples: https://developers.google.com/site-policies.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that, to the best of my knowledge, O'Reilly cookbooks don't have a separate code license.

Comment: @200_success Don't they have bulk reprint licensing and other stuff available as an add-on? I think you're right in that they don't have separate licenses, but I think their business model keeps them pretty far from even having to think about it, it's just not a problem for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tl;dr version:**

1. CC-BY-SA is *fantastic* for collaborative *prosaic* content, or content that's intended to be read and interpreted by human beings.
2. CC-BY-SA isn't a software license. It's not the best license for content that's intended to be read and interpreted mostly by machines.
3. Software licenses aren't really as good as CC-BY-SA when it comes to prosaic content. The clear attribution requirements of CC-BY-SA help us stay ahead of bad actors, like SEO scrapers - but don't get in the way of people legitimately (and honestly) re-using our content. The goal for *code* was to be a bit more permissive, but there's no reason to be more permissive when it comes to prosaic content - we already have a great balance there.
4. We don't think there's a 'universal' license that could serve us as well as two very specific licenses, one for prosaic content and one for code. As we burned through a ton of ideas, we kept landing on separation of concerns being the best path forward. We could have been wrong, but I'm just explaining how we arrived there.

---

**Now, Tim rambles introspectively for a bit:**

The biggest reason for going in this direction is that it makes our job as custodians of your contributions *much* easier if we transition into a more permissive code license. Any change can't weaken our stance [in a never-ending war against SEO scrapers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/page-appears-indexed-in-google-but-not-findable-for-any-search-terms) that started in late 2009.

How permissive *all of you* want the code license to be [is something you're currently discussing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273168/a-new-code-license-the-community-edition?lq=1). I'm just narrating our thinking and position *at the time* we reached it, with the MIT license in mind.

Put aside for a moment the complexities of trying to define *code*. Simplified, you end up with is content that is *prosaic* in nature - or meant to be *read*. You also have content that is *non-prosaic*, which can be read, but is *mostly* meant to be interpreted by machines. We want *much* tighter restrictions on what folks can do with *prosaic* content, and separating the concerns is the only way to achieve that. We don't need to make it any easier for people to just *read* stuff, essentially. That's easy enough.

CC-BY-SA is a *fantastic* license for prosaic content, and we definitely want to keep it. The attribution requirements help to ensure that 'mirror' sites don't outrank the original because the links *back* help search engines to identify them.

I'm not sure if all of you noticed, but we tossed in a proposed change to our terms of service at the same time that we added the proposed option for folks not to carry the MIT license (neither change is yet in effect). We put ourselves in a position where we can better enforce the terms of *both* licenses on your behalf (*upon request of the copyright holder, or Stack Overflow, Inc.*)

We're not the copyright holder - you are, you just give us a perpetual license to distribute your contributions. But, we're also the people folks look to for *enforcement*. I'm pretty sure we're going to want to close that gap in whatever scheme we ultimately end up with.

So let's say purely for the sake of discussion that the community broadly supports a 2 or 3 clause BSD-ish license. Just like CC-BY-SA isn't so ideal for software, BSD-ish licenses aren't so ideal for prose (though, it's generally okay for documentation). CC-BY-SA has everything we want on that side.

We should have been much more forward about this because we are doing some really good things to help ensure that we take good care of what you give us. The enormity of all the moving parts we were dealing with just .. well, never mind - we're talking about it now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Could you clarify why a more permissive license would hinder going after scrapers? E.g. CC-BY has exactly the same attribution requirements as CC-BY-SA, so wouldn't you be able to demand the same backlinking? The only real difference is that the scraping site currently needs to use the same license, but I wouldn't think they'd mind.

Comment: @otus, I don't think this answer ever claimed that every more-permissive license will necessarily hinder going after scrapers.  The answer seems to be making some weaker claims: CC-BY-SA is great for what they want; some of the most natural candidate licenses for code (e.g., BSD-ish licenses) are not great for prose.  Anyway, the original question was about why separate licenses for code and prose might make sense, and I think this gives a clear and plausible explanation of why one might want separate licenses for them.

Comment: @D.W., I have to disagree about it being clear. The reasons stated here are "going after scrapers" (why would it help in that?) and "because we want to keep prose BY-SA". The reasoning that some code licenses are not good for prose makes sense, but that only rules out *those* licenses, it does not explain why BY-SA would be the ideal.

Comment: @otus I edited in a 'tl;dr;' version. As much as I tried to avoid rambling while recalling the massive amount of work that led us to the decision, I ended up rambling a bit. Is that any better? I don't mean to stammer, there's just _a lot_ of depth to how we arrived there.

Comment: @TimPost, thanks, yes especially 3. and 4. in the list explain the reasoning more clearly.

Comment: @TimPost, *"The clear attribution requirements help us stay ahead of bad actors, like SEO scrapers - but doesn't hinder 'good faith' remix-and-reusing endeavors."* I don't understand what you intend this sentence to mean. Please could you edit it for clarity, at least specifying what it is referring to? (E.g. "The clear attribution requirements of CC-BY-SA..." or "The clear attribution requirements of attribution-required software licenses...")

Comment: @TimPost, "we tossed in a proposed change to our terms of service at the same time... We put ourselves in a position where we can better enforce the [license terms] on your behalf (upon request of the copyright holder, or Stack Overflow, Inc.)" I am in favour of licensors receiving the support of Stack Overflow, Inc, in upholding the license terms, because licensors might not possess awareness of a violation or might not possess resources to pursue enforcement, whereas SO might possess both. Putting this in the ToS is probably a Good Thing, as it makes explicit that possibility of support.

Comment: @sampablokuper (1) Take a look at the edit, I think I made it clearer and (2) I'm leaning toward putting that modification of the TOS in place regardless. I want to see if we can get close to another implementation that everyone feels good about over the next few weeks and just modify the terms _once_, but if it looks like it's going to take longer than that, it might be a good idea to get that in on its own.

Comment: @TimPost, thanks. I think it's unlikely any good faith user of SE would have a valid objection to that ToS change (your (2) above) on its own merits; & of course, I'd be in favour of that ToS change as I've expressed above. Even so, I would encourage you not to go ahead with a ToS change without first making the case clearly & checking the community is OK with it. A good place to start might be by asking on meta.SE if users support this particular proposed change, & by answering [this question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7372) with an answer pointing to that new meta.SE question.

Comment: @TimPost, *"Take a look at the edit, I think I made it clearer"*. Thanks for trying, but it's still ambiguous. "The clear attribution requirements" of *what*?

Comment: @sampablokuper Edit: Take 2 :) Better now?

Comment: @TimPost, yes, thank you. That makes your meaning much clearer :)

Comment: @sampablokuper It's definitely not a horrible idea to push the TOS change sooner, and yes, I'd allow plenty of time for feedback here prior to doing it. I need to meet with counsel to make sure the change is as intrinsically safe as we think it is, just as a matter of diligence. I agree we should have it no matter what license we ultimately choose.

Comment: @TimPost, OK, *we* (you & I) both think that particular ToS change seems a good idea, but please can I encourage you to restrain yourself a bit when it comes to implementation. In your comment above, & w.r.t. the proposed license change, you spoke *as though* getting the community's approval is a given, & that the change is - subject to your counsel's approval (& you know what I think of that!) - a *fait accompli*. Even though I agree with you about the benefit of this particular ToS change, your approach to implementation doesn't feel patient/consensual/respectful; it feels aggressive/hasty.

Comment: @TimPost, specifically, it's not enough just to allow time for feedback. It's crucial to *heed* that feedback, even if it could mean having to leave things as they are rather than making what you (& in this case, I too) see as improvements. Giving time for feedback ≠ receiving consent. The community was pretty shaken up by the way the licensing proposal was handled, & SE needs to demonstrate trustworthiness anew.

Comment: @sampablokuper We .. miscommunicate often. When I said we'd allow for plenty of time for feedback - _not a great idea at all and here's some reasons why_ would very likely delay any implementation while we fix it. I'm working from the last few mistakes, I don't intend to repeat them _that_ easily :)

Comment: @TimPost, *"'not a great idea at all and here's some reasons why' would very likely delay any implementation while we fix it."* I think I am, along w/at least some other SE users, asking something slightly different of you. Rather than wanting you to be willing to "delay and fix" yr proposed changes if the community dislikes them, we want you to be willing to *abandon* yr proposed changes if the community dislikes them. That's the difference. Maybe by "fix" you really did mean "fix or abandon". If so, great; & say so :) If not, then it's not miscommunication, it's difference of opinion ;)

Comment: "Put aside for a moment the complexities of trying to define code." Alright, I put it aside, and it's been a moment. Now it's back. This is a very important piece that cannot be handwaved away.

Comment: @shelvacu It's not being hand waved. We're going to be digging into this more next week. They're entwined, but separate issues, and need separate discussions.

Comment: @TimPost "We're going to be digging into this more" Don't worrry, [I already got it figured out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272264/249013)