# End of long question or answer overprinting status information at bottom of browser window

Tags: support, bug, design, firefox

Starting today, using the Firefox browser (52.6), some long questions or answers were displayed so that the end of the main entry overprinted the status information at the bottom:

> [image]

This appears in the posting [Wrapped Figures Using `insbox` in Lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417516)
It also suppresses the ability to click on any of the buttons (share, edit and flag).

This has been confirmed by other tex.stackexchange users.

Has something changed with the way the site is presenting postings?

**update:**
working on the theory that this is related to questions or answers that end with long image insertions or code blocks, i looked into code golf and found another, at [Create a solar system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156666) :

> [image]

**(incomplete) list of affected posts:**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417652/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417633/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417602/36296

[Glossaries Dual Entry IsUsed Flag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417534/36296)

[Beamer multi-frame problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417575/36296)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417578/36296

[My multi bibliography appears empty (using multibib package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243792/36296)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417635/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417618/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417605/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417597/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417610/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417510/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417600/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417601/36296

[Hyperref box does not obey slant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237063/36296)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417571/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417611/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417591/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417650/36296

## Update 1 March:

Seems to be working fine again!

Comment: Some additional observations: I think this problems started about 2 to 3 hours ago and it works fine with opera or safari.

Comment: I'm on FF 52: I get this on the question op linked, but not here on Meta SE. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271100/366373) is just as long, but nothing untoward is happening.

Comment: @BigBadCat -- it doesn't seem to happen consistently.  It appears more frequently on items that end with an image or long code insertion.

Comment: One example of too much space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/osRgf.png from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417605/36296 (I am using FF ESR 52.5.3)

Comment: @samcarter -- another example of an answer that ends with a long code block insertion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton a code block or an image alone seems not enough to trigger. Example of a long code block at the and without this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417561/36296

Comment: @samcarter -- as i implied (but didn't say) in the question, this is intermittent.  i found another, in code golf, and added an update to the question with that reference.  (it's beginning to remind me of the double backslash fiasco.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Totally agree that code block or picture seems to be a requirement. I just went through 20 random questions and their answers and all post with this problem end either with a code block or an image.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have found one that does end with normal text: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156682

Comment: Works fine with firefox 55.0b11

Comment: An example with question overlapping with the answer. Also, no code block or image was used: [https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6443](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6443)

Comment: @Adyrem May I ask which browser version you use? Also Firefox 52?

Comment: @samcarter Yes I'm using Firefox 52.5.3 as well

Comment: The inability to click the edit button is particularly annoying: If it happens for your own post and you can no longer click the edit button to remove the code block at the end of the post that causes the problem... no escape!

Comment: I've seen the same affect on several posts using FF ESR 52.6.  The issue just started.

Comment: [More](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180747/metasploit-stuck-half-way) [examples](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122789/is-xss-possible-when-is-not-escaped-but-also-not-displayed-if-followed-by-a-c). (There's an overlap between two answers in the 2nd link.)